# Como criar um link de redefinição de senha?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site que possui área de cadastro de usuários, a senha é criptografada para aumento da segurança no site, porém quando o usuário esquecer a senha como será possível eu devolver a senha dele descriptografada?

Já vi em vários sites aonde se recebe um link para que possa redefinir a sua senha.
Esse link deve estar salvo na base de dados?
Como posso criar um link apenas pra isso? Qual a lógica?

Comment: redefinição de senha ou recuperação de senha? para redefinir vc não precisa saber sua senha anterior

Comment: @Math Escrevi dessa forma pois não sabia qual a melhor solução, aguardava uma orientação se seria melhor recuperação ou redefinição

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Você não deve armazenar senhas que possam ser recuperadas. Use algoritmos one-way como o implementado pelo [`BCrypt`](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) (opção que utilizo em meus projetos). Isso significa que sua senha `12345` se torna algo como `534df$aa` no banco, e não é possível transformar `534df$aa` de volta para `12345`, apenas pegar `12345`, aplicar o [`salt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) definido e chegar ao hash gerado.

Quanto à recuperação de senha: você tem uma entidade (uma tabela) que armazena as solicitações de redefinição de senha, vinculadas ao usuário que as solicitou. É gerado um hash dinâmico para aumentar a segurança desse processo. Quando o usuário segue o link, é informado via `QueryString` o hash, o mesmo é verificado na base e, se for encontrada a ligação (comprovando que o link é legítimo), uma nova senha é definida pelo usuário através do formulário apropriado, exibido por você nessa tela.

Nunca implemente funcionalidades que retornam a senha que o usuário cadastrou, pois armazenar a senha de forma que a mesma possa ser recuperada é uma falha de segurança.

Links usados:

- http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29
- [**https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura) (obrigado Bacco!)

Comment: É recomendável também fazer com que o registro relativo ao link de redefinição de senha, na base de dados, tenha um prazo de validade - e que seja removido após esse prazo, ou após a redefinição da senha. Caso contrário, alguém que se apodere da conta de email de um usuário pode redefinir a senha a qualquer momento, a partir de um email antigo.

Comment: Deveras salutar e pertinente, @Renan. De fato a data é crucial nesses casos. Aliás, recomendo que o intervalo em que o hash seja válido seja de apenas algumas horas (2 horas é um prazo extremamente pertinente). Além do mais, excluir a tupla à qual pertence o hash, após a redefinição da senha.

Comment: Não é necessário o uso de banco de dados para isso. Usando-se algum algoritmo de criptografia autenticada, pode-se criptografar uma lista com o identificador do usuário e o instante da requisição e enviar um email para o usuário com o resultado da operação na query string. Ao acessar o link, a aplicação descriptografa o parâmetro, verifica se o prazo do link está válido e identifica o usuário.

Comment: Basta resolver um hash para sempre ter acesso a qualquer conta no sistema, não apenas as do usuário... Basta saber (ou inferir) os IDs de cada usuário

Answer (score 2):

Esses links possuem [tokens](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/token.html) para cada requisição de recuperação e/ou alteração de senha.

Para cada solicitação de recuperação de senha, você deveria seguir o seguinte fluxo:

1. Crie um token e armazene-o no banco referenciando à conta do usuário;
2. Depois, utilize esse token como parâmetro da URL de recuperação de senha para que quando o usuário venha a acessar, a sua aplicação saiba com quem ela esteja lidando;
3. Por fim, faça um formulário para o usuário inputar as novas definições de senha;
4. Envie as novas definições para o banco, exclua o token e voi là!

Tecnicamente, essa seria a lógica.

E tal como um sistema de log-in, uma senha **não deve ser descriptografada**. Ao invés disso, gere uma nova. [Rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) às vezes já incomodam criptografias one-way, imagine se você usasse um base64 para "criptografar" a base das suas senhas.

No mais, **não descriptografe** e utilize uma **criptografia segura** como o BCrypt.

Algumas dicas:

1. Faça com que o token expire depois de um certo tempo. Isso vai aumentar os obstáculos de um usuário mal intencionado à tentar alterar a senha de alguém;
2. Ou você guarda o token para referências futuras, ou descarte-o após utilizar.
3. Não vou explicar tecnicamente como é a URL final de uma recuperação de senhas, mas vou mostrar como é a URL em si: http://seuapp.com/recuperar/senha?token=123k23p2h3klndi2o3nd.

*Obviamente, a criptografia do token é fantasiosa.*

Answer (score 2):

**Lembra Senha**

Pode criar um `link`, onde usuário informa o `e-mail` dele e com esse e-mail você fornece um link para `troca de senha`, já que se a senha está criptografada no banco acredito não ter uma forma de reverter a `criptografia` em formato de `string`.

Como o `e-mail` vai estar na `base de dados` e um e-mail pertence a um usuário, para informar qual usuário deve ser atualizado ou pegar um ID com base nele.

**Observação:** Desconheço suas tabelas e seus campos, por tanto pense que o e-mail é sua identificação.

---

**Tente Troca de Senha:**

Primeiro o usuário deveria informar a `senha atual`, o site verifica se a `senha` informada é igual a que esta no `banco de dados`. Caso elas sejam iguais você pode permitir com que ele informe a `nova senha` e `sua repetição`.

---

**Campos:**

Senha Atual: |..........|

Nova Senha: |.............|

Repita Senha: |............|

Answer (score 1):

### Opção 1 (simples)

Gerar uma senha aleatória grava-la em seu banco de dados usando seu script de criptografia, e envia para o usuário essa nova senha aleatória.

Se houver uma tentativa de troca de senha por um outro usuário mal intencionado, o usuário verdadeiro terá que logar com a nova senha.

### Opção 2 (médio)

Trocar o algoritmo de criptografia para um que possa ser descriptografado. Assim você poderá enviar para o usuário a sua própria senha, sem maiores problema. A parte ruim é que se esse usuário "perdeu" o e-mail, ao enviar a senha vc poderá revelar a um impostor (lembrando que muitos usuários utiliza a mesma senha para várias contas diferentes). E se um usuário tiver acesso ao seu algoritmo de criptografia poderá reverter a tenha criptografa do seu banco inteiro.

### Opção 3 (difícil)

Geração de um hash para a troca de senha. Não é complexo e sim trabalhoso, criar uma nova tabela para guardar um hash aleatório que será enviado para o usuário necessitando deste para redefinir a senha. Essa opção é, digamos, a mais completa, não tem como evitar facilmente o roubo de uma conta se o "atacante" tiver acesso ao e-mail, mas ao menos a senha ele não vai saber. E se um usuário mal intencionado solicitar a recuperação de senha, o usuário verdadeiro pode simplesmente ignorar o e-mail e continuar com a senha antiga.

Answer (score -1):

Minha opinião julgo ser melhor você no caso ter uma logica para gerar uma nova senha para o usuário, concatenando letras maiúsculas e minúsculas números e caracteres especias e enviar esta nova senha ou para o celular do usuário, que na minha opinião é bem bacana, ou/e para o e-mail pessoal, pois dependendo da criptografia que usa não tem reversão para texto plano, e se tiver também não é 100% segura, eu no seu lugar geraria uma nova senha e enviaria para o cliente e quando o cliente se logasse no sistema pediria para faz a troca da senha, mas não o obrigaria a fazer isso.

Espero que possa ter ajudado

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro é necessário saber o tipo de Hashes que você esta usando.

Pois existe Hashes de Mão única e de mão dupla, se for de mão única, você não consegue descriptografar a senha:

Mão Única: Neste caso o seu sistema precisa gerar uma nova senha temporária, e enviar esta nova senha para o cliente com o link para ele resetar esta senha.

Mão dupla: Neste caso seu sistema pode buscar pelo e-mail do usuário descriptografar a senha e enviar para o e-mail dele, porem não é uma boa pratica.

CRIPTOGRAFIAS DE MÃO ÚNICA EM PHP

MD5

```
<?php
    $string = 'O rato reu a ropa do rei de Roma';
    $codificada = md5($string);
    echo "Resultado da codificação usando md5: " . $codificada;
    // 54cf74d1acdb4037ab956c269b63c8ac
?>
```

SHA1

```
<?php
    $string = 'O rato reu a ropa do rei de Roma';
    $codificada = sha1($string);
    echo "Resultado da codificação usando sha1: " . $codificada;
    // b186b709f7cf5a1d98d413379a66e511df8d59a4
?>
```

CRIPTOGRAFIAS DE MÃO DUPLA EM PHP

BASE64

```
<?php
    $string = 'O rato reu a ropa do rei de Roma';
    $codificada = base64_encode($string);
    echo "Resultado da codificação usando base64: " . $codificada;
    // TyByYXRvIHJldSBhIHJvcGEgZG8gcmVpIGRlIFJvbWE=
    $original = base64_decode($codificada);
    echo "Resultado da decodificação usando base64: " . $original;
    // O rato reu a ropa do rei de Roma
    // Note que $original vai ser idêntica a $string
?>
```

Segue um Link explicando um pouco mais sobre os tipos de criptografia no PHP

http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografia-no-php-usando-md5-sha1-e-base64/

Comment: *Não!* Base64 não é uma criptografia. MD5 e SHA1 devem ser evitados para senhas: rapidamente são quebradas. Use BCrypt, como o Tiago disse.

Comment: Tem certeza que MD-5 é de mão única? http://www.md5decrypt.org/

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira É de mão única, porém é facilmente quebrada. `9545d5fe013264ea287bbdbf6d1b1076` (é seu nome) o site não acha, mas usando uma boa GPU qualquer acha isso em pouco tempo.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues saquei! Valeu pela dica! Sempre achei que fosse de mão dupla.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues, A criptografia é um conjunto de técnicas para esconder informação de acesso não autorizado. O objetivo da criptografia é transformar um conjunto de informação legível, como um e-mail, por exemplo, em um emaranhado de caracteres impossível de ser compreendido. Ou seja base64 pode e é considerado criptografia, claro que extremamente simples.

Realmente o MD5 e muito fácil de ser quebrado. E sua sugestão de usar o BCrypt e a melhor opção mesmo!!!

Comment: Nesse conceito muita coisa vira criptografia, porém Base64 não foi criado para ser uma, é só uma forma de armazenar dados binários usando caracteres ASCII. Porém, pelo conceito, sim, é criptografia. *(mas não contem para ninguém, se aparece outro usando isso no lugar de algo mais seguro)!*

Comment: Passaram mais de dois anos e só agora eu vi a barbeiragem no comentário sobre Base 64.  **Base64 não é criptografia.** E nem foi feita pra ser criptografia, cuidado ao ler, e principalmente divulgar informações erradas.