# Redefinidor de Senha

Tags: php, java, android, servidor, login

Estou fazendo um app porém estou com dificuldade para implementar a opção de redefinir senha, uso um servidor web, gostaria de saber qual a melhor opção de redefinição de senha:

1) Pergunta secreta escolhida pelo usuário na hora do cadastro;

2)Redefinir porçamento envio de mensagem ao email do usuário.

Obs.: Não sei como implementar a segunda opção. Como posso fazer um código php para enviar um email automaticamente para o usuário

Comment: O q é "porçamento" no item 2?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar um link de redefinição de senha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7812/como-criar-um-link-de-redefini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-senha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu amigo, a segunda opção é certamente a mais segura e mais recomendada. Enviar um e-mail do servido via PhP é relativamente simples...

```
 <?php
  include('../conexao/conexao.php');
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  ini_set('smtp_port', '587');
  if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'recuperar'){
    //filtra caracteres especiais
    $email = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'emailRecupera', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = '$email'";
    $verificar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar) == 1){
      $codigo = base64_encode($email);
      $data_expirar = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));
      $mensagem ="<html>
                    <head></head>
                      <body>
                        <h1>Reservas de Salas - ENE</h1><br>
                        <h2>Recebemos uma tentativa de recuperação de senha para este e-mail.</h2>
                        <p>Caso não tenha solicitado, por favor, desconsidere este e-mail. Caso contrário clique no link abaixo para alterar a senha.<br><br>
                        <a href= http://homol.redes.unb.br/ptr012017-B-grupoA/recuperar/recuperar.php?codigo=".$codigo.">Recuperar Senha</a></p><br><br>
                        <p>Departamento de Engenharia Elétrica</p>
                      </body>
                  </html>";
      $email_remetente = 'reservado.ene@gmail.com';
      $assunto = 'Recuperação de senha';
      $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
      $inserir =  mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO codigos SET codigo = '$codigo', data = '$data_expirar'");
      if($inserir) {
        if(mail("$email","$assunto","$mensagem", $headers, "-f$email_remetente")){
          header('Location: ../index.html?SUCESS=2'); //Verifique seu e-mail para obter nova senha!
        }
      }
    } else {
      header('Location: ../index.html?ERROR=6'); //  E-mail digitado não está cadastrado.
    }
  }
?>
```

Lembrando que seu PhP tem que está configurado pra enviar e-mail.
Vale lembrar que o link que você enviar ao usuário tem que ser uma nova `session` por questões de segurança.

Comment: Super legal isso... Se o usuário ainda tiver acesso ao email. Se ele tiver começado a usar outro email e não tiver mais acesso ao email antigo, você garantirá que o usuário estará trancado fora do sistema.

Comment: É só pedir pra ele informar o novo e-mail. isso é tranquilo de mudar. No caso que mostrei ele pega o e-mail do banco de dados mas isso não precisa, necessariamente, ser assim. Você pode pedir um novo input do usuário e enviar para aquele e-mail.

Comment: É... pensando assim, +1.

Comment: Esse código está vulnerável ao meu ver, qualquer um pode alterar senha de outras pessoas. Você está usando `$codigo = base64_encode($email);`, ou seja o códgo envido para a pessoa em `recuperar.php?codigo=".$codigo.` é justamente o BASE64 do e-mail da pessoa, ou seja se eu quiser redefinir a senha do `fulano@email.com` eu posso clicar em "Esqueci Senha" e então entrar em `..recuperar.php?codigo=ZnVsYW5vQGVtYWlsLmNvbQ==`, pronto poderei redefinir a senha dele.