# Login não redireciona, header('Location')

Tags: php, servidor, conexão

Acabei de fazer um site que possibilita CMS para que o nosso cliente possa o login e modificar o conteúdo ao seu gosto. No localhost e num servidor de teste que temos funciona muito bem, mas no servidor final de destino não consigo sair da página de login depois de preencher com os detalhes corretos.

Existem 2 desfechos possíveis *submit*:

- ficar na página do formulário
- e caso esteja tudo certo ele faz o `redirect` para o menu.

Mas não faz o `redirect` e também não aparece nenhuma das mensagens de validação. Fui à consola do browser e a única diferença que vi entre os servers é no cabeçalho de resposta em que neste é `connection: close` e nos outros (onde funciona corretamente) é `connection: Keep-Alive`. Será isto?

Já pesquisei bastante e não consigo encontrar nenhuma resposta clara que me ajude a resolver este problema.
Já tentei inclusive implementar `header("Connection: Keep-Alive");` no código mas o problema permanece, apesar de no cabeçalho de resposta agora estar `connection: Keep-Alive, close`. Usei também o `var_dump` no localhost aparece `array(1) { ["logged_in"]=> bool(true) }`. No server final aparece `array(0) { }` a sessão não está a ser iniciada. Não percebo o porquê.

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
include_once('../includes/connection.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>AdminPT</title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                CMS - PT
                <br>

                <ol>

                    <li><a href ="add.php">Adicionar Artigo</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="delete.php">Eliminar Artigo</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="logout.php">Sair</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php
}
else {
    //display login
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = crypt(sha1(md5($_POST['password'])), 'st');

        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            $error = "Todos os campos têm de ser preenchidos!";
        }
        else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if($num == 1) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
            }
            else {
                $error = "Detalhes incorretos!";
            }
        }
    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>AdminPT</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                CMS - PT
                <br><br>

                <?php
                if (isset($error)) { ?>
                    <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo $error; ?></small>

                <?php } ?>

                <br><br>

                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type ="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Já experimentou usar o caminho completo no "window.location"? Se bem que no seu caso eu usaria o PHP mesmo, com `header( 'Location: /index.php' ) - Entretanto note que o correto no header location é usar o caminho completo também. Nada a ver com a pergunta, mas você enfiar 3 hashes um dentro  do outro na senha está apenas enfraquecendo a proteção.

Comment: Obrigado, já redirecinei com o php também usei agora o var_dump no localhost aparece "array(1) { ["logged_in"]=> bool(true) }" no server final aparece "array(0) { } ", ou seja a session não está a ser iniciada, mas não percebo porquê. Quanto aos hashs eu só copiei um metodo do youtube que me pareceu bom, mas obrigado pelo concelho

Comment: A hora que tiver um tempinho, dê uma espiada nesta questão, para saber mais sobre senhas e hashes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura

Comment: Muito obrigado sim irei ver já gravei nas bookmarks

Comment: Ja experimentou ver se a versão dos PHPs é a mesma? Dê uma espiada no log de erro do servidor, pode ter alguma dica lá.

Comment: Log de erro do servidor? Como vejo isso? desculpe a minha ignorancia

Comment: Estive a investigar e no entanto em enviado um cookie com a session id... Não percebo pk não redireciona, apesar do resultado da Var_dump ser "array(0) { }"

Comment: A configuração output_buffering no php.ini está habilitada? (http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/outcontrol.configuration.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 - Antes de mais nada, habilite todas as mensagens de erro. Assim provavelmente ficará explícito o que está acontecendo de errado no servidor remoto.

2 - Tente mover as validações para o inicio do código. Muitos servidores não aceitam instruções do tipo `header:location` "no meio" do código, e sim somente antes do `<html>`

3 - Outra possibilidade é ter algum módulo desabilitado no servidor remoto, então verifique através do `phpinfo()` as diferenças entre o servidor local e remoto.

Creio que apenas a ação 2 resolva tudo, mas mesmo assim deixo aqui outras sugestões. :)

Comment: Obgado tentei agora implementar a opção2 mas não está a resultar creio que devo estar a fazer algo mal, o sr. pode implementar essa ideia no meu codigo sff?

Answer (score 2):

O meu está assim também eu fiz o seguinte:

No lugar de:
`header ("location :index.php")`

Fiz assim: `echo "<a href='index.php'> voltar a página inicial</a>";`

Então vai imprimir na tela voltar a página inicial, é só clicar e faz o retorno.

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location: " . $endereco);
```

Pode sempre deve colocar:

```
exit();
```

Se não resolver, pode ser que colocando isso no inicio do seu arquivo:

```
ob_start();
```

e no final do arquivo:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

a solução para mim foi ob_start(); no inicio do arquivo php e ob_end_flush();  no final, ele voltou a redirecionar, coloquei até um refresh com tempo, deu muito certo. Muito obrigado pela contribuição.

Comment: Não use esse espaço para fazer comentários ou agradecimentos. Esse espaço é exclusivo para dar respostas a pergunta feita na página.

Answer (score -5):

estava com um problema do  seguinte  tipo , meu arquivo estava dentro de um diretório e a página que eu queria  redirecionar estava em um repositório antes .

quando eu colocava desse jeito

```
header("location:../app_agenda/novo_cadastro.php?cadastro=1");
```

dava erro!!!!

tive que fazer assim para funcionar :)

```
header("location:../../app_agenda/novo_cadastro.php?cadastro=1");
```