# Algoritmo de criptografia comum entre Java e C#

Tags: java, c#, criptografia

**Problema**

Estou criando um Web Service em C# para ser consumido por um aplicativo Android (Java), entre outras informações gostaria de passar as credências do usuário para fazer login *offline* no aplicativo. Mas essas credências gostaria de enviar criptografadas (do C#), e salvá-las no aplicativo, e no momento do login no aplicativo quero criptografar a senha informada pelo usuário na entrada, com o mesmo algoritmo de criptografia utilizado no C#, para compara-la com a credencial salva no aplicativo.

As senhas não serão alteradas no aplicativo, sendo possível apenas no sistema legado onde o Web Service consulta. E toda a estrategia para manter estes dados sincronizados (aplicativo *offline* e sistema legado) já está implementada.

**Dúvida**

Não entendo muito bem os algoritmos de criptografia, a ponto de saber como eles funcionam internamente, por exemplo: não sei se o md5 do C# tem o mesmo funcionamento interno do md5 do Java, ou seja, se sempre com a mesma entrada eles vão ter a mesma saída, independente de ser em Java ou em C#.

**Então gostaria de saber se existe algum algoritmo de criptografia, comum às duas tecnologias, que eu possa usar com confiabilidade em meu caso?**

Comment: Não com a intenção de responder a pergunta, mas para dar uma noção geral, recomendo a leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura . Quanto às funções utilizadas, são comuns as implementações para várias linguagens. Armazenar algum resultado de bcrypt na versão offline, por exemplo, resolveria. MD5, por outro lado, não vai te ajudar muito.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bem após analisar as opções apontadas por vocês, implementei a minha solução utilizando **Pbkdf2** que foi a seguinte:

Em C#, segui [este](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32856/secure-password-hashing-in-net-code-review) exemplo ficando assim minha implementação:

```cs
// este retorna em bytes (byte[])
public static byte[] PBKDF2(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
    pbkdf2.IterationCount = iterations;
    return pbkdf2.GetBytes(outputBytes);
}

// Esse retorna em Base64 (que é o que uso no fim)
public static string PBKDF2ToBase64(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, outputBytes));
}
```

Em Java, segui [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java) e [este](https://gist.github.com/jtan189/3804290) exemplo ficando assim minha implementação:

```java
private static final int KEYLENGTH_MULTIPLIER = 8;
// este retorna em bytes (byte[])
public static byte[] PBKDF2(String password, byte[] salt, int iterations,
        int outputBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations,
            outputBytes * KEYLENGTH_MULTIPLIER);
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    return f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}

// Esse retorna em Base64 (que é o que uso no fim)
public static String PBKDF2ToBase64(String password, byte[] salt, int iterations,
        int outputBytes){
    try {
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, outputBytes)), "UTF-8");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

A biblioteca que estou utilizando para converter para Base64 em Java é [essa](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html), e no Android o método `encodeBase64String`, não funciona e fiz uma adaptação com o método `encodeBase64` conforme [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method) sugestão.

> Aparentemente tudo está funcionando perfeito, tanto em C#, quanto em Java (Android), se observarem alguma melhoria, ela será bem vinda. Obrigado a todos pelo auxilio.

---

**Explicação de parâmetros:**

> Os parâmetros `salt`, `iterations`, `outputBytes` são parâmetros de configuração do método de Hash, e podem ser utilizados como chaves secretas de sua aplicação.

Onde:

1. [`salt`: Ou sal em Português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_(criptografia))
2. `iterations`: Quantidade de iterações para calcular o hash, quanto maior esse valor maior o tempo de processamento do hash;
3. `outputBytes`: Quantidade de bytes de saída do hash;

---

**Exemplo de utilização:**

**C#:**

```cs
private int LengthOutputBytes = 32;
private byte[] Salt = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x23, 0x65, 0x46, 0x43, 0x24, 0x55, 0x23, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x34, 0x72, 0x18, 0x67, 0x68 };
private int HashIterations = 10;
private string password = "123";

string hash = PBKDF2ToBase64(password, Salt, HashIterations, LengthOutputBytes);
```

**Java:**

```java
private byte[] SALT = { 0x20, 0x23, 0x65, 0x46, 0x43, 0x24,
        0x55, 0x23, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x34, 0x72, 0x18, 0x67, 0x68 };
private int ITERATIONS = 10;
private int OUTPUTBYTES = 32;
private String password = "123";

String hash = PBKDF2ToBase64(password, SALT, ITERATIONS, OUTPUTBYTES);
```

Answer (score 16):

Do que eu entendi que são suas perguntas:

1. Sim, os "mecanismos de criptografia" são os mesmos, ou seja: implementado o mesmo algoritmo com os mesmos parâmetros de inicialização, o resultado obtido deverá ser o mesmo = saídas idênticas.
2. O MD5 não é exatamente criptografia, ele é um *hash*: pega uma entrada de um tamanho qualquer e transforma isto em uma saída de um tamanho fixo. E é irreversível: a partir da saída produzida você não consegue (ou não deveria conseguir) dizer qual foi a entrada.
3. A saída MD5 de uma biblioteca Java deveria ser a mesma de uma biblioteca C# que deveria ser a mesma de Perl que deveria ser a mesma de um programa .EXE que calcule um hash MD5.

E se eu entendi, você quer ter uma aplicação em C# em um servidor que verifique a senha do usuário, isto ? E quer que seu aplicativo em Java armazene a mesma senha no dispositivo (celular?) e que o usuário digite a senha para entrar no aplicativo, isto ? Por ex., se usuário estiver conectado, digita a senha e ela é validada no servidor, se usuário estiver offline, digita a senha e é validado no aplicativo ?

Se for isto, então: (o que penso ser a melhor abordagem)

1. offline: No primeiro uso ou instalação, a senha é digitada pelo usuário, o seu aplicativo java faz o hash dela (usando bcrypt ou scrypt ou pbkdf2, MD5 não é mais indicado já faz um tempo) e guarda no dispositivo. Na próxima vez que o usuário for fazer o login offline, o aplicativo faz o hash novamente e compara se o hash guardado é o mesmo do hash que acabou de ser calculado, e autoriza ou não o usuário.
2. online: tudo igual ao passo 1, só que é guardada no servidor e não no dispositivo. Lembre-se que é um acesso via internet com uma senha "em aberto", ou seja, em *plain text*, e qualquer um que intercepte a comunicação poderia ver a senha. Use mecanismos de criptografia de comunicação (Https, etc).
3. sincronia da senha offline - online : junto com a senha armazene um valor de quando foi a última vez que a senha foi alterada. Quando o aplicativo estiver no modo online, mande o hash da senha e a data para o servidor: se a senha do dispositivo for a mais recente, atualiza a do servidor.
4. troca de senha: toda vez que o usuário trocar a senha online, aplicativo troca a senha offline (calcula o hash e guarda no offline), e isto completa o passo 3. Toda vez que trocar offline, o item 3 fará ela ser sincronizada com o servidor no primeiro acesso.

E, principalmente, aprenda bem a armazenar de forma segura a senha no dispositivo. Mesmo ela sendo guardada na forma de hash, sempre poderá ser possível a um atacante tentar alterar este hash para um hash que ele conhece (ou seja, ele vai colocar o hash de uma senha que ele conhece, então ele saberá a senha). Cada sistema operacional (Android, iOs) possui mecanismos para restringir este tipo de acesso, aprenda como usá-los.

Comment: Você considera conveniente, utilizar [tag:md5], como hash para essa finalidade, ou há algo mais interessante?

Comment: Ops, eu estava editando a pergunta ao mesmo tempo :). MD5 é considerado fraco (pois é muito fácil/rápido calcular milhões/bilhões de hashes MD5). Vá com bcrypt ou scrypt ou pbkdf2, e veja o link que o Bacco colocou lá no comentário da sua pergunta

Comment: Sim, foi problema de simultaneidade. hehe. Eu li o tópico do link do @bacco, e é muito bom alias, vou estudar os algoritmos citados, e a respeito de restringir o acesso a senha armazenada, o [tag:android] tem um grande problema que é o acesso root ao dispositivo, onde o atacante teria acesso, aos arquivos e base de dados do aplicativo. E não sei como agir para evitar isso?

Comment: É inevitável. Se um invasor tem acesso ao hardware (computador, celular, etc), ele tem tudo. Você pode dificultar, não impedir. Se você utilizar hashes fortes (tipo pbkdf2) com salt, ele vai ter o hash, e vai levar zilhões de anos para quebrar. Mas se senha for fraca (tipo 123456), não tem tecnologia que resolva. Se ele instalar um keylogger no celular e usuário digitar senha, também não tem o que vc possa fazer. Se ele filmar usuário digitando a senha, idem :). Inevitável isto.

Comment: Boa colocação, _"Você pode dificultar"_, essa é a ideia. Entre as tecnicas que você citou na resposta, tem algum que você me indica e que já haja implementação tanto em [tag:java] quanto em [tag:c#], e que seja razoavelmente seguro e fácil de implementar. Já que no meu caso (por enquanto), uma segurança, mesmo que não muito forte já é o suficiente. (algo é melhor que nada, ^^)

Comment: Pbkdf2 para c#: http://www.shawnmclean.com/blog/2012/04/simplecrypto-net-a-pbkdf2-hashing-wrapper-for-net-framework/ e para java http://bouncycastle.org/ . Eu não verifiquei se os parâmetros são os mesmos, ou seja, se vc pode setar o número de iterações, o salt...

Comment: Para quem editou: desculpe, dei um rollback porque a edição deixou a pergunta cheia de links para tags aqui do Stackoverflow. O objetivo das tags é só facilitar busca por perguntas. Acho que links nas respostas só seriam bons se forem para sites que expliquem melhor algo (ex.: link em "criptografia" para um site que explique o que é criptografia)

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxilo, foi muito util, postei minha solução

Comment: @Fernando: você pode marcar como aceita a sua resposta (já que é o que resolveu mesmo o problema). Obrigado por ter aceito a minha, ganho pontos com isto, mas posso perde-los e vc aceitar a melhor resposta (a sua :) )

Answer (score 4):

O processos criptográficos como MD-5, AES, Base64, etc, funcionam igualmente independente da linguagem que os implementa. Eu tenho um projeto em C#.NET que pode sanar, acredito eu, seus problemas em implementar uma criptografia utilizando C#. [Pode acessá-lo aqui](https://github.com/Openbytes/FileCypher).

- [O teste de como usar a classe de criptografia AES](https://github.com/Openbytes/FileCypher/blob/master/Openbytes.Cryptography.Test/Schemas/AES/AESCypherTest.cs).

Basta compilar o projeto e utilizar a DLL.