# Criptografia com Java

Tags: java, segurança, criptografia, md5

Preciso fazer criptografia dos dados em uma sessão de autenticação de usuario, e gostaria de saber qual melhor maneira, e mais segura de trabalhar com criptografia com Java. Se é usando Salt, MD5, AES, SHA, ou outra? 
Quais API's recomendada para este trabalho?
Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada modo de criptografar os dados.

Comment: O que você está realmente tentando fazer? Criptografia é muito delicado, é muito muito fácil fazer algo que pareça seguro mais não seja, cuidado. Regra de ouro nessa área: use uma biblioteca, **nunca** implemente você mesmo um algoritmo a não ser que saiba exatamente o que está fazendo.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Preciso usar na área de autenticação de usuário em um sistema web. Qual biblioteca você me recomenda a usar? Em asp.net eu conheço bem, mas em Java eu não tenho conhecimento muito afundo a respeito de criptografia e bibliotecas que fazem esse trabalho.

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento específico de java, mas acredito que [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) seja o que está procurando.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer criar uma autenticação utilizando hash para guardar a senha, e quer saber qual melhor forma (mais segura e eficiente) e quais bibliotecas/frameworks pode utilizar? Certo? Se for isso recomendo dar uma olhada nesses dois topicos aqui mesmo do SO-PT: [Algoritmo em Java (com PBKDF2)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13835/2998) e [esse que trata de "Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura), acredito que não irá responder sua pergunta, mas irá lhe ajudar e entender o problema.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda @Fernando vou olhar esses tópicos e ver o que consigo com eles. Obrigado.

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender exatamente quais dados devem ser encriptados num login de sistema web por código Java. A primeira precaução é usar SSL/HTTPS. O que o Fernando comentou faz sentido, mas não tem a ver com "sessão de autenticação" e sim na forma como as senhas são armazenadas no banco de dados. É isso mesmo? Se for, é bom entender que esses algoritmos não dependem de plataforma. Se você já usa algum em C#, o efeito do ponto de vista de segurança será o mesmo em Java ou qualquer linguagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que li nos seus comentários, a criptografia servirá para um sistema Web desenvolvido em Java. Já ouviu falar do *framework* [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)? Ele te possibilita implementar regras de autenticação e controles de acesso de uma forma relativamente simples. Eu mesmo já desenvolvi um sistema em Java Web com login e controles de acesso utilizando como criptografia o [bCrypt](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), que é muito melhor que o MD5 que está ficando (ou já ficou) obsoleto.

Comment: Já ouvi falar do Sprint Segurity sim @Electus, o problema é que estão evitando usar frameworks, então estou deixando isso como segunda opção caso eu não encontre outra escapatória. Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: @EricoSouza "Evitando usar frameworks" é o mesmo que "nós achamos melhor reinventar uma roda tosca". Claro que você pode usar diretamente o bCrypt e se você já usa algum outro framework sei que pode "pesar" adicionar mais um outro, mas considere que o Spring Security é uma das ferramentas mais maduras e flexíveis disponíveis atualmente. Só mais uma observação: todos os projetos que conheço onde a "segurança" foi implementada manualmente acabaram cedo ou tarde com problemas por causa disso, seja nas mãos de um usuário mais "espertinho" que aprende a burlar a segurança ou de um especialista.

Comment: @utluiz pois é, concordo contigo, mas o meu gerente foi claramente a respeito de frameworks, ele queria algo "puro". Não sei se ele teve más experiencias, mas tenho a impressão que ele acha que todo framework só tra probelmas. Porem, eu conhecendo os riscos de desenvolvermos algo do zero, principalmente a respeito de criptografia, desenvolvi uma rotina, mas bati o pé, documentei os riscos, e indiquei o uso do Spring Security. Esses frameworks confiaveis estão ai pra facilitar a nossa vida.

Answer (score 3):

Eu não entendi muito bem como você está fazendo sua sessão, se é por HEADER Basic a cada requisição.

Ex: HTTP Authentication Basic MD5(username:password)

Se for, eu aconselharia utilizar o flow password do [OAUTH2](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified).

Que nada mais é do que persistir a sessão do usuário em um banco de dados e trafegar um identificador ao invez dos dados de acesso, claro que com algumas convenções de nome de endpoint e parametros.

Agora quanto aos metodos de criptografia eu com certeza indicaria o bcrypt.

**Porque?**

**O MD5** gera sempre o mesmo hash, ou seja se você cryptografar um valor, o hash para esse valor vai ser sempre o mesmo, isso facilita o atacante que com algum esforço pode ir fazendo o hash até chegar no valor.

exemplo:

```
Se eu fizer o hasg desse texto:
    MD5("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") = 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
Se fizer denovo, da o mesmo valor:
    MD5("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") = 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
```

**O Bcrypt** gera sempre um hash diferente, que quando comparado com um outro hash gerado ele retorna se é valido ou não.

exemplo:

```
Se eu fizer o hash desse texto:
    Bcrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") = "$2a$10$o2o0OMLJh4M6EQuF9Tk/Ceidt/JSFOpPzNl6WSIQV9ip.VyrlW8py"
Se eu fizer denovo, o valor sai diferente:
    Bcrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") = "$83e912b45ea3cbd8f99163323dt/JSFOpPzNl6WSIQV9ip.1313aC"
Mas se você comprar os dois atraves de uma função do Bcrypt
    Bcrypt.compare("$83e912b45ea3cbd8f99163323dt/JSFOpPzNl6WSIQV9ip.1313aC", "$2a$10$o2o0OMLJh4M6EQuF9Tk/Ceidt/JSFOpPzNl6WSIQV9ip.VyrlW8py") == true
```

Conclusão básica, comparar o hash através de uma função (propositadamente) lenta, faz com que fique muito difícil e lento o atacante chegar no valor correto, então de preferência ao bcrypt ou algum algoritmo de comparação para dados sigilosos.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta @Rodrigo, na verdade como eu ainda não havia trabalhado com criptografia em java, estava na dúvida na melhor e mais aconselhável maneira de faze-la. Gostei da sua explicação a respeito do bCrypt, e de sua indicação a respeito do OAuth2. vlw

Comment: Tem algo muito estranho nesse exemplo do Bcrypt: primeiro, as saídas têm comprimentos diferentes (deveriam dar sempre o mesmo); segundo, você está comparando dois hashes diferentes e ele está dando true?! De onde é esse exemplo, você por acaso lembra da fonte? Com certeza tem algo errado aí...

Comment: Olá, o exemplo é meu mesmo, não peguei de lugar nenhum.
Pode executar o código, na resposta eu explico o que está acontecendo, copiando ("O Bcrypt gera sempre um hash diferente, que quando comparado com um outro hash gerado ele retorna se é valido ou não.").
Mas só para add alguma coisa nova e não só copiar, o bcrypt é seguro justamente por causa disso, sempre que você gera um hash ele gera com um valor diferente, mas os dois comparados com a função dele ( não com o igual do javascript ) retornam true (verdadeiro).