# Divergência em criptografar e descriptografar em Java e C# algoritmo Aes

Tags: java, c#, criptografia, aes

Tenho dois projetos um em Java e outro em C# onde os dois se comunicam entre si, e uma das funções e criptografar e descriptografar as informações confidenciais entre eles, utilizando [algoritmo Aes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx), estou tentando criptografar com C# da seguinte forma.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Aes_Example
{
    class AesExample
    {
        // Mensagem que sera criptografada.
        const string mensagem = "Mensagem que sera criptografada.";
        // Senha definida da operadora.
        const String chave = "uexDPnPr";

        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chave);
                byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
                int len = pwdBytes.Length;
                if (len > keyBytes.Length)
                {
                    len = keyBytes.Length;
                }

                Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);

                using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create("AES"))
                {
                    myAes.Key = keyBytes;

                    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(mensagem, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
                    string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    String TESTE = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
                    Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", mensagem);
                    Console.WriteLine("Criptografado: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
                    Console.WriteLine("Descriptografado: {0}", roundtrip);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {

                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting  stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return plaintext;
        }
    }
}
```

Isso me retorna uma string criptografada assim,

> NElQHsXIpc+bHezzad/Ubzj94+1YKomH5LwmlDUseQtGs9veFPmUexy82KJTsBVD

E do lado Java tenho.

```
package Teste;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public final class Criptografia {

    private static final String ALGORITMO = "AES";

    public static String criptografar(String mensagem, String chave) throws Exception {

        final Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, chave);

        final byte[] criptografado = cipher.doFinal(mensagem.getBytes());

        return StringUtils.trim(Base64.encodeBase64String(criptografado));
    }

    public static String descriptografar(String mensagem, String chave) throws Exception {

        final Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chave);

        final byte[] descriptografado = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(mensagem));

        return new String(descriptografado, "UTF-8");
    }

    private static Cipher getCipher(final int encryptMode, final String chave) throws Exception {

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITMO);
        cipher.init(encryptMode, buildKey(chave));

        return cipher;
    }

    private static Key buildKey(String chave) throws Exception {

        final MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        final byte[] key = Arrays.copyOf(messageDigest.digest(chave.getBytes("UTF-8")), 16);

        return new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITMO);
    }

    /**
     * Classe de exemplo de utilizacao. Futuramente passar para o padrao JUnit.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            nao precisa informar
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *             erro na criptografia
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Mensagem que sera criptografada.
        final String mensagem = "Mensagem que sera criptografada.";

        // Senha definida da operadora.
        final String chave = "uexDPnPr";

        // Valor criptografado.
        String criptografado = Criptografia.criptografar(mensagem, chave);
        System.out.printf("Valor criptografado: '%s' %n", criptografado);

        // Valor original.
        String descriptografado = Criptografia.descriptografar(criptografado, chave);
        System.out.printf("Valor descriptografado: '%s'", descriptografado);
    }

}
```

Gerando a criptografia.

> JGTfV+CntuSutHK0LLeZix9Teu87ynjpJN8d3OaQdWge6yN0stn7/1I5KmMJEFYk

A dificuldade aqui e encontra uma forma que coincida a criptografia gerada no C# sendo que **a parte do java não posso altera devido ser do cliente**, já cheguei a ver alguns assuntos sobre isso no stackoverflow gringo, mas todos que vi não compreendi como corrigir isso.

Resumindo; preciso que a criptografia gerada no C# seja idêntica a gerada no java.

> Para a mensagem = "Mensagem que sera criptografada.";
>
> e a chave = "uexDPnPr";

Tenho hoje.

**No C#**

> NElQHsXIpc+bHezzad/Ubzj94+1YKomH5LwmlDUseQtGs9veFPmUexy82KJTsBVD

Esta criptografia do C# tem que ser idética a do java abaixo.

**e no Java.**

> JGTfV+CntuSutHK0LLeZix9Teu87ynjpJN8d3OaQdWge6yN0stn7/1I5KmMJEFYk

Comment: Apareceu nas sugeridas, não sei se você chegou a ver ou se essa aqui ajuda de alguma forma, mas vale a pena a sugestão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12206/algoritmo-de-criptografia-comum-entre-java-e-c?rq=1

Comment: @diegofm, tinha visto sim, mas usa outro tipo de criptografia.

Comment: Goku, dê uma olhada [nessa resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698272). Tente esse `RijndaelManaged` com `BlockSize = 128`, `aesEncryption.KeySize = 256` e chaves de 32 bytes (256 bits). Se funcionar me dê um toque que eu escrevo uma resposta.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, tinha visto isso, mas não consegui fazer com que ficasse iguais as criptografias, se conseguir uma solução fico grato e você fique com a gratificação.

Comment: Você quer que as duas `strings` produzidas (C# e Java) sejam exatamente iguais? Ou está com dificuldade para fazer os dois sistemas se comunicarem?

Comment: @Gomiero, Que a string gerada no C# seja igual a do Java.

Comment: Sem acesso ao código Java, provavelmente não tem como fazer isso devido ao [Vetor de inicialização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_de_opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(criptografia)#Vetor_de_inicializa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_.28IV.29) (no seu código C#: `myAes.IV`), que teria que ser o mesmo nas duas implementações. O `IV` normalmente é aleatório ([Sal (criptografia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_(criptografia))) e se você fixá-lo direto nos códigos (C# e Java), irá reduzir muito a segurança do algoritmo.

Comment: @Gomiero, se eu recebe o IV do java como parâmetro teria como fazer?

Comment: Sim! Se todos os parâmetros do algoritmo (ex: `IV`, tamanho do bloco, tamanho da chave) forem os mesmos, você consegue gerar sempre a mesma *string* com qualquer linguagem de programação. Porém, acredito que você precise avaliar bem o contexto do sistema como um todo (ex: o `IV` irá transitar entre as aplicações Java e C# através de uma conexão insegura?) para evitar problemas de segurança :)

Comment: @Gomiero, fiz um cipher.getIV(); e ele sempre me retorna NULL.

Comment: A instância (`cipher`) está usando o padrão [ECB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_de_opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(criptografia)#Modo_ECB_.28Electronic_CodeBook.29), sem o IV (INSEGURO!). Alterando a inicialização para, por exemplo: `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` (modo CBC, padrão no .NET), o `getIV()` funcionará (essas *strings* estão na documentação do [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)). Há outras alternativas (como alterar o código C# para usar o modo ECB e "zerar" o IV), porém, são más-práticas de programação e não recomendo utilizá-las :)

Comment: Não entendi o porquê do buildKeys (que vai gerar uma hash e modificar a chave) no Java. Sugiro tirar a chamada à buildKeys e forçar uma mensagem de debug logo antes de chamar as funções de cifragem contendo a chave e a mensagem (tanto no C# quanto no Java); ambas variáveis tem que ter o mesmo conteúdo e tamanho.

Comment: @osmarcf, obrigado pela dica, mas acho que você não leu a pergunta completamente, o lado java é do cliente.

Comment: Perdão, não captei essa informação!
De qualquer forma, é só virar minha sugestão (multiplica por -1): pegar os 16 primeiros bytes do cálculo da hash SHA-256 da chave (em UTF-8) no C# antes de cifrar (que é o que o buildKeys do Java está fazendo). Você está dando o copy, com a len de 16 (0x10), mas não está fazendo isso deopis de calcular o SHA-256. Uma hash de um texto deve ser igual, se o texto de entrada e o algoritmo for igual.
Mesmo sendo código que você não pode mudar, você pode compilar ele localmente para testar (e colocar mensagens de debug)?

Comment: @osmarcf , não entendi muito bem como seria isso.

Comment: @osmarcf, não é possível multiplicar por -1 o [Intervalo do byte  é de 0 a 255](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/5bdb6693.aspx), o que faria isso é o sbyte  mas ele é incompatível com o Key que é do tipo byte .

Comment: Infelizmente a piada sobre multiplicar por -1 não deu certo (para inverter a forma de pensar).

Tente substituir a linha que lê a **chave**:


`byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chave);`


pelo código que gera a hash SHA-256 dela:


`using (SHA256 hash = SHA256Managed.Create()) {
    Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
    byte[] pwdBytes = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(chave));
}`

Peguei do (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999361/obtain-sha-256-string-of-a-string)

Não estou com um compilador C# aqui para testar, espero que funcione!

Comment: @osmarcf, Já tinha visto isso. Não dar certo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Primeiro vamos fazer seu código funcionar

Existem três principais diferenças entre as implementações C# e Java da sua pergunta:

### A chave

O algoritmo do lado do Java está computando um *hash* (SHA-256) da chave original e selecionando os primeiros 128 bits (16 bytes) do resultado como chave do algoritmo AES. A escolha é bastante peculiar, porém pode ser imitada do lado do C#:

```
static byte[] BuildKey(string chave)
{
    SHA256Managed sha256algorithm = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] originalKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chave);
    byte[] keyBytes = sha256algorithm.ComputeHash(originalKeyBytes);
    // primeiros 16 bytes do SHA-256            
    Array.Resize(ref keyBytes, 16);

    return keyBytes;
}
```

### A cifra

O processo de criptografia vai muito além do algoritmo. Ao especificar uma cifra também precisamos falar do [modo de operação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_de_opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(criptografia)) e [da técnica de *padding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) (preenchimento de bits extras dentro de um bloco). Outros parâmetros a serem considerados são o tamanho do bloco e da chave.

Do lado do Java, `Cipher.getInstance("AES")`é equivalente a string de especificação `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (128)`. Por sinal, [esse é um detalhe de implementação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Cipher). É sempre recomendável usar a string completa.

Isso significa que quando você requisita uma cifra no padrão AES o Java te dará um algoritmo específico (Rijndael), em modo *Electronic CodeBook* (*ECB*) com *padding* do tipo PKCS#5 ([na verdade PKCS#7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20770158/664577), mas esse é outro assunto) e tamanho do bloco e da chave = 128 bits.

Já do lado do C# o [modo de operação padrão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode.aspx) é *Cipher-block chaining* (CBC) e [*padding* padrão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx) PKCS#7

Para que o resultado seja o mesmo dos dois lados precisamos instruí-los para usarem a mesma "configuração". Como você não quer mudar nada do lado do Java, eis a solução do lado do C#:

```
static SymmetricAlgorithm GetCipher(byte[] key)
{
    Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create("AES");
    aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
    aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
    aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    aesAlg.Padding =  PaddingMode.PKCS7;  
    aesAlg.Key = key;

    return aesAlg;
}
```

A grande maioria dessas propriedades possuem valores *default* razoáveis; na prática as únicas duas alterações que estão fazendo diferença nesse exemplo são o `Mode = CipherMode.ECB` e `Key = key`. Dito isso, em código relacionado a criptografia eu prefiro ser explicito sempre que possível.

Finalmente podemos utilizar a configuração acima durante as chamadas para criptografar / descriptografar o texto:

```
using (SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg = GetCipher(Key))
{
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
    // Ou
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV); 
    // [...] Restante do seu código...
 }
```

*Et voilá*

```
Original:   Mensagem que sera criptografada. 
Criptografado: JGTfV+CntuSutHK0LLeZix9Teu87ynjpJN8d3OaQdWge6yN0stn7/1I5KmMJEFYk
Descriptografado: Mensagem que sera criptografada.
```

#### [Exemplo funcional no Ideone](http://ideone.com/rKpR3J)

---

## Agora vamos tentar entender mais algumas coisas

### O que é vetor de inicialização?

A grande fraqueza do modo *ECB* é que blocos de entrada iguais sempre geram saídas iguais. Isso significa que de certa forma parte da estrutura original é conservada. Com algum conhecimento de criptoanálise e da estrutura / conteúdo original é possível extrair bastante informação do conteúdo cifrado.

Outros modos de operação utilizam algum "estado" durante a transformação (e.g., informações do bloco anterior, um contador, blocos aleatórios "descartáveis", etc) para produzir variações no conteúdo cifrado. Em geral isso dificulta a paralelização das operações de transformação em um *trade-off* por maior segurança.

O vetor de inicialização (*IV*) nada mais é do que o "estado" a ser utilizado inicialmente. Este valor deve ser o mais aleatório possível; [reutilizar o vetor de inicialização pode comprometer a segurança da aplicação](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059609995/crypto-noobs-1-initialization-vectors).

Conforme [os comentários na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152080/diverg%C3%AAncia-em-criptografar-e-descriptografar-em-java-e-c-algoritmo-aes#comment314705_152080) e [a resposta do Marcos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152932/100), Java e C# adotam estratégias diferentes em relação ao *IV*.

Como um vetor de inicialização não faz sentido para o modo de operação *ECB* o Java não faz nada em relação ao *IV*, i.e., [`cipher.getIV()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getIV--) `== null`. Se você escolhesse um modo de operação em que o *IV* fizesse sentido (e.g. *CBC*) o Java geraria um valor aleatório.

Já no C# um *IV* aleatório é sempre gerado por padrão, porém o mesmo é completamente ignorado no modo de operação *ECB*, não fazendo nenhuma diferença para o resultado final da cifra.

```
Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create("AES");
// IV aleatório toda vez que você instancia  `Aes`
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", aesAlg.IV));
```

De qualquer forma, não custa nada "zerar" o *IV* explicitamente:

```
aesAlg.IV = new byte[16];
```

### Então essa solução é fraca?

**Sim!** Pelos motivos explicados acima, fora de contextos muito específicos (blocos únicos de informação sem grande relevância semântica), operar em modo *ECB* é uma [péssima](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946) ideia! Do ponto de vista de segurança esse tipo de solução é [bastante amadora](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22958889/664577)! Sério mesmo, [não tente encontrar motivos](https://www.quora.com/Is-AES-ECB-mode-useful-for-anything) para justificar uso de *ECB*.

[image: Wikipedia - Fraqueza do ECB]

Uma solução minimamente satisfatória seria [operar em modo *CBC*, gerar um vetor de inicialização e compartilhá-lo com o cliente](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/block_modes_java.shtml). Uma ideia melhor ainda seria usar uma solução de [criptografia autenticada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption). Na maioria dos casos porém, jogar a responsabilidade da criptografia para fora do seu código (e.g., [TLS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)) é a solução mais fácil e correta. Se você está usando um servidor de aplicação o problema se torna de infraestrutura (i.e., obter um certificado e configurar suporte ao protocólogo https). Se você não tem essa sorte, sempre é possível usar uma biblioteca comum ao Java e C# como [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).

### Mas o código do lado Java é externo/proprietário/ofuscado

Sempre dá para fazer alguma coisa. Nem que essa alguma coisa seja entrar em contato com o cliente e dizer para ele ler esse post. O ponto principal aqui é que todo essa esforço de criptografia manual não está ajudando muito a segurança da sua aplicação.

Conforme os pontos acima, você ganha mais trocando informações via https do que tentando reinventar a roda. Caso a aplicação cliente possua um modo de operação "inseguro" (sem criptografia) que tal sugerir isso para ele? Use o modo inseguro sobre https.

Caso contrário eu avaliaria se a troca de informação entre as aplicações realmente tem que ser segura. Nesse caso eu me voluntariaria para escrever algo no meio de caminho entre a sua aplicação e o cliente para garantir segurança de verdade. Por exemplo, você pode escrever uma camada do lado cliente para falar com sua aplicação C# de forma segura.

Se o seu cliente realmente for completamente irredutível você pode até manter toda essa lógica com AES/ECB do lado dele, desde que esse seja só um esquema de criptografia *on-site*. Da rede dele para fora eu ao menos embrulharia as mensagens em um esquema de segurança mais bem pensado.

Em suma: O problema de código está resolvido. O problema de segurança continua pendente.

---

### Referências:

1. [Wikipedia - Modo de operação (criptografia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_de_opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(criptografia))
2. [Wikipedia - Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography))
3. [Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide - The Cipher Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Cipher)
4. [SOen - AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding vs AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding with 256 key size performance java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20770158/664577)
5. [MSDN - SymmetricAlgorithm.Mode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode.aspx)
6. [MSDN - SymmetricAlgorithm.Padding Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx)
7. [Cipher (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getIV--)
8. [Crypto - Why shouldn't I use ECB encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946)
9. [SOen - How to choose an AES encryption mode (CBC ECB CTR OCB CFB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22958889/664577)
10. [Is AES ECB mode useful for anything?](https://www.quora.com/Is-AES-ECB-mode-useful-for-anything)
11. [Crypto Fails — Crypto Noobs #1: Initialization Vectors](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059609995/crypto-noobs-1-initialization-vectors)
12. [Javamex - Using block modes and initialisation vectors in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/block_modes_java.shtml)
13. [Wikipedia - Authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption)
14. [Wikipedia - Transport Layer Security](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)
15. [The Legion of the Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

---

P.S.: Perdão se desrespeitei alguma convenção de código do C#. Essa não é uma linguagem que eu use no dia a dia. Sinta-se livre para editar minha resposta e corrigir / melhorar tudo o que achar conveniente.

Comment: Eu apoio esta resposta. Quem usa ECB, não sabe o que faz.

Comment: Apesar de não dominar o assunto, a resposta está excelente. Mesmo sendo bastante leigo em criptografia, consegui entender seu ponto vista. Esse tipo de resposta eleva bastante a qualidade do site! :)

Comment: +1 pelo `ECB Penguin` :)

Answer (score 8):

No código .NET, apenas uma alteração. Inicializando o IV, sempre com o mesmo valor:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Aes_Example
    {
    class AesExample
    {
        // Mensagem que sera criptografada.
        const string mensagem = "Mensagem que sera criptografada.";
        // Senha definida da operadora.
        const String chave = "uexDPnPr";

        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chave);
                byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
                int len = pwdBytes.Length;
                if (len > keyBytes.Length)
                {
                    len = keyBytes.Length;
                }

                Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);

                using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create("AES"))
                {
                    myAes.Key = keyBytes;
                    myAes.IV = new byte[0x10];//IV é zeroooooooooooooooo

                    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(mensagem, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
                    string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    String TESTE = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
                    Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", mensagem);
                    Console.WriteLine("Criptografado: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
                    Console.WriteLine("Descriptografado: {0}", roundtrip);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {

                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting  stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return plaintext;
        }
    }
}
```

No Java:

```
    package teste;

    import java.security.Key;
    import java.util.Base64;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    public final class Criptografia {

    private static final String ALGORITMO = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    public static String criptografar(String mensagem, String chave) throws Exception {

        final Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, chave);

        final byte[] criptografado = cipher.doFinal(mensagem.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(criptografado);
    }

    public static String descriptografar(String mensagem, String chave) throws Exception {

        final Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chave);

        final byte[] descriptografado = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(mensagem));

        return new String(descriptografado, "UTF-8");
    }

    private static Cipher getCipher(final int encryptMode, final String chave) throws Exception {

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITMO);
        cipher.init(encryptMode, buildKey(chave), new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16], 0, 16));

        return cipher;
    }

    private static Key buildKey(String chave) throws Exception {

        byte[] utf8 = chave.getBytes("UTF-8");
        final byte[] key = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(utf8, 0, key, 0, utf8.length < 16 ? utf8.length : 16);

        return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }

    /**
     * Classe de exemplo de utilizacao. Futuramente passar para o padrao JUnit.
     *
     * @param args nao precisa informar
     *
     * @throws Exception erro na criptografia
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Mensagem que sera criptografada.
        final String mensagem = "Mensagem que sera criptografada.";

        // Senha definida da operadora.
        final String chave = "uexDPnPr";

        // Valor criptografado.
        String criptografado = Criptografia.criptografar(mensagem, chave);
        System.out.printf("Valor criptografado: '%s' %n", criptografado);

        // Valor original.
        String descriptografado = Criptografia.descriptografar(criptografado, chave);
        System.out.printf("Valor descriptografado: '%s'", descriptografado);
    }

}
```

Apenas alterei o código o suficiente para fazer funcionar. Agora o valor deve ser:

> MlHaz/gOfy+9n/lptTYhqIAjRxqZAwH0hKkQoqyE+DTIV1WB6Tain322hk2yWnjw

É bem fraquinho o jeito que a chave é gerada ali. Eu sugiro usar PBKDF2 ou algo melhor. Se possível, trocar CBC para CTR (talvez seja necessário substituir o Policy File).

Comment: GOKU, na verdade o Marcos está certo. Eu estou preparando uma resposta para o seu problema, mas a sua *constraint* de não alterar o lado do Java compromete toda a segurança do sistema. O comportamento *default* do lado do java é usar `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`. Essa combinação, fora de aplicações muito específicas, é bem inútil do ponto de vista de segurança. O fato do código original não especificar o modo de cifra e padding já demonstra que quem escreveu essa parte não tinha muita ideia do que estava fazendo. Eu vou te dar uma "solução", mas o marcos está certo, o buraco é mais embaixo.

Comment: Bem, é o jeito que eu decidi resolver o seu problema e do seu cliente. O senhor Anthony Accioly explicou muito bem os motivos. Nem me dei ao trabalho de deixar o hash SHA ali, por ser fácil de aplicar _dictionary_ _attack_ e _rainbow_ _tables_.

Answer (score 3):

Use [IKVM.net](https://www.ikvm.net/) e compile a classe Java em .NET. Assim é certeza que sai igual:

### Edição:

Passo a passo:

1. [Baixe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ikvm/files/) e [instale](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/install.html) o IKVM.net:
2. Compile o seu código Java:

   ```
    javac Aes_Example.java
   ```

   **Saída:**  `Aes_Example.class`
3. Gere um Assembly .NET a partir da classe:

   ```
    ikvmc -target:library Aes_Example.class
   ```

   **Saída**:  `Aes_Example.dll`
4. Aí você pega a dll e usa no projeto C#!

---

Para mais informações: http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tutorial.html