# Criptografia C# equivalente em java

Tags: java, c#, criptografia

Tenho o método abaixo em C# e preciso fazer algo equivalente em JAVA, mas não estou conseguindo. Poderiam me ajudar?

```
private const string chave = "eMbARaLhaDo";

public static string Descriptografar(string Message)
{
    byte[] Results;
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(chave));
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
    TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(Message);       
    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
        Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
        HashProvider.Clear();
    }
    return UTF8.GetString(Results);
}
```

Eu tentei o código abaixo, mas não deu certo:

```
public static String decodificar(String key, String text) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] encData = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(text);
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    byte[] tdesKeyData = md.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "AES");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey);
    byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(encData);
    return new String(plainText);
}
```

Comment: Talvez isso possa lhe ajudar: [**Algoritmo de criptografia comum entre Java e C#**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12206/2998)

Comment: [Essa solução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13835/2998) que adotei em meu projeto, quando tive esse problema.

Comment: Fernando, obrigado pela resposta! 
Não entendi o que são os parâmetros: byte[] salt, int iterations,  int outputBytes

Comment: El Diablo, atualizei a reposta lá, com uma explicação dos parâmetros e com um exemplo de utilização para cada linguagem.

Comment: Maravilha Fernando! Eu meio que peguei o bonde andando aqui e me passaram esse método em C#, para fazer um equivalente em java, ou seja, não tenho essas informações de salt, iterations e nem outputBytes. É possível descobrir na unha?

Comment: El Diablo, desculpe não responder antes. Na unha acho difícil (ou talvez impossível). Então primeiro você tem que estudar o que o método em C# utiliza para Criptografia (pelo que vi ali é MD5). E como tudo é feito, pesquisando as classes e métodos que são utilizadas, e procurar equivalências em Java. Essa seria a unica forma se você tem que manter a compatibilidade com a implementação em C#. Só uma observação o seu método em C# se chama "Descriptografar" mas o MD5(além de não ser uma criptografia e sim um Hash) é irreversível, sendo assim não poderia haver um método para reverter um hash MD5.

Comment: Fernando, obrigado pela ajuda. No fim das contas, consegui resolver, vou postar o método aqui.