# Problema ao decriptar hash em Base64

Tags: hash, codificação-de-caracteres, base64

Estava lendo sobre uma regra do apache para validação de permissões à acesso a *arquivos/diretórios*, e vi que o padrão do arquivo que lê o usuário e senha era:

```
usuário:senha (sendo a senha em base64).
```

Tentei decodificar a senha pelo terminal do linux, só que foi retornado uma mensagem de erro:

```
~$ echo "zuQCCnEXtTamg" | base64 -d

~$ Invalid Input
```

E No Windows com **cerUtil**:

```
Retorno inválido de dados
```

Pesquisei e vi que esse erro é gerado pelo tipo de char-encoding que o arquivo foi codificado (*UTF-8, UTF-16, etc*)

O Problema é que não sei como ele foi codificado e nem onde (como o windows usa utf8 e o linux não por padrão). Existe alguma forma de descobrir como ele foi codificado e sua encoding?

Hash: `zuQCCnEXtTamg`

Comment: `echo "zuQCCnEXtTamg" | base64 -d , isso no Linux.`


`No windows usei o cerUtil --decode ...`

`O resultado no linux foi : caracteres bugados`

`e no Windows: Retorno de dados inválidos`

Comment: @user3386417 coloque essa informação na pergunta também!!!

Answer (score 2):

Não é assim que o `.htpasswd` funciona... O que é armazenado não é a senha codificada em base 64, mas sim um **hash da senha** - e que eu saiba, este não é necessariamente codificado em base 64 (ele pode especificar o algoritmo, parâmetros, sal, cada um no seu formato e tudo separado por `$`).

Caso não esteja familiarizado com hashes, veja [essa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215). É impossível (exceto por tentativa e erro) recuperar a senha original a partir do hash, por isso que tentar "decodificar" o texto em base 64 não está dando resultado (independentemente do *encoding* de saída). Para autenticar um usuário, o que o Apache faz é re-hashear a senha enviada e comparar seu hash com o hash salvo no arquivo.

Obter a senha original a partir do hash é, no melhor caso trabalhoso, e no pior impossível [na prática]. Note ainda que o hash usado como padrão pelo Apache (`MD5` ou `crypt`) é considerado "fraco" (ver pergunta linkada), de modo que sistemas mais novos ([Apache 2.4+](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.4)) deveriam migrar pro `bcrypt`. Se esse algoritmo for usado, de fato é inviável tentar recuperar a senha a partir do hash.

<sub>**Nota:** Ver [essa pergunta no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/56789/6939) (em inglês) para razões pela qual é importante sim usar um hash "forte" nessa situação, ainda que à primeira vista não pareça.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No MacOS decodificou "q?6?", mas utilizei `--decode`:

```
echo zuQCCnEXtTamg | base64 --decode
??
q?6?Paulo:~ paulo$
```

Neste site http://www.base64decode.org o resultado foi "q6"