# Quais são os valores recomendados para database MySQL (id, usuario, senha e email)?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Eu criei uma tabela `user` com os seguintes valores:

```
Tipo = `MyISAM`

ID = `int, PRIMARY, AI`;   
Usuário = `varchar, 16`;   
Senha = `varchar, 16`;   
Email = `varchar, 100`;
```

Esses valores são recomendados? Seguros?

Comment: Tenho dúvidas se isto pode ser respondido objetivamente. Você não colocou valores aí, você parece estar colocando a definição das colunas. Se for isso que quer saber, `varchar` parece ser apropriado, mas é possível que não seja, depende de cada caso. Quanto aos tamanhos, depende, você tem controle sobre o tamanho do usuário e senha que podem ser cadastrados? Se tiver, você diz se 16 é suficiente. Se não tiver, então é melhor colocar um valor bem maior para garantir. O e-mail você provavelmente não tem controle. 100 pode ser suficiente mas eu não arriscaria.

Comment: Eu acho muito curta uma senha dessas, e user tambem. E já que vai usar varchar, deixe o email no máximo (255) por garantia.

Comment: Lembre-se que `varchar` só gasta espaço realmente usado, então para que economizar? Colocar limite é só para "proteger" a coluna de receber dados maiores. Mas provavelmente sua aplicação já faz isto, não é mesmo? Se falhar a escrita no banco de dados porque ultrapassou o limite, sua aplicação trata isso adequadamente? Colocar um limite é mais uma validação do que uma forma de organizar o espaço no DB.

Comment: NOTA: Disse curta a senha, pq qualquer hash decente vai ocupar mais que 16 bytes. Espero que você não esteja pensando em armazenar a senha "limpa". Leia mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/

Comment: Não sei se "colocar tudo no máximo porque é varchar" é uma boa solução... Afinal, o varchar utiliza alguns recursos para fazer essa diminuição ao tamanho do valor inserido.

Comment: @Patrick o Varchar tem _overhead_ de 1 byte para tamanhos até 255, e 2 bytes para tamanhos até 65535.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Parece estar falando da configuração da estrutura de uma tabela e não dos valores de uma tabela. O conceito correto ajuda entender o problema.

Precisa de muito mais informação para poder dizer com certeza se é uma boa estrutura de banco de dados para o seu caso. Vou tentar ser objetivo de acordo com minha experiência, baseado no que você informou.

O `ID` parece estar correto.

Os demais parecem ter do tipo `varchar` apropriadamente. Um tipo `varchar` no MySQL permite que textos sejam armazenados com tamanho variável entre 0 e 65535 bytes (o que pode não significar 65535 caracteres se estiver usando UTF8, por exemplo). Essencialmente só o espaço realmente necessário para o texto individual é consumido na tabela. Então normalmente por questão de espaço não faz muito sentido estabelecer um limite para a coluna. Na verdade até tem um limite que é 65535. Claro que na prática não dá para ter uma coluna com este tamanho porque este também é o limite para o tamanho da linha.

Por que colocar um valor menor? Talvez porque você tenha certeza que nunca será ou nunca poderá ser ultrapassado esse limite.

Mas se tem certeza que um texto tem tamanho fixo, talvez seja melhor usar o `char`. Se quer estabelecer um limite que não pode ser ultrapassado, você está usando a estrutura do banco de dados para fazer validação. Funciona, mas nem sempre é o mais adequado.

Se vai usar esse tipo de validação tenha certeza que sua aplicação sabe como lidar com um erro gerado por ter violado esse limite.

Claro que esta validação pode ser feita na aplicação também e provavelmente é uma boa ideia nem tentar gravar algo que é sabidamente em estado inválido.

Os tamanhos para `Usuário` e `Senha` parecem pequenos, mas você pode responder melhor que eu. De onde vêm esses dados? Você tem controle de como isto é cadastrado? Não há como precisar de tamanho maior? Se não tiver controle absoluto sobre o tamanho, é melhor deixar um tamanho maior, talvez 255.

A senha será gravada como? Pura e simples? Sabe das implicações disto? Não vai pelo menos usar a função `password()` para gerar um [***hash* da senha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101)? Se for usar isto, 41 bytes serão necessários. Mas não vai usar nenhum outro método? Pode ser curto demais. Leia o [texto que o Bacco *linkou*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/) no comentário. Se souber que o tamanho é da senha é fixo (*hash*), a coluna não precisa ser `varchar`, mas também não há mal em ser. Algumas pessoas tendem achar que um tipo tem mais performance que outro, mas isso pode não se realizar no caso real.

Endereço de e-mail normalmente tem algumas poucas dezenas de caracteres, mas é possível ter **254 caracteres**. Eu colocaria fácil o tamanho 254 para esta coluna, nem pensaria em tamanho menor. Informações podem ser obtidas na [RFC do SMTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321). 100 não deve causar problemas (até que cause), de fato muitos provedores nem permitem endereços que ultrapassem este limite, mas se quer uma solução robusta que resolva o problema, deixe 254. Colocar 100 é opinião.

Se precisa de alguma informação mais detalhada do que isto, seria bom editar e fornecer mais detalhes na pergunta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só para esclarecer algumas informações, no sistema de registro os novos usuários podem ter: Nome de usuário entre 4 e 16 caracteres, Senha entre 8 e 16 caracteres e Email de até 100 caracteres, caso contrário eles recebem uma mensagem de erro durante o registro. Meu objetivo é só evitar falhas futuramente.

Comment: Ok, se você garante isso através da aplicação, então você pode usar estes limites no DB sem problemas, não há necessidade de deixar mais espaço do que pode ser cadastrado. O limite pode ser usado para garantir que a aplicação não deixe passar por engano. O que neste caso seria um erro de programação que precisa ser consertado o mais rápido possível, então nenhuma tratamento especial dentro da aplicação precisa ser feito mesmo. Você não pode prever tudo o que vai acontecer no futuro, pode só minimizar algumas coisas. Você parece querer gravar a senha pura. Aí você pode ter problemas hoje.