# Segurança de senhas: Devo usar Mysqli -> real_escape_string ou bind_param?

Tags: segurança, mysqli, senhas

**Mysqli => real_escape_string**

Quero que o armazenamento da senha seja o mais seguro possível, no momento estou usando só `mysqli => real_escape_string`:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_safe = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($password);
```

É melhor usar `sttm::bindParam`, `prepare` e `execute`?

Comment: Tem inúmeras maneiras de fazer isto. Você pode usar a função `password()` do MySQL ao invés de fazer o *hash* no PHP, conforme lhe falei em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16967/quais-sao-os-valores-recomendados-para-database-mysql-id-usuario-senha-e-emai/16978#16978. Pode até existir, mas não vejo vantagem de fazer no PHP.

Comment: O manual já começa errado dizendo que MD5 e SHA1 são boas opções. Não são. Você já deve ter lido isto ontem. Eu confesso que nunca li isto no manual. Porque não consigo imaginar para que eles criaram uma função que não deve ser usada. E principalmente porque ela seria pior que a `password_hash()`. É preciso entender o porque do que está lá. Mas se eles já falaram uma besteira no parágrafo, não sei se dá para confiar no resto. Já vi várias aplicações conhecidas usando. Qualquer coisa usada sem contexto tem chance de estar errada. Concordo que `bcript` é uma boa opção.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os resultados são equivalentes tanto assim:

```
$safeuser     = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($user    );
$safepassword = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($password);
$mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO usuarios ( nome, senha ) VALUES ( '$safeuser','$safepassword' )" );
```

... quanto assim:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( 'INSERT INTO usuarios ( nome, senha ) VALUES ( ?, ? )' );
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $password );
$stmt->execute();
```

Porém, *prepared statements* apresentam algumas vantagens:

- A query original fica muito mais legível (assim como o resto do código).
- Você não precisa lidar com as aspas na sua query, independente do tipo de parâmetro.
- Não tem perigo de esquecer de tratar as variáveis.
- Não precisa criar variáveis intermediárias ou alterar as originais para inserir no banco;
- Não é o seu caso, mas em situações onde a mesma *query* vai ser executada varias vezes seguidas apenas mudando valores, o conector do MySQL só vai mandar os dados atualizados, em vez de mandar a *query* inteira e refazer o planejamento (o que é o grande diferencial de fazer *binding* nativo, pelo servidor).

Comment: @Lukaz11 O `bind_param` já processa a string de maneira correta, como o `real_escape_string` faria. Se você "encavalar" os dois, vai acabar convertendo coisa que não devia (gerando barras invertidas na base de dados, aspas onde nao devia ter etc). Pode usar sossegado no formato do segundo exemplo, que resolve.

Comment: Ok, aí basta conferir o número de campos, de `?` e de variáveis. e se vc tem 1 string só, é "s" e não "sss".

Comment: as variaveis vao aqui e nao na query: $stmt->bind_param( "sss", $username, $password, $email )