# Segurança Login Anti Injection MySQLI

Tags: mysqli

Estou a seguinte dúvida, dei uma boa pesquisada, mais gostaria de saber... 
Meu sistema de login administrativo eu estava utilizando somente **addslashes**, por **motivo de busca de um maior segurança, adicionei o real_escape_string**.

Gostaria de saber se meu sistema está seguro desta forma, **se métodos e funções estão com ordem correta** para que venha ser evitado os ataque de sql injection.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) && isset( $_POST['user_password'] ) && !empty( $_POST['user_login'] ) && !empty( $_POST['user_password'] ) )
{
    $db = new Mysql;

    $user_login = $db->con->real_escape_string(addslashes(trim($_POST['user_login'])));
    $user_password = $db->con->real_escape_string(addslashes(md5(trim($_POST['user_password']))));

    $db->query( "select * from users where user_login = '$user_login' and user_password = '$user_password'" )->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Não precisava de nada disso, bastaria usar um BIND nas variáveis. Na falta do bind, deve usar somente o real_escape_string (e setar o charset correto). Quanto mais coloca coisas espúrias, mais problema cria na aplicação.

Comment: @bacco como fazer meu amigo. Poderia me dar um exemplo seguro?

Comment: Basta tirar o addslashes, no seu caso (e esse trim é duvidoso, pesquise no site sobre "remover espaços em senhas"). Sobre binding, tem muitas postagens no site já, vale a pena uma pesquisada por "SQL Injection"

Comment: Veja esse post sobre [usar BIND ou Escape](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17020/70)

Comment: Quer dizer que não preciso de addslashes, somente real_escape_string ou BIND tras segurança pra meu sistema??? Onde usaria então addslashes por exemplo?

Comment: Exatamente. Claro, isto contra injection. Contra outros ataques, aí é em outras partes da aplicação que tem que tomar cuidado.

Comment: Melhor que `md5` seria utilizar [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) e [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) o que iria implicar alterar esse `select`