# Quais os tipos de dados existentes no MySQL para textos?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tipagem

Quais os tipo de dados existentes no MySQL?

Qual o melhor para armazenar textos longos? (documento em forma de HTML por exemplo) Por quê?

Comment: Estou pensando em usar TEXT. Mas preciso ter certeza de que não há nenhum outro tipo melhor. A informação que tenho é que TEXT suporta até 2Gb. Não vou precisar de tudo isto, mas quero que meu banco suporte conteúdo extenso.

Comment: Não sei se engloba tudo o que vc quer, mas [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16978/23400) tem uma resposta excelente sobre isso. Edit: é, talvez só complementarmente... a resposta abaixo é bem mais específica. +1 for all

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depende do que você precisa. Não tem detalhes, contexto na pergunta.

Um `VARCHAR` permite 65535 caracteres (*bytes* se estiver usando uma versão antiga < 5.0). Mas este limite é menor na prática. O tamanho da linha também é este, por isto você não pode ter várias colunas deste tipo com tamanhos grandes. Uma única coluna pode encher toda a linha ou pode ter centenas de colunas `VARCHAR`. Como o próprio nome diz, o tamanho efetivamente ocupado varia conforme a necessidade.

Um `TEXT` permite 65535 *bytes*. E esta diferenciação é importante se estiver usando UTF-8 ou outra codificação *multibyte* já que um caractere pode ocupar 3 *bytes* (isto pode mudar de acordo com o *charset* escolhido - o uso de 3 *bytes* era um erro no UTF-8 padrão inicial, por isso existe outro *charset*).

Assim como o `TINYTEXT` suporta 255 *bytes*. E se você precisa mais que isto tem que usar `MEDIUMTEXT` (16MB) ou `LONGTEXT` (4GB).

O armazenamento desses tipos `TEXT` é feito fora da linha normal, fica em área específica e não ocupa espaço na linha (exceto pelo apontador, que é bem pequeno, para a localização do dado, por isso não compensa se sabe que a maioria dos textos será pequeno).

No MyISAM uma parte pequena do texto fica na linha, mesmo tendo essa regra. A ocupação do espaço na linha também é variável.

Nem falarei do `CHAR` de tamanho fixo que parece ser bem fora do que está precisando.

## A [decisão não é tão simples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-syntax.html).

É óbvio que textos em `VARCHAR` precisam ter seus tamanhos mais controlados, não podem ser tão grandes assim. Quando você não tem tanto controle ou sabe que o tamanho será bem grande, ou seja, é um texto e não apenas uma simples *string*, tem que usar o `TEXT` mesmo, não tem jeito.

O `TEXT` costuma ter acesso mais lento na maioria das situações. Nada muito significativo mas é comum ele precisar mais acessos ao disco que o `VARCHAR` mesmo tendo o mesmo tamanho. Como o texto é armazenado separado, é como se tivesse uma outra tabela e estivesse fazendo um `JOIN`, embora o processo seja diferente.

Tabelas temporárias com qualquer tipo de `TEXT` [precisam estar em disco](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html), o que é bem mais lento que as tabelas normais que podem ficar só na memória.

Usando um `TEXT` em índices comuns (não *full-text*) é necessário determinar o tamanho da chave. Você não pode indexar toda a coluna, precisa dizer quantos caracteres quer no índice. E outro ponto importante é que os textos na chave são armazenados sempre com os espaços para que todas as chaves tenham o mesmo tamanho. Isto é ineficiente e se você não souber o que está fazendo, terá resultados falsos.

`TEXT` não permite valores `DEFAULT`, o `VARCHAR` sim.

Eu já vi algumas pessoas dizerem que deve usar sempre `TEXT`. Isto não é bem verdade. Ele tem desvantagens. Use o `VARCHAR` até que tenha um motivo para usar o `TEXT`.

O seu caso parece exigir pelo menos um `MEDIUMTEXT`, não só pelo tamanho, mas pela semântica do que está armazenando. Mas se algumas destas restrições criam problema para você e consegue garantir que esses HTMLs são pequenos e não terão vários na mesma linha, não descarte o `VARCHAR`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O valor do longtext que é de 4GB ocupa realmente esse valor, ou é correspondente ao tamanho da string igual ao varchar?

Comment: Não, ele é só o máximo, ele só usa o que for necessário para o dado que colocar lá.

Answer (score 9):

O tipo de dado que você pretende usar (`TEXT`) suporta dados de, no máximo, em torno de **65kb**.

Para termos uma referência, o HTML retornado do portal de notícias [Globo.com](http://globo.com/) possui o tamanho de ~48kb, e o da [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/), **mais de 100kb**.

Os dois exemplos acima mostram que um arquivo HTML pode facilmente ultrapassar o limite máximo de um campo `TEXT` do MySQL.

Tendo isto em vista, sobrariam outros dois tipos de dados de texto que seriam mais adequados ao seu caso:

> `MEDIUMTEXT` = suporta até ~16MB de dados.
>
> `LONGTEXT` = suporta até ~4.000MB de dados.

A título de comparação, no caso de um campo ser `MEDIUMTEXT`, ele suportaria mais de 100 mil "códigos HTML" da BBC antes de atingir o limite. Caso ele fosse um `LONGTEXT`, seriam **mais de 42 milhões** de cópias do código HTML da BBC.

Então, no seu caso, imagino que um **`MEDIUMTEXT`** já proveria espaço mais que suficiente para armazenar códigos de páginas HTML.

<sup>**Referências:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text 

http://help.scibit.com/Mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html 

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html</sup>

Comment: +1 pelas comparações.