# Dados cortados no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou adicionando um pequeno texto em meu banco de dados porém o texto sempre é cortado, por exemplo:

> A Empresa X atua em segurança privada com o objetivo de prevenir e reduzir perdas patrimoniais em uma determinada organização, além de inibir qualquer ação contra a vida das pessoas. Nosso atendimento é personalizado e respeitamos a particularidade de cada cliente, montando um plano operacional conforme procedimentos e após análise de vulnerabilidade.

O que é armazenado no banco.

> A Hiperion atua em segurança privada com o objetivo de prevenir e reduzir perdas patrimoniais em uma determinada organização, além de inibir qualquer ação contra a vida das pessoas. Nosso atendimento é personalizado e respei~

alguém sabe o que pode ser a causa disso?

Comment: O tipo da sua coluna está definido errado. Por exemplo: varchar(250), que é o número de caracteres que você colou como resultado. Considere aumentar a quantidade de caracteres ou mudar o tipo, para text() por exemplo. Mostre-nos o SQL da tabela que está apresentando problemas.

Comment: Coloca o código e veja o tamanho do campo como disse o buback

Comment: estou tentando usar o sql para mudar o tipo da coluna e não está funcionaod: `ALTER TABLE servicos ALTER COLUMN 'text' text;`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, você só conseguirá se não tiver registros. Faça backup, apague os registros e depois execute a alteração do tipo.

Comment: Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78812/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o tamanho da sua coluna (provavelmente um `VARCHAR` com tamanho 255) está limitando a quantidade de caracteres que pode ser registrada na tabela.

Para resolver isso, altere o tipo da coluna para `TEXT`. Exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE nomedatabela MODIFY nomedacoluna TEXT;
```

**Obs.:** É recomendado fazer *backup* da tabela quando for executar comandos de alteração da estrutura.