# Entity Framework: Modelo de Dados com coluna com o maior número possível de caracteres

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, dataannotations

Estou criando as tabelas com o `Entity Framework`, e estou usando o `Data Annotation` para determinar a quantidade de caracteres, queria saber qual o tamanho maior suportado para digitação de textos e se o tipo correto seria `string` mesmo?

No caso queria um que coubesse o maior numero possível. Por padrão uso com 255.

```
[DisplayName("Informações Diversas")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha as informações diversas")]
[StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "As informações diversas deve ter de 3 a 255 caracteres")]
public string InformacoesDiversas{ get; set; }
```

Comment: No banco de dados qual é o tipo esperado? `text` ou `varchar`, alias qual é o banco que está usando ?

Comment: MySQL, sobre o tipo esperado eu não sei te dizer, pelas pesquisas que fiz, seria varchar, mas na hora de criar a classe não aparece. Vi esta fonte http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78812/quais-os-tipos-de-dados-existentes-no-mysql-para-textos e está https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee382832(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Se pode usar na sua classe `string` está correto e `varchar(255)` no MySQL para um limite de texto, se não quiser limite de texto use o tipo `text` no MySQL.

Comment: No mysql tudo bem, eu entendi, mas na classe, não tem o tipo text, pelo menos eu tentei importar (usando CTRL + . ), mas não apareceu nada

Comment: o tipo que representa na classe é `string` fique tranquilo está correto o jeito que você representou.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute` para definir que a sua propriedade será criada como `text` no Banco de Dados.

```
[Column(TypeName = "text")]
public string InformacoesDiversas { get; set; }
```

Ou através de Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OTipoDaSuaEntidadeAqui>()
    .Property(e => e.InformacoesDiversas)
    .HasColumnType("text");
```

É recomendado utilizar o `text` no Banco de Dados quando você não quiser limitar o tamanho do texto.