# Registro de IPv4 e/ou IPV6 no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

A internet funciona através de protocolos como o IPv4 e o IPv6, possuindo 32 bits e 128bits, que são combinações numéricas que estabelecem conexões entre computadores. Tenho uma tabela de dispositivos, `tbl_device`, no qual preciso enviar *status* do dispositivo hora ou outra. O *status* inclui a localização de o `IP` do dispositivo, no entanto fiquei na dúvida em que formato usar, se `TEXT`, `VARCHAR`, `CHAR` etc. no banco de dados.

Qual seria o tipo ideal para salvar IPv4 e/ou IPv6 no MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece ser um caso claro para `VARCHAR` já que precisa de um tamanho variável mas que nunca será muito grande. `CHAR` só seria útil se não tivesse essa variação. Até poderia usar o maior tamanho, mas não vejo vantagem nesse desperdício. O `TEXT` armazena fora da tabela normal e cria um indireção que não só é vantajoso quando o dado é acesso esporadicamente e é muito grande.

Eventualmente poderia ser útil (não parece ser) ter uma coluna para cada, aí o `CHAR` pode ser mais útil já que será sempre do mesmo tamanho. Não vejo vantagens, mas sempre depende do caso.

Pode ler mais sobre em [Quais os tipos de dados existentes no MySQL para textos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78812/101).

Se o espaço for importante não descarte codificar o IP binariamente e depois jogar no `VARCHR`, assim o máximo ocupado será 16 bytes (mais o [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) do `VARCHAR`) para os 128 bits e não o espaço ocupado para a representação hexadecimal e pior ainda se conter os separadores.

Comment: Não entendi a ultima frase @bigown ^^

Comment: @acklay precisa melhorar algo mais?

Comment: Eu continuei fazendo algumas pesquisa, onde varias pessoas dão outras ideias [além de VARCHAR(15)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5133610/2570426). Ainda estou pesquisando para melhor adaptar a performance e espaço.

Comment: Eu não gosto da ideia principalmente se for com colunas separadas, como demonstrado. Mas mesmo que seja na mesma coluna não gosto da ideia de ocupar 16 bytes para armazenar apenas 4. Claro que é uma opção.

Comment: Colunas separadas pra mim também não vejo muita vantagem.