# Como criptografar e descriptografar dados em MD5 utilizando C#?

Tags: c#, .net, criptografia, hash

Como fazer criptografias MD5 com C# de um texto ou arquivo?

E uma vez já criptografado, como descriptografar?

Comment: MD5 é uma função de _hash_ de sentido único, isto é, ela só "criptografa" (o termo mais correto é embaralhar) e não desembaralha. Vide [pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes).

Comment: De sentido único? Parece não ter sentido, rs. Se eu criptografo algo por questão de segurança, por que eu não consigo ler depois a criptografia? O que eu criptografei não terá mais utilidade? Não entendi, talvez eu tenha que estudar mais sobre criptografia. Obrigado Piovezan!!

Comment: MD5 não é destinada a criptografar coisas. Ela tem sua utilidade por exemplo quando você aplica a uma senha salva no banco e depois compara esse _hash_ com o _hash_ de uma senha digitada pelo usuário para ver se batem. Mas você não é capaz de "invertê-la" e ter a senha original de volta, a não ser por outros meios. Como função de criptografia de duplo sentido não serve, porque ela não preserva a informação original após ter sido aplicada.

Comment: Como o Piovezan disse, se for p/ usar p/ senhas você vai guardar o Hash e comparar com o que foi digitado pelo usuário depois de transformar e HASH.

Comment: @MatheusBessa as vezes você não precisa da informação original de volta. Por exemplo, senhas gravadas em banco. Quando alguém vai autenticar, você apenas roda o mesmo algoritmo de hash na senha que o usuário informou, e verifica se o resultado existe no banco. Assim você complica a vida de quem quiser obter as senhas depois de ter roubado sua base de dados.

Comment: Você vai precisar de segurança mesmo? Não use MD5. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura

Comment: @MatheusBessa Por favor explique melhor o que quer dizer com "por questão de segurança", aí talvez possamos te indicar uma alternativa melhor. *Hashes* rápidos como o MD5 são mais apropriados para prevenir contra alterações **acidentais** nos dados (ex.: arquivo corrompido) ou ajudar a detectar arquivos duplicados, mas não são adequados [por si só] para segurança - já que além de serem rápidos (o que os torna inadequados para proteger senhas) são também vulneráveis a ataques de colisão (o que os torna inadequados para proteger contra alterações **maliciosas** nos dados).

Comment: MD5 é uma função de sentido único. A questão é que existem bancos de dados na internet com dezenas de milhares de strings e dicionários com o MD5. Ex: Se você criptografar em MD5 a palavra "Deus" e jogar esse hash no google vai encontrar um site dizendo que o hash se refere a Deus. Assim é "facilmente" descoberto se a ideia era criptografar senhas. Por isso não é ideal em alguns casos como segurança de senha. Mais interessante como dito acima prevenir arquivos corrompidos ou gerar um nome de arquivo um pouco mais complicado do usuário acertar alterando url.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[MD5](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) não é reversível, ou seja, só é possível criar o hash (ou, como você disse, criptografar) e comparar com outro hash. Se forem iguais, a senha digitada é considerada a mesma.

Segue um exemplo:

```
public static string GerarHashMd5(string input)
{
    MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
    // Converter a String para array de bytes, que é como a biblioteca trabalha.
    byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

    // Cria-se um StringBuilder para recompôr a string.
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop para formatar cada byte como uma String em hexadecimal
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Como faço para comparar com um outro dado ? Por exemplo, se eu usar o Hash citado acima, em uma senha salva em um banco de dados, como faço para comparar ela com uma senha digitada pelo usuário?

Comment: `if (senhaDigitada == registroTabela.Senha) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

No final vou dizer por que eu respondi esta pergunta.

Primeiro, várias pessoas disseram que MD5 não deve ser usado em nada que exija segurança. Isso é fato bastante conhecido e especificado em comentários mostrando como é algo falho e considerando insuficiente se o objetivo é segurança, ainda que seja usado em alguns lugares.

O alento é que a pergunta fala em criptografar um arquivo, então parece que não é para usar em segurança, e parece querer ter só um *hash* mesmo (ainda que comentários desmintam isso, o que deixa confuso e a pergunta deveria ter sido fechada).

E MD5 é uma técnica de hash, por isso em sentido único, portanto não dá para descriptografar algo que não foi exatamente criptografado. Só por isso a pergunta deveria ter sido fechada. Algumas pessoas podem dizer que é uma forma de criptografia com perda de dados pelo sentido único. Então não se sabe o que a pergunta quer.

[Para saber mais sobre *hashes* e senhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101).

## MD5 do .NET

A [classe MD5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397N&view=net-7.0) do .NET implementa o padrão de projeto chamado Disposable, portanto ele tem o método `Dispose()` para liberar recursos do sistema operacional usados para gerar a criptografia. Em quase todos os casos, e esse é um deles, você deve usar o `using` para não vazar o recurso. Na maioria das vezes não causará um grande problema, mas é errado, apesar de funcionar.

A API desta classe não é das melhores, e a classe nem deveria ser tão necessária assim, pelo menos deveria ter métodos estáticos que gerasse de forma simples. Mais ainda, deveria ter uma forma de já pegar como texto "legível", se for o que a pessoa deseja.

Note que a pergunta não fala nada em converter em *string*, então receber apenas os bytes do *hash* já deve ser suficiente e não deveria precisar nada além disso. Então não vou converter os bytes para `string` porque a pergunta não específica que deseja isso, e na maioria dos casos não faz sentido fazer isso. É o de sempre, o texto só deveria ser gerado para uma apresentação, o que não é o caso.

Não vou entrar nisso, mas é possível [gerar partindo diretamente de um arquivo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397N&view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithm-computehash(system-io-stream)).

Então para responder a pergunta, até onde dá, basta este código:

```
md5.ComputeHash(dados)
```

Se os dados estivem em forma de `string` aí tem que converter para bytes:

```
md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
```

Exemplo:

```
using static System.Text.Encoding;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using var md5 = MD5.Create();
var hash = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes("dados"));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/41RjSk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sp9Ah0). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Md5.cs).

Aí faz o que quiser com o *hash* gerado.

Note que tem que usar o método de fabricação [`Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5.create?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397N&view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-md5-create) no lugar do construtor porque a classe é abstrata e não pode ser usada de forma direta.

Usei a classe básica mais simples de usar. Tem inúmeras outras formas de fazer o mesmo trabalho dependendo da necessidade, mais um motivo porque a pergunta não é boa.

---

Esta pergunta deveria ter sido fechada. Ela foi postada em uma época que se achava que dava para ter qualidade em qualquer coisa do site. Ela é a prova que esse tip ode pergunta não pode ficar aberta, porque gerou informação errada, talvez apenas por vontade de ter votos, porque vê-se que a resposta é desleixada em todos os sentidos. A resposta aceita e com muitos votos é [plágio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806183/221800), fora de contexto em uma pergunta aberta que não se sabe o que é desejado, e pior, ensina usar errado, ainda que seja culpa do autor original. E que comentários indicam que é para segurança, o que não deve usar o mecanismo, conforme alguns comentários informaram, e tiveram pouca repercussão.

O comentário colocado na própria resposta mostra que não havia interesse em responder adequadamente e piora a situação. A resposta negativada foi mais feliz nesse ponto específico.

A outra resposta é melhor em alguns aspectos, mas reforça a ideia de usar MD5 para segurança, o que é um erro enorme.

Cuidado com o conteúdo na internet. Respondi para que tivesse uma informação útil e não ficar só o erro.

Answer (score 3):

[MD5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma função de hash de sentido único, isto é, ela só criptografa, o que você pode fazer é criptografar salva no banco de dados, após isso você pode receber a senha de uma tela de login (EX;) e fazer o processo de criptografia e fazer a busca no banco por essa senha. Ou caso queira compra dois uma variável com um MD5 na aplicação o exemplo abaixo demostra como fazer isso.

Veja funcionado [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4mLWz7).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;


public class CriarMD5
{
    public string RetornarMD5(string Senha)
    {
        using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
        {
            return RetonarHash(md5Hash, Senha);
        }
    }

    public bool ComparaMD5(string senhabanco, string Senha_MD5)
    {
        using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
        {
            var senha = RetornarMD5(senhabanco);
            if (VerificarHash(md5Hash, Senha_MD5, senha))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private string RetonarHash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
    {
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private bool VerificarHash(MD5 md5Hash, string input, string hash)
    {
        StringComparer compara = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

        if (0 == compara.Compare(input, hash))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CriarMD5 md5 = new CriarMD5();

        var senhabanco = "827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b"; 
        var Senha = "12345";

        Boolean ComparaSenha = md5.ComparaMD5(Senha, senhabanco);

        Console.WriteLine(ComparaSenha.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Ficaria assim:

```
if(GerarHashMd5(senhaDigitada) == registroTabela.Senha) { ... }
```

Você deve converter a senha digitada pelo usuário em MD5 e após comparar com a senha MD5 do banco de dados.