# Gerar hash de senhas e salvar no banco de dados

Tags: c#

alguém pode me disponibilizar um código que aborde como criar hash de senhas e salvar no banco de dados? É que eu já tentei fazê-lo, mas está a dar dor de cabeça, caso alguém já o tenha feito, agradeceria imenso que me ajudasse neste sentido.

Answer (score 2):

o método abaixo armazena a senha em dois campos, um `binary[16]` e outro `binary[64]`, respectivamente o salt e a senha em si.

```
private byte[] CreateSalt()
{
    var salt = new byte[16];
    using (var provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        provider.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    return salt;
}

public async void SalvarSenha(dynamic dto)
{
    var temp = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512() { Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dto.Password) };
    var salt = this.CreateSalt();
    var password = Pbkdf2.ComputeDerivedKey(temp, salt, UInt16.MaxValue, temp.HashSize / 8);
}
```

para fazer o codigo acima funcionar, é necessario adicionar o seguinte Nuget:

[`CryptSharp (Official Version)`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CryptSharpOfficial/)

Answer (score -1):

Este código gera HASH MD5 de senhas quando preciso salvá-las no banco de dados criptografadas:

```
public string HashMd5(string input)
{
    MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();

    byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Já utilizo a um bom tempo e sempre funcionou bem. Consegui [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17181/como-criptografar-e-descriptografar-dados-em-md5-utilizando-c)

Comment: funções de Hash não são adequadas para proteger uma senha, e dentre todas elas, MD5 é a mais falha e quebrada de todas.

Comment: Essa informação eu desconhecia, por quais razões a utilização de MD5 não é aconselhável nesse caso?

Comment: Um algoritmo de cryptografia forte tem que atender três premissas, não sofrer com colisõoes, não ser reversivel e ser custoso (para evitar ataques de força bruta). o MD5 como todo Hash não é reversivel, porém ao contrario do SHA2, pode ocorrer colissões, e por fim todo algoritmo de Hash é muito barato, você pode executar ele milhões de vezes por segundo.

Comment: Na minha resposta, estou usando um `Pbkdf2`, que usa um Salt unico por usuario, como função de Hash o SHA512 e 65535 interações.

Comment: Na pratica, é como se ele concatena-se a senha ao salt e realiza-se o hash 65535 vezes, este processo demora cerca de 1 segundo dependendo do processador, então um ataque de força bruta se forma inviável.

Comment: @Renato http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo, sempre utilizei MD5, apesar de ser uma boa solução onde estou aplicando, mas estudarei a passarei a aplicar os algoritmos que vc citou. Muito obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: @Renato, disponha, algoritmos de Hash são ideias para checar a integridade de um arquivo, por exemplo, você passa o hash e um link para download, o usuário baixa o arquivo e gera o hash do arquivo e compara com o seu hash, se forem iguais é pq o arquivo não está corrompido. e para que ele seja eficiente para este uso, ele precisa ser muito rápido e leve.

Answer (score -2):

Criação de hash simples não é bicho de sete cabeças. Você pode elaborar um com uma lógica simples, basta pesquisar. Ou simplesmente pegar a string digitada como senha e chamar o método de extensão GetHashCode() para inserir e para validar a entrada do usuário no sistema.

Caso queira algo mais avançado e seja um projeto WEB, recomendo implementar o Membership ou o Identity.

Comment: Não faça uma coisa destas. Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101