# Como verificar usuário em tela de login?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou com um problema, tenho uma tela de login e preciso verifica-la com uma `query Sql`.

Conseguir fazer algo, mas ela não verifica e entra direto.

```
private void btn_Entrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection();

        conexao.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.cs1;


        try
        {
            conexao.Open();
            SqlCommand obj = new SqlCommand();

            obj.CommandText = "Select * FROM TB_LOGIN WHERE Usuario =@Usuario And  Senha=@Senha";


            obj.Parameters.Add("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  Txt_Nome.Text;
            obj.Parameters.Add("@Senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt_Senha.Text;

            obj.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            obj.Connection = conexao;
            obj.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conexao.Close(); 


        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Falha ");
            conexao.Close();
        }
```

Comment: na realidade você só esta fazendo o select no banco de dados, você tem que verificar se o retorno do seu usuário existe no banco de dados.

Comment: Em que momento é verificado se o usuário existe no banco??

Comment: Espero que este codigo seja apenas um exercicio, pois não é boa ideia guardar à senha exposta no banco de dados. você pode usar o [CryptSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CryptSharpOfficial/) para proteger a sua senha da seguinte forma: [Gerar hash de senhas e salvar no banco de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140331/2363)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere seu método para o abaixo e faça a validação do seu usuário

```
protected void btn_Entrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection();
            conexao.ConnectionString = ConnString;
            conexao.Open();
            SqlCommand obj = new SqlCommand();
            obj.CommandText = "Select * FROM TB_LOGIN WHERE Usuario =@Usuario And  Senha=@Senha";
            obj.Parameters.Add("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt_Nome.Text;
            obj.Parameters.Add("@Senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt_Senha.Text;
            obj.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            obj.Connection = conexao;

            SqlDataReader reader = obj.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                //todo : usuario logado
                Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]); // ????
            }
            else
            {
                //todo : Login ou Senha Invalida
            }
            conexao.Close();
        }
```