# Login usando Entity com o password criptografado como varbinary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autenticação, varbinary

Eu fiz a criptografia da senha do usuário e no campo Password da minha tabela eu passei de Varchar para Varbinary, na parte web do meu sistema esta tudo certo só que na parte windows eu estou usando o Entity e não sei como fazer para validar a senha do usuário, não sei se o EF tem algo do tipo ou tenho que criptografar a senha digitada e passar por parâmetro para realizar essa consulta...

```
    public static User ValidateUser(string UserName, string Password, ObjEntities cx)
    {
        var o = from c in cx.User
                where c.UserName == UserName && c.Password == Password
                select c;

        if (o.ToList().Count > 0)
            return o.Single();
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Como você fez essa "criptografia da senha do usuário"? Teria sido um hash? (tipo [`HashBytes`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3275576/520779)) Se for o caso, você tem que re-hashear a senha e comparar com o valor salvo (não sei como fazer isso via LINQ, mas via SQL com certeza deve ser fácil - ver resposta linkada no SOen).

Comment: Eu fiz direto na minha Store Procedure - PWDENCRYPT(@Password)

Comment: Esse `Password` passado como parâmetro é um hash ou é a própria senha digitada em tela?

Comment: Se você usou `PWDENCRYPT(senha)` para hashear, você deve usar [`PWDCOMPARE(senha, hash)` para comparar](http://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/1433/). Em SQL seria algo como `where UserName = c.UserName and PWDCOMPARE(Password, c.Password)`. Não sei como fazer via LINQ (não tenho experiência prática com C#). P.S. [Essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10103510/520779) explica como fazer.

Comment: PWDENCRYPT é uma StoredProcedure? e o userName é único?

Comment: Esta maneira de fazer é um tanto quanto fora do padrão das aplicações ASP.NET MVC. Já pensou em usar ASP.NET Membership ou ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Embora eu concorde 100% com sua sugestão (autenticação e autorização são assuntos complexos, quanto menos soluções *ad-hoc* melhor), fica a ressalva de que - pela descrição do OP ("na parte web do meu sistema esta tudo certo só que na parte windows...") - *me parece* que se trata da interoperabilidade entre dois sistemas distintos (não necessariamente na mesma plataforma, mas posso estar enganado). Adotar os padrões de um implicaria em precisar adaptar o outro (o que do ponto de vista da segurança não é uma má ideia, mas de qualquer forma não é algo que viria sem custos).

Comment: O cadastro do usuário é realizado pela web, na parte windows o usuário só acessa o sistema, a principio iriamos desenvolver o sistema em MVC utilizando o EF também mas pela necessidade de um desenvolvimento rápido resolvemos desenvolver em ASP.NET usando o ADO e na parte windows WPF usando o EF, obrigado pela atenção...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Pois é... mas é a validação de um sistema autônomo. Por isso pensei no Membership ou no Identity. Enfim, fica a sugestão.

Comment: @Jhonas Independente dessas escolhas, Membership e Identity ainda servem bem ao propósito. Acho que vale a pena alguma pesquisa.

Comment: Eu vou pesquisar sim, vlw pela dica!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Exemplo simples:***

Eu criaria 2 *Stored Procedure* para a Tabela `User`, e carregaria dentro do *Entity Framework*.

***Create Table User***

```cs
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [varbinary](128) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

***Stored Procedure***

```cs
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Insert_User 
(
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(30)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [User]([UserName], [Password]) VALUES(@UserName, PWDENCRYPT(@Password));
    SELECT [UserId], [UserName], [Password] FROM [User] WHERE [UserId] = @@IDENTITY;
END

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_User_Verify
(   
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(30)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [User].[UserName] = @UserName AND 
                               PWDCOMPARE(@Password,[User].[Password]) = 1
END
```

A `SP_Insert_User` para inserir novos usuários e a `SP_User_Verify` para verificar a existência do usuário com o retorno dos seus dados.

No seu Model importo as duas *Stored Procedure* dessa maneira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolha as duas com os respectivos nomes que dentro do Contexto será criado duas *functions* de retorno dessa maneira:

```cs
public partial class ObjEntities : DbContext
{
    public ObjEntities()
        : base("name=ObjEntities") { }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }   
    public virtual ObjectResult<SP_Insert_User_Result> SP_Insert_User(string userName, string password)
    {
        var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

        var passwordParameter = password != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Password", password) :
            new ObjectParameter("Password", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<SP_Insert_User_Result>("SP_Insert_User", userNameParameter, passwordParameter);
    }
    public virtual ObjectResult<SP_User_Verify_Result> SP_User_Verify(string userName, string password)
    {
        var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

        var passwordParameter = password != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Password", password) :
            new ObjectParameter("Password", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<SP_User_Verify_Result>("SP_User_Verify", userNameParameter, passwordParameter);
    }
}
```

***Como usar:***

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ObjEntities cx = new ObjEntities())
        {
            SP_User_Verify_Result user = ValidateUser("USUARIO2", "SENHA2", cx);
        }
    }
    public static SP_User_Verify_Result ValidateUser(string UserName, string Password, ObjEntities cx)
    {
        return cx.SP_User_Verify(UserName, Password).FirstOrDefault<SP_User_Verify_Result>();
    }
}
```

***Debug:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se nessa linha `SP_User_Verify_Result user = ValidateUser("USUARIO2", "SENHA2", cx);` a variável `user` for `null`, então, não foi encontrado o usuário, consequentemente, usuário não autorizado.

Comment: Vlw Harry, deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

> Resposta traduzida/adaptada [desta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103724/520779)

O que você precisa fazer é encapsular `PWDCOMPARE` em uma UDF (função definida pelo usuário) no seu banco de dados, e então chamar esse UDF através do seu `DataContext`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399416.aspx

Ou seja, execute isso no seu banco de dados:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_PWDCOMPARE (@pwd NVARCHAR(MAX),@pwdhash NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIT
BEGIN
  RETURN PWDCOMPARE(@pwd, @pwdhash)
END
```

Então adicione isso no seu `DataContext` no Visual Studio e chame dessa forma:

```
var o = from c in cx.User
            where c.UserName == UserName && 
                  db.fn_PWDCOMPARE(Password, c.Password)
            select c;
```

P.S. A função [`PWDENCRYPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd822791.aspx) é uma função antiga, e seu uso é desencorajado em projetos novos. Se for possível a mudança, considere usar [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174415.aspx) em vez dela (embora lendo a documentação, me parece que as funções de hash suportadas [não são seguras para se proteger senhas...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215) Infelizmente, não tenho nenhuma alternativa a sugerir).

Comment: Legal! Eu add a função no meu Contexto usando o Update Model from Database mas não estou conseguindo visualizar ela, aparece todas as tabelas e as Store Procedure mas essa não, eu tenho que fazer algo diferente para usar essa função?

Comment: @Jhonas Infelizmente, não tenho como te ajudar nisso. O pouco de C# que eu conheço é no Mono, nunca usei o ambiente da Microsoft... Receio que você terá que esperar que outra pessoa responda.