# Fazer uma consulta usando Entity Framework e Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho a procedure procRetornaCliente que recebe os seguintes parametros: Id, areaAtuacao, Cidade.
Mapeando ele no EDMX, consegui um Complex Type (`procRetornaClienteModel`)  com todos os campos mapeados, porém nao sei como fazer uma consulta usando o Entity Framework, já pesquisei e todo site faz um exemplo diferente.
Minha estrutura é a seguinte:

```
using (DataBaseAdmin db = new DataBaseAdmin())
{
    int id = Session["_id"];
    String areaAtuacao = Session["_areaAtuacao"].ToString();
    String Cidade = Session["_Cidade"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Nesse http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23174/6026  tem o que você procura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou fazer algo assim?

```
using (DataBaseAdmin db = new DataBaseAdmin())
{
    int id = Session["_id"];
    String areaAtuacao = Session["_areaAtuacao"].ToString();
    String Cidade = Session["_Cidade"].ToString();

    //retornar da procedure
    var object = db.procRetornaClienteModel(id);

    //manipular e salvar
    var cliente; // coloque aqui código pra transformar seu retorno em uma entidade cliente.
    cliente.AreaAtuacao = areaAtuacao;
    cliente.Cidade = Cidade;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Pra uma melhor resposta é necessário ter mais informações sobre o que exatamente sua procedure faz, quais são suas entidades, etc. Mas espero ter ajudado.

Comment: modifiquei um pouco e aparentemente ta funcionando.
obrigado!

Comment: Por nada! Fico feliz em poder ajudar!