# Erro ao usar store procedure - Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu usei uma store precedure para autenticação na minha aplicação como sugerido...

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23141/login-usando-entity-com-o-password-criptografado-como-varbinary)

Mas agora esta dando o seguinte erro...

[image: Link da pergunta anterior]

Answer (score 1):

deverá colocar Value a seguir ao nome do campo.
por exemplo `minhaSP.campo.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Alguma coluna está retornando `null` quando você executa a procedure.

1. Execute a procedure direto no banco de dados, veja se tem algum valor retornando `nulo`
2. Adapte sua procedure para não retornar `null`.

Comment: Eu executei a minha procedure no banco, mas ela não me retorna nenhum valor nulo, eu criei outra só com campos obrigatórios mas mesmo assim aparece a mesma mensagem de erro.