# jBCrypt continua seguro?

Tags: java, hash, bcrypt

Gostaria de saber se o jBCrypt esta defasado pois faz dois anos que nao atualizam

https://github.com/josephw/jBCrypt

Se sim teria algum substituto para solucionar hashs e salts para java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O jBCrypt é simplesmente uma implementação do algoritmo [bcrypt](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), de modo que se:

1. Não houver nenhum bug nessa implementação ([não há nenhum *bug report*](https://github.com/josephw/jBCrypt/issues)); e:
2. Nenhuma vulnerabilidade tenha sido descoberta nesse algoritmo (não foi).

Então pode-se dizer que ele continua seguro.

O fato dele não ser atualizado há dois anos não significa nada nesse caso, apenas que o sistema foi concluído, cumpre bem o seu propósito, e não há mais nada a se fazer. Seria interessante que ele fosse *peer reviewed* por pessoas com experiência em sistemas criptográficos, mas na ausência disso, temos somente o fato de que não houve evidência alguma de problemas...

Quanto a alternativas, não conheço implementações específicas, mas o algoritmo bcrypt é um dos mais recomendados (os demais sendo [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) e [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)). Veja [essa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215) para mais detalhes sobre esses algoritmos (e o processo de hash em geral).