# Gerar senha MD5 de 32 caracteres com o CryptSharp

Tags: c#, .net, criptografia, md5

Estou utilizando a biblioteca CryptSharp para gerar senha em MD5. Havia lido que MD5 gera string com hexadecimais de 32 caracteres porém está gerando 34 e com varios tipos de caracteres.

Está gerando nesse formato:

> $1$gSUz3sUo$mFPQB05MAMhFokOSydON91

Pesquisando vi que existem alguns formatos diferentes de MD5. Esse inicia com esses $ nos tres primeiros caracteres.

Meu código utilizando a biblioteca é esse:

```
    public string Codifica(string senha)
    {
        return Crypter.MD5.Crypt(senha);
    }
```

Alguém que já tenha usado sabe se existe algum parametro dessa biblioteca que possa deixar a minha senha codificada em 32 caracteres?

Comment: Desde 2008 que MD5 e' considerado *broken* e inseguro. Actualmente, recomenda-se o uso de SHA-256 para criar hashes seguras.

Answer (score 4):

MD5 é um algoritmo de Hash de 128 bits, na verdade ele não vai te retornar 32 caracteres e sim 16 bytes que geralmente são convertidos para texto em hexadecimal assim ficando com os 32 caracteres que você se refere.

Porém você está usando uma biblioteca que o gera de uma forma um pouco diferente, pegando como exemplo o hash que você citou

```
$1$gSUz3sUo$mFPQB05MAMhFokOSydON91
```

Pela lógica usada por esta biblioteca este hash pode ser quebrado em 3 partes

`$1$` é o identificador de versão

`gSUz3sUo` é o salt usado

`mFPQB05MAMhFokOSydON91` é o hash em si, o `$` entre o salt e o hash é apenas usado como separador.

Nesta biblioteca os valores são codificados usando uma variante do Base64, se este valor for decodificado você teria de volta os 16 bytes.

Então devido a estas informações extras, usando esta biblioteca você não vai ter os 16 bytes (ou 32 caracteres) como você queria, para usar ela e poder usar o método `CryptSharp.Crypter.CheckPassword(senha, hash)` para verificar as senhas você precisa do hash da forma como ele retorna mesmo, a alternativa seria usando o `MD5CryptServiceProvider` do próprio .Net e converter os 16 bytes que ele retorna para texto em hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

É uma necessidade utilizar a biblioteca `CryptSharp`?

Por que utilizo a biblioteca nativa `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5`, e funciona perfeitamente para mim. Se você puder fazer essa mudança!

Minha implementação com `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5` é a seguinte:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gera hash MD5
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">String a ser aplicado o hash</param>
/// <returns>String já aplicado o hash MD5</returns>
public static string HashMD5(string input)
{
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5Hash = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        // Convert the valor string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string.
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

> Recomendo também dar uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura), pois `MD5` não é a melhor forma de criar hash de senhas.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Criptografia
    {
        public static string GetMD5Hash (string Valor)
        {
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Valor))).Replace("--", string.Empty);
        }
        public static string GetSHA1Hash (string Valor)
        {
            SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Valor))).Replace("", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT, poderia [edit] sua resposta e explica-la? Obrigado