# O hash do MD5 pode se repetir para senhas diferentes causando colisão?

Tags: hash, md5

Um colega de trabalho fez um [**Sistema em Java**](https://github.com/jl91/Collisions) que encontra colisões em uma série de senhas de hash MD5. Porém ele não parou para analisar os resultados, fez apenas uma afirmação de que existem. Só que gostaria de tirar isso a prova, alguém por acaso sabe a existência de duas senhas diferentes que poderiam ter o mesmo hash MD5?

O [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities) fala mais sobre colisões e vulnerabilidades.

Para esclarecer o problema, algo que parece de simples compreensão, mas que parece não ter ficado muito claro, o que quero é os dois valores distintos que causaram o mesmo hash MD5, exemplo, digitando no Workbench:

```
set @valor1 := 'senha_distinta1????';
set @valor2 := 'senha_distinta2????';
SELECT MD5(@valor1) AS hashA, MD5(@valor2) AS hashB;
```

onde: **hashA = hashB**

**Obs:** Tentei colocar os seguintes valores de entrada para testar os exemplos sugeridos e ambos retornaram em valores diferentes de hash:

```
set @a:= "d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70";

set @b:= "d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70";

set @a:=Replace(@a," ","");
set @a:=Replace(@a,"
","");
set @b:=Replace(@b,"
","");
set @b:=Replace(@b," ","");

SELECT  MD5(@a) as hashA, MD5(@b) as hashB, @a as valorA, @b as valorB;
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como funciona o algoritmo de hash MD5?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43495/como-funciona-o-algoritmo-de-hash-md5)

Comment: @Sanção, você está redondamente errado, a pergunta não é uma duplicata e também não responde a minha pergunta, ela apenas informa o funcionamento do algoritmo, o que eu preciso é de exemplos reais de que existem colisões. Até agora só vi afirmações sobre isso, mas nada é conclusivo.

Comment: Olha eu acho que a pergunta não responde diretamente isto, mas afirma e forneça os links sobre o assunto, realmente não é uma duplicata, mas te digo uma coisa, o sha1 que também apresentou o mesmo problema posteriormente, sendo agora recomendado o sha-2, que "talvez" possa a ter o mesmo problema, mas não sei em que frequencia. Votei por deixar em aberto pois apesar da outra pergunta ser praticamente a mesma que a sua a resposta lá pouco fala do problema de segurança. Vamos ver o que os demais acham.

Comment: Realmente após ler alguns links notei que a questão de senhas e de arquivos com md5 talvez possa variar, levando em consideração isto a sua pergunta é bem diferente realmente da outra. Deve ser mantida em aberto mesmo, só acho que o titulo não ficou bom (mas é uma opinião minha). Se ninguém responder mais tarde eu tento formular uma resposta. Até mais.

Comment: Porquê surgiu o **salt** ?

Comment: @Edilson O *salt* existe para evitar *rainbow tables* (quebrar várias senhas pelo "preço" de uma), não tem nada a ver com colisões.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, realmente, ao citar _salt_ tornei-me alheio à conversa, quando a problema em causa é outro.

Comment: Não entendi porque me negativaram, mas ok. Acredito que isso é uma forma das pessoas demostrarem que não conseguiram compreender a pergunta, logo negativam. É normal não compreenderem algo que não sabem.

Comment: A resposta para a pergunta é simples. SIM. Matematicamente é comprovado que qq hash possui colisões. Agora ter senhas com o mesmo hash de saída é muito dificil. Mais comum que uma cadeia longa de bits gere uma colisão para uma cadeia curta.

Comment: no seu exemplo usando o Workbench, tente fazer um UNHEX da sua string hexdecimal: `SELECT  MD5(UNHEX(@a)) as hashA, MD5(UNHEX(@b)) as hashB, UNHEX(@a) as valorA, UNHEX(@b) as valorB;`

Comment: @TobyMosque **Isso!** É isso que eu estava tentando explicar pro AP mas não estava conseguindo me fazer entender (a propósito, atualizei a minha resposta, espero que esse ponto esteja um pouco mais claro).

Comment: Funcionou @TobyMosque, acredito que sua resposta sanou minha dúvida, obrigado. EU colocaria isso como uma resposta.

Comment: O meu comentario não é uma resposta, eu apenas apontei pq o seu codigo adaptado do exemplo dado pelo @mgibsonbr não estava funcionando da maneira esperada. Ao meu ver a resposta do gibson está completa e não preciso acrescentar nada a mesma.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Há não só exemplos mas também [um site que gera colisões pra você](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/):

> os dois blocos
>
> ```
> d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
> 55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b
> d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0
> e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70
> ```
>
> e
>
> ```
> d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
> 55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b
> d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0
> e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70
> ```
>
> produzem uma colisão MD5.
>
> Cada um desses blocos possui o hash MD5 `79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4`.

<sup>[Fonte](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1434)</sup>

[**Exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/9QI8CJ)

Se você se refere a duas strings **curtas** com o mesmo MD5, acho bastante improvável que exista. A saída do MD5 é de 128 bits. Isso significa que se você gerar 2<sup>128</sup> + 1 strings distintas então *garantidamente* você terá uma colisão ([princípio da casa dos pombos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_casa_dos_pombos)). Mas o conjunto de strings Unicode no BMP de tamanho até 7, juntas, dão menos que 2<sup>128</sup> - 1, de modo que é possível que nesse conjunto não exista uma única colisão.

De todo modo, o problema de usar MD5 para proteger senhas não é sua vulnerabilidade a colisões (pois pra senhas o que importa é a **resistência à segunda pré-imagem**, e nisso o MD5 ainda não foi quebrado), e sim o fato dele ser muito **rápido** (um [bom hash pra proteger senhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura?rq=1) precisa necessariamente ser **lento**).

---

**Atualização:** um ponto que parece estar causando confusão é que a entrada que um hash MD5 espera é uma sequência **binária**, e não uma sequência de caracteres. De modo que, mesmo que sua entrada seja uma string, primeiro ela teria que ser convertida em uma sequência binária (via uma codificação ou *encoding*) antes de ser enviada como entrada para o algoritmo MD5. Muitas bibliotecas e funções fazem isso automaticamente pra você, por isso *parece* que o MD5 aceita entradas strings, quando na verdade não aceita.

Os exemplos citados são duas sequências binárias, expressas em hexadecimal. não é uma simples questão de usar o texto acima como entrada para o hash, é preciso interpretá-lo da forma correta:

```
0xd1 == 209 == 1101 0001
```

O que é diferente da *string* `"d1"`:

```
"d1" == 0x64 0x31 == 0110 0100 0011 0001
```

Note como as saídas são diferentes. Feito dessa forma, os hashes também serão diferentes...

Se você quiser/precisar colocar o exemplo acima numa string, o jeito é usar um código hexadecimal para cada par de caracteres. <del>Você não disse qual plataforma está usando</del>, mas um exemplo em Python seria: (*Edit:* foi mal, eu é que não sabia o que era esse Workbench... veja [o comentário do TobyMosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99194/o-hash-do-md5-pode-se-repetir-para-senhas-diferentes-causando-colis%C3%A3o#comment203244_99194) para um exemplo)

```
a = "\xd1\x31\xdd\x02\xc5...\x70\x80\xa8\x0d...\x70"
print(hashlib.md5(a).hexdigest())

b = "\xd1\x31\xdd\x02\xc5...\x70\x80\x28\x0d...\x70"
print(hashlib.md5(b).hexdigest())
```

Ou, mais fácil, é converter os dados acima de hexadecimal para binário e testar direto no binário (como eu fiz no [exemplo do ideone](https://ideone.com/9QI8CJ) mencionado anteriormente).

Comment: Eu não entendi onde está a senha que gerou esses blocos que foram colididos. E como você chegou nesse hash: 79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4 ? E qual seria as duas senhas diferentes geradas com 2 elevado a 128 + 'string qualquer' que deu em uma colisão?

Comment: @IvanFerrer Os blocos são a entrada, não a saída. Repare que eles não são iguais (o primeiro link que eu passei mostra realçado as diferenças). O hash é o MD5 de um ou outro par de blocos (binário, representado acima como hexadecimal). Eles são bem grandinhos, mas como eu falei não se conhece uma colisão com entradas **curtas**, tipicamente o que se usa numa senha (mas não é garantido que elas não existam). Testar isso é complicado num computador comum, veja [esse post no crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15877) para mais detalhes.

Comment: não entendi, pois a entrada do primeiro hash convertido em md5 foi 'f52a2ca211111dc63ea4b50e5854bf0a';

Comment: Isso que eu falei do 2 elevado a 128 é que se você sair gerando strings distintas (ex.: `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `z`, `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, ...`, `zz`, `aaa`, ...) e o número de strings for maior que 2^128 então garantidamente você encontrará uma colisão, pois existem apenas 2^128 saídas distintas pro MD5.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Como você fez a entrada? Estou falando de um arquivo **binário**, não é só copiar o texto e fazer o MD5 dele. Essa colisão foi descoberta por dois chineses em 2005, e desde então já foi descoberta uma colisão mais curta, com 1 bloco só. Mas reiterando: achar colisões não é fácil, não dá pra fazer com um computador comum, é preciso muito processamento e/ou muito tempo pra isso, por isso não tem como eu te dar exemplos melhores.

Comment: Pois é, eis a questão.

Comment: Voltamos na estaca zero, não há comprovação de haver colisão, são só suposições.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Por favor, leia sobre o princípio da casa dos pombos, não há suposição, existem colisões sim e elas são inevitáveis! Eu vou montar um exemplo em Python pra você *ver* a colisão, se ainda não está acreditando. Agora, se o que você quer é outra coisa (ex,: strings só com letras e números, etc) então por favor edite a pergunta esclarecendo isso. Porque eu não estou na estaca zero não, pra mim está tudo muito claro! Se você quiser que eu continue te ajudando, então "me ajude a te ajudar" rsrs.

Comment: Eu li, e reeditei a pergunta para ficar mais claro, eu entendo que logicamente deve haver uma colisão: como está nesse exemplo: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value, porém eu testei todas as opções e nada me deu um hash válido.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Com strings "normais" (alfanuméricas, latinas, Unicode...) eu não conheço nenhum exemplo, só posso provar que existe (como vejo que você também já entendeu). Com dados binários, contudo, o exemplo acima funciona (eu também editei a resposta, colocando um exemplo prático no ideone).

Comment: Os exemplo que você deu no ideone não é um binário, é exadecimal... Eu queria um exemplo prático em string+numeros+simbolos+etc. Acho que terei que descobrir isso sozinho.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, `Workbench` é uma GUI para gestão de SGBD, no caso o `MySQL`, outros exemplos de ferramentas para este fim, são o `SQL Server Management Studio` e o `pgAdmin`.

Comment: Obrigado! Eu colocaria também o complemento da solução apresentada pelo @TobyMosque, que é exatamente o que eu precisava para capturar o valor das duas entradas em que foram decodificadas do exadecimal.