# Uso de preg_replace invalida senha com SHA1

Tags: php, mysql

Estava usando `preg_replace`, para evitar injection SQL:

```
$senha = preg_replace('/[^[:alpha:]_]/', '',$_POST['senha']);
```

Ao comparar a `$senha` recebida por POST com a senha do banco (usando SHA1) , elas não são compatíveis.

Alguém me indica uma codificação melhor que evite realmente injection SQL?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-sql-no-meu-c%c3%b3digo-php/3869

Comment: Não entendi como a regex resolveu o problema de sql injection, parece que ela criou outro.

Comment: Usando `PDO`, ou `mysqi_*` basta criar um tipo de placeholder para injetar uma SQL válida, não vejo porque tratar o dado com `preg_replace()`. exemplo em PDO: `insert into tabela (senha) values (:senha_string)` e em mysqi: `insert into tabela (senha) values(?)`.

Comment: @IvanFerrer já faço isso com mysqli

Comment: Mas vc concorda que é impossível fazer sql injection quando vc declara o campo `$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha); ` a única coisa que vc vai fazer é validar o formato, mas nunca será injetado uma query que danifique seu sistema com isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há necessidade em filtrar a string pois será convertida para um hash. O hash converterá tudo, inclusive caracteres de escape que permitiriam injeções sql ou quaisquer outros tipos de injeções.

Em suma, não se preocupe com filtros anti-injection para esse caso específico.

Veja um teste de exemplo para entender na prática:

```
$str = '\' delete from users; --\'';
echo sha1($str);
```

Para ser mais claro, preocupe-se mais com a validação do parâmetro recebido:

```
$senha = null;
if (isset($_POST['senha']))
    $senha = trim($_POST['senha']);

if (!empty($senha))
    $senha = sha1(trim($_POST['senha']));
else
    echo 'senha não pode ser vazia'; exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

É óbvio que a pergunta já tem resposta, mas, para complementar o existente nos comentários, ***«Não use `sha1` para criptografar senhas»***, simplesmente porque não te protege.

Para tratar de validações, recomendo usar as funções & constantes de validação nativas do `PHP` - [Filtros PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) - ou ainda podes ler [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php) para teres mais ou menos em mente como deves proceder com o resto.

**Alguns exemplos de uso:**

- [Qual a melhor maneira de criar um sistema de login com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php)

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer filtro de **sha1** seria assim:

```
function isSHA1($sha1) {
    return (bool) preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/i', $sha1);
}
```

Se estiver usando o PDO por exemplo, você pode fazer assim:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seubanco", $user, $pass);  

try {

      if (!isset($_POST['usuario'])) {
          throw new PDOException('Informe o nome de usuário!');
      }
      if (!isset($_POST['senha'])) {
          throw new PDOException('Informe a senha!');
      }

      if (!isUser($_POST['usuario'])) {
          //aqui você cria um método para tratar o usuário
          throw new PDOException('Informa um usuário válido!');
      }

      if (!isSHA1($_POST['senha'])) {
          throw new PDOException('A senha informada é inválida!');
      }

       $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
                            INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha)
                            VALUES (:user,:pass)
                           "); 

       $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
       $senha = $_POST['senha'];

       $stmt->bindParam(':user', $usuario);
       $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $senha);
       $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Porém não tem necessidade de validar **sha1** para um caso desse, pois o usuário irá digitar uma senha normal, e depois ela será convertida para **sha1**:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seubanco", $user, $pass);  

try {

      if (!isset($_POST['usuario'])) {
          throw new PDOException('Informe o nome de usuário!');
      }
      if (!isset($_POST['senha'])) {
          throw new PDOException('Informe a senha!');
      }

      if (!isUser($_POST['usuario'])) {
          //aqui você cria um método para tratar o usuário
          throw new PDOException('Informa um usuário válido!');
      }

       $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
                            INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha)
                            VALUES (:user,:pass)
                           "); 

       $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
      //convertendo a senha para sha1
       $senha = sha1($_POST['senha']);

       $stmt->bindParam(':user', $usuario);
       $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $senha);
       $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

> **OBS:**  Não recomendo uso de hash com `sha1()` e nem `md5()`, embora eles sejam seguros, contanto que você inclua um `token` junto à senha, ambos possuem falha de colisão: [**Nesta pergunta, fala mais sobre o assunto**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99194/o-hash-do-md5-pode-se-repetir-para-senhas-diferentes-causando-colis%C3%A3o)

Uma boa alternativa para senha é o uso do [**password_rash**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).