# O que é autenticação em dois fatores?

Tags: segurança, autenticação

O que é autenticação em dois fatores? Ou múltiplos fatores?

Essa expressão normalmente vem "associada" a empresas grandes - como o Google, Facebook, etc - que têm um meio de login e de recuperação de senhas mais "chato" que o normal: códigos de telefone, SMS, "computadores confiáveis", etc. Isso é algo que só interessa aos "gigantes", ou posso usar também nas minhas aplicações? É caro implementar isso de maneira correta?

Por fim, quais os benefícios que essa técnica me traz? Será que vale a pena o esforço, afinal todo mundo já está acostumado a um simples nome de usuário e senha (e as bibliotecas/frameworks já vêm com isso pronto). Não é mais negócio manter esse padrão e só exigir senhas melhores?

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente reforçar a segurança e saber se você é você mesmo.

> "A autenticação de dois fatores fornece segurança melhorada, porque
>   exige que o usuário atenda a dois critérios de autenticação: uma
>   combinação de nome de usuário/senha e um token ou certificado,
>   conhecido como algo que você possui, algo que você sabe." -
>   [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc441642.aspx)

A técnica é muito útil e inclusive não é só utilizado em redes sociais e afins, ela é muito utilizada em bancos. Pode e inclusive é uma boa opção para reforçar o seu sistema e trazer ao usuário um pouco mais de confiabilidade.

Apenas exigir senhas fortes não quer dizer total segurança afinal o usuário é um ser humano e estamos sujeito a falhas. A técnica elimina (não totalmente) a chance de ser um impostor.

**Há a autenticação gerada por um dispositivo ou aplicação**: *Tokens, SMS, Email e etc..* - Mais seguro

**Há também a autenticação com informações que apenas você conhece**: *utilizando como exemplo o Facebook. Experimente abrir em outra região que seja diferente do seu estado; O sistema fará perguntas sobre informações vinculada a sua conta ("Quem é esta pessoa?", "Qual o nome do seu Pai?")* - Menos segura

Answer (score 3):

A forma mais comum de autenticar um usuário (i.e. provar que ele é mesmo quem ele diz que é) é através de uma senha - um segredo compartilhado entre o usuário e o servidor, que se presume que somente o usuário conheça. Em outras palavras, **algo que o usuário *sabe***.

Outras formas, nem todas aplicáveis à internet, seriam:

- um documento, crachá ou cartão: **algo que o usuário *tem***.
- impressão digital, escaneamento de retina, etc: **algo que o usuário *é***.

A autenticação em dois fatores consiste em se utilizar não uma, mas duas formas de autenticação, de preferência de naturezas distintas (i.e. não vale pedir duas senhas em vez de uma, pois ambas ainda seriam um só fator - o que o usuário *sabe*). Assim, ainda que uma dessas formas for comprometida (alguém copiou a senha, alguém roubou o cartão, [o escaneamento de retina deu falso positivo](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/65762/6939)) a chance de que a outra também o seja são bem menores.

Também é possível se exigir mais de dois fatores, mas isso é raro - dado que cada fator adicional dificulta um pouco mais a autenticação (i.e. reduz a conveniência, incomodando os usuários) sem que necessariamente a segurança tenha uma melhoria significativa. Também é possível - e comum - se ter vários fatores à disposição do usuário, sendo que quaisquer dois dentre eles possam ser usados.

### Motivação

Embora o conceito "nome de usuário e senha" seja de conhecimento comum, não deixa de ser um incômodo ao usuário, principalmente se ele possui conta em diversos serviços e cada um deles tem uma política diferente no que diz respeito à "força" da senha (tamanho mínimo, tipos de caracteres exigidos, tipos de caracteres *permitidos*, trocas de senha obrigatórias, etc). Um usuário pode até memorizar as senhas dos serviços mais importantes, individualmente, mas chega um ponto que ele passa a ou reutilizar senhas para não ter que memorizar *mais uma*, ou anotá-las em algum lugar (ex.: um *post-it* grudado no monitor).

Além disso, a "força" média das senhas é bastante baixa: o ser humano é péssimo para pensar em coisas aleatórias, de modo que as senhas de um usuário qualquer sempre acabam por se encaixar num certo padrão. Os atacantes estão cientes disso, e as técnicas usadas para "adivinhar" senhas - [bem como as ferramentas existentes para se auxiliar na tarefa](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2007/01/choosing_secure.html) - estão suficientemente sofisticadas a ponto de tornar árdua a tarefa de se utilizar senhas seguras. A melhor opção hoje em dia é usar um [gerenciador de senhas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerenciador_de_senha), mas esses além de por vezes inconvenientes ainda representam um "único ponto de falha" (se alguém roubar sua senha mestra, todas as suas senhas são roubadas de uma vez só).

Por fim, há a questão de se fazer login em um computador/dispositivo que você não controla: se você entra com sua senha numa máquina infectada por um *keylogger*, por exemplo, não interessa o quão boa é sua senha - ela está passível de ser capturada. Pior ainda se ela for a senha mestra do seu gerenciador de senhas! Essa é uma que você não quer de jeito nenhum digitar num computador não confiável, mas se você fizer questão de só entrar com ela em um dispositivo seu, isso já se caracteriza como dois fatores (i.e. para obter a senha real, você precisa ao mesmo tempo estar de posse do seu dispositivo - algo que você *tem* - e usar sua senha mestra para desbloqueá-lo - algo que você *sabe*).

### Implementação

Embora certos métodos de autenticação tenham um custo (ex.: enviar um código ao usuário via SMS - se certificando que o usuário *tem* seu aparelho de celular), outros estão acessíveis a qualquer um que quiser usá-los. Um deles é a ["senha descartável"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senha_descart%C3%A1vel) (*one-time password*), cuja implementação mais comum é através de um [HOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) ("senha descartável baseada em [HMAC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)") e sua variante [TOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) ("senha descartável baseada em tempo"). Outro é marcar um computador como "confiável", [contendo um cookie com um símbolo secreto e de longa data de expiração](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26745/6939).

Uma boa utilização dessas técnicas seria oferecê-las todas ao mesmo tempo - a senha como "o que o usuário sabe" e qualquer uma das outras como "o que o usuário tem". Usando o Google como exemplo, quando um usuário habilita a autenticação em dois fatores, ele precisa para fazer login além de sua senha um dos seguintes:

- Estar fazendo esse login a partir de um "computador confiável" (i.e. o cookie enviado pelo browser prova que o usuário está de posse do seu computador pessoal);
- Estar de posse de um dispositivo móvel com o [Google Authenticator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) (ou aplicação compatível), capaz de gerar senhas descartáveis baseadas em tempo;

  - Ou simplesmente um dispositivo capaz de receber SMS, mas aqui estamos falando de métodos acessíveis a todos.
- Estar de posse dos seus [códigos de backup](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538?hl=pt-BR), que são uma forma de senha descartável baseada em HMAC. Onde o usuário guardou esses códigos - em papel, em arquivo, etc - é da conta dele, mas prova que ele está de posse de algo que presumivelmente ninguém mais possui.

Cada uma dessas técnicas é de fácil implementação, e isso se já não existirem bibliotecas prontas na sua plataforma de escolha que o façam pra você. Em particular o TOTP, em que basta você implementar a parte *server-side* de modo compatível com o Google Authenticator (se quiser, inclusive gerando um [QRCode](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_QR) pro usuário não ter que digitar nada) e usá-la junto com esse próprio aplicativo.

### Cuidados

Por fim, uma nota rápida em relação aos casos *excepcionais*: muitos sites oferecem uma opção pro usuário resetar sua senha, simplesmente enviando ao e-mail do usuário um link para concluir a ação. Essa prática, sozinha, elimina completamente o "algo que o usuário *sabe*", delegando a autenticação inteira à premissa que o usuário ainda tem controle sobre seu endereço de e-mail. Em outras palavras, quem obtiver acesso ao e-mail do usuário, pode resetar todas as suas senhas... Por essa razão, há quem proponha até mesmo eliminar a senha da equação, reduzindo o processo de login a simplesmente enviar um e-mail pro usuário com um link de acesso de validade única.

Isso não é o ideal, pois depender apenas do que o usuário *tem* para autenticá-lo torna o roubo de suas credenciais uma maneira bastante atrativa de ataque (ex.: você acessa seu e-mail via smartphone? o que, além de um padrão ou um simples *swipe* impede alguém que pegue seu aparelho de ler todo seu e-mail?). Um componente secreto é importante, ainda que não tão forte quanto possível. Se seu modo primário de autenticação é o que você *tem*, isso permite que mesmo uma senha fraca ainda cumpra bem o seu papel - como as senhas de banco, que em geral são numéricas e curtas, mas isso pouco importa pois sem seu cartão com chip você não faz nada.

Por essa razão, é importante oferecer múltiplos meios de autenticação, e deixar claro ao usuário a importância de protegê-los. Pois ao evitar o erro de se "relaxar" demais a forma de recuperação de senha, você pode acabar cometendo um outro erro, de inviabilizar a recuperação do acesso a uma conta perdida. Ou seja, quando for decidir entre oferecer ou não múltiplos fatores de autenticação - e qual o "peso" de cada um deles, quais as alternativas caso um ou outro seja perdido - ter sempre em mente o equilíbrio entre **autenticidade** e **disponibilidade**.