# Como garantir que a pessoa que usou o sistema é realmente ela?

Tags: java, validação, autenticação

Na universidade em que estudo estamos desenvolvendo um sistema em Java EE para desburocratizar alguns processos de matrícula, extinguindo formulários e gerando formulários em PDF que em vez de passar literalmente por mão e mão, passarão por pessoa em pessoa dentro do sistema. Primeiramente pensamos assim, vamos criar um botão, se o funcionário (que pode ser professor, diretor de centro etc.) clicar em deferir (como se ele assinasse) é porque está deferido e pronto, mas e se alguém pedir alguma prova de que realmente foi ele que deferiu tal inscrição? Como provar? Como podemos assegurar que somente o funcionário vá fazer um deferimento? Considerando que o mesmo pode acessar o sistema de qualquer computador/smartphone, em qualquer lugar, a única restrição é que ele terá um período no mês específico para fazer tal deferimento.

Comment: Deletei parte dos meus comments pra nao ficar bagunçado aqui, sugeriria vc fazer o mesmo. Jajá a gente vai estar sugerindo por um scanner de DNA nos terminais. O cara põe o braço no sensor, toma uma agulhada, e se o DNA bater, é ele :)

Comment: Brincadeiras à parte, podia fazer um sistema com senha que mandasse um SMS de confirmação com token pro celular do responsavel. Apenas ao lançar esse token no sistema num prazo razoavel de tempo seria reconhecido o deferimento.

Comment: @Bacco eu Assisti Gattacca, dá para burlar o sistema do DNA :)

Comment: Cada usuário não tem seu próprio login e senha pra acessar o sistema? Neste caso, basta armazenar o registro do usuário que deferiu o processo. A garantia de que a pessoa é realmente ela está na privacidade do login. Usar soluções mais complexas pode acabar ferindo o seu próprio princípio inicial de "desburocratizar alguns processos de matrícula". :)

Comment: Realmente, algumas opções iriam burocratizar mais =/

Comment: 3 opções:
1) senha. Mas se a pessoa coloca a senha num post-it...
2) ligação entre o site e a pessoa 'física'. Tipo Leitor Biométrico. Problema: para acessar precisa estar na frente do computador que tem o leitor. 
3) ligação entre o site e um sistema física mas sem obrigação de estar na frente de um computador especifico. Tipo enviar um SMS o um mensagem "vocal": o site cria o código, memoriza ele na base de dados durante por exemplo 5 min, envia ele e espera que a pessoa digita o código. 
Da também um olhada aqui https://www.yubico.com/

Comment: Somente o Biométrico, pois o Token (nda impede de emprestar para alguém)

Comment: Acredito que o Bacco e o Peter tenham razão. Eu iria de SMS. A Google usa SMS. Se envolvesse grandes quantias de dinheiro justificaria utilizar leitores biométricos. Aqui na minha universidade todos os documentos são assinados digitalmente, e utilizamos apenas login e senha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> e se alguém pedir alguma prova de que realmente foi ele que deferiu tal inscrição?

O nome dessa característica que você procura é [**não-repúdio**](http://www.documentoeletronico.com.br/faqTEC010.asp) (*non-repudiation*). É uma das características que sistemas criptográficos frequentemente buscam alcançar (as outras sendo **confidencialidade**, **autenticidade** e **integridade**).

Antes de comentar sobre as maneiras *"hard"* de garantir não-repúdio, quero dizer que concordo com as demais respostas e comentários: se você *confia* nos funcionários e na equipe de TI da sua universidade (i.e. não está preocupado por exemplo com algum administrador do sistema inserir manualmente no banco um deferimento em nome de um professor, sem sua autorização), então tudo não passa de uma questão de autenticação e autorização:

- Estabeleça suas políticas de credenciais de modo a reduzir o risco de alguém acessar indevidamente a conta do professor (por exemplo, exigindo senhas fortes - [porém memoráveis](http://xkcd.com/936/) - mais alguma forma de [segundo fator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32559/215)). Na minha faculdade, por exemplo, recebemos um papel com uma lista de PINs, e para cada ação "sensível" no sistema tínhamos que inserir um deles, mesmo já estando logado. Esse PIN usado não era mais reutilizado pra nada.
- Cuide para que sua aplicação estabeleça as regras de autorização corretamente (i.e. garanta que só os usuários do grupo "professores" tenham acesso à funcionalidade "deferir").

Se, por outro lado, você precisa de uma garantia mais forte, então entramos nas soluções de natureza técnica. Algumas pessoas sugeriram biometria, de forma séria ou jocosa, mas o fato é que biometria serve para *autenticação*, não para não-repúdio. Pior, sozinha a biometria nem é assim tão boa para autenticar: se você deixar uma porta não supervisionada com um leitor de retina ao lado, onde basta a pessoa olhar para a porta se abrir, aproximadamente 7000 pessoas poderiam olhar para ela e o sistema identificá-las como sendo **você**... Biometria só funciona se for acompanhada de outros fatores (ex.: você mostra um documento para um funcionário - se **identificando** - e depois olha pro leitor de retina - se **autenticando**). [Essa resposta no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/65762/6939) mostra mais detalhes.

O meio mais utilizado para não-repúdio é a assinatura digital. Digamos que cada professor cria para si um certificado digital (onde *ele próprio* estabeleceu a chave privada - se foi a própria faculdade que forneceu isso a ele, o não-repúdio não se aplica), e registra-o no seu sistema. A própria universidade pode ser a Autoridade Certificadora, ou em casos ainda mais formais pode-se usar por exemplo [os serviços da ICP-Brasil](http://www.iti.gov.br/index.php/certificacao-digital/como-obter) - cujas assinaturas digitais têm por lei a mesma validade das assinaturas "normais" neste país. Esse certificado pode ficar no próprio computador do usuário (menos seguro) ou em um *smartcard* (mais seguro).

É responsabilidade do usuário garantir a segurança de seu certificado, não permitir que sua chave privada seja acessada por terceiros. E/ou notificar imediatamente a universidade caso se suspeite que o mesmo foi comprometido. Nessas condições, partindo então do pressuposto que somente o professor tem acesso à sua chave privada, basta fazer com que suas ações críticas no sistema tenham de ser digitalmente assinada por ele. Assim, ao mesmo tempo que se garante sua integridade e autenticidade (i.e. ninguém pode mexer no conteúdo sem invalidar a assinatura, e ninguém pode assinar por ele) se tem também o não-repúdio (se a assinatura dele está lá, não tem como ele negar que foi ele quem assinou).

De novo, estou dando essas informações com o fim de tornar a resposta completa: essa parafernália toda tem um custo nada desprezível (se não em dinheiro, mas em inconveniência para os usuários), e não deve ser usada a menos que realmente necessário. Em 99% dos casos é *overkill*, e a simples confiança nos administradores do sistema é suficiente para transformar a autenticidade em não-repúdio ("está registrado no banco que a ação X foi executada pelo usuário Y, ponto final").

Comment: Cara, excelente resposta! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Vou ver com o cliente o que vai ser feito, mas vamos ficar entre duas opções que você colocou, ou assinatura digital que espero que os professores não achem tanta burocracia, ou apenas o "está registrado no banco que a ação X foi executada pelo usuário Y."

Comment: @JoãoNeto Eu espero sinceramente que eles concordem com a saída mais simples, pois muito raramente tal nível de "paranoia" é necessário... Mas se decidirem por usar assinatura digital, [esse artigo](http://java.dzone.com/articles/digital-signatures-javascript) (em inglês) pode ser do seu interesse, pois ele trata justamente de assinar algo no browser e verificar a assinatura no servidor Java. não é *cross-browsers* (FF e IE somente), mas enquanto não padronizarem o WebCrypto é difícil conseguir coisa muito melhor.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada! Espero que realmente eles fiquem com a opçao mais simples.

Answer (score 2):

Vejo que a única forma é com um login, como é uma universidade todos tem que ter seu RA cadastrados na entidade ou seja você deverá utilizar deste para autêntica-los como também deverá haver uma senha, o que me vem a cabeça é você pedir um  email para cada aluno para que por meio deste este receba sua senha ou que os mesmos cadastrem sua senha na universidade diante da apresentação do cartão da escola.

Infelizmente sem isso não vejo como autenticar essas pessoas com segurança e integridade

Answer (score 1):

É necessário saber o quanto hardcore você quer ser para realmente garantir que ele é determinada pessoa.

---

**CASO 01:** em uma votação realmente precisa ser ele.

**Solução:** Leitor Biométrico.

---

**CASO 02**: Acesso a uma página (exemplo sites de banco)

**Solução:** Token ou SMS code

---

**CASO 03:** Acesso a uma página

**Solução:** Acesso em 2 ou 3 etapas, sendo que a 2ª e 3ª etapa pode variar com Senha, Pergunta secreta, dados do cadastro, etc.

Mais Informações (links):

https://www.google.com/intl/pt-BR/landing/2step/

[2 etapas Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/two-step-verification-faq)

Comment: Biometria é muito boa para identificação ou autenticação, mas [não as duas ao mesmo tempo](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/65762/6939). Um segundo fator é crucial quando se trabalha com biometria. E eu entendi errado, ou você está sugerindo uma segurança *menor* para "sites de banco" do que para sites "normais"?

Comment: vc diz do acesso em 2 etapas vs site de banco? bom apenas informei como é hoje, sites de banco fazem validação em algumas etapas sim...e ainda usam o token..

Comment: Eu devo ter interpretado mal sua resposta então... O fato é que todos os métodos indicados me parecem variações de um mesmo tema - autenticação em 2 fatores. No caso do voto temos algo que você tem (seu documento) + algo que você é (biometria); nos demais, algo que você sabe (senha) + algo que você tem (o telefone que vai receber SMS/gerar códigos de autenticação). Apenas quando todas as "etapas" envolvem só algo que você sabe (senha, pergunta secreta, dados do cadastro, etc) sem incluir algo que você tem/é, é que a autenticação só tem um único fator, e portanto é mais fraca.