# Criptografar senhas da forma mais segura possível

Tags: android, criptografia

Gostaria de saber como criptografar senhas no Android e quais são as melhores práticas.

Estou usando Eclipse, banco de dados SQlite para armazenar a senha localmente e MySql com PHP para armazenar no servidor via `HttpClient`. Minha aplicação vai ser de uso online e offline. Por isso qualquer cadastro ou alteração de dados do usuário, é feito no servidor e só depois localmente, ou seja, só online que o usuário pode se cadastrar ou alterar seus dados.

Uma alternativa que acho boa seria criptografar a senha, gerar um hash para evitar que seja alterada durante o envia para o servidor e gerar uma espécie de hash de assinatura do dispositivo para que o servidor saiba que a senha veio de um dispositivo com a aplicação instalada e concatenar tudo ficaria assim:

"Senha Criptografada" + "Hash de integridade" + "Hash de autenticidade"

E o servidor iria verificar tudo isso e armazenar no banco de dados tudo isso junto também localmente e externamente.

Comment: Duplicata(?), relacionada: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/4808)

Comment: É realmente necessário armazenar a senha no dispositivo do usuário? Se seu aplicativo vai conseguir descriptografar a senha, um usuário malicioso também vai. O ideal neste caso é usar um web service.

Comment: @André Ribeiro Eu sei disso, mas o meu aplicativo vai ser de uso online e offline, neste caso eu tenho uma sugestão que pode ser útil, mas não sei como poderia implementa-la, vou editar a pergunta com a minha sugestão.

Comment: @renan Duplicata não aquele link se refere ao uso de hash e a minha se trata de criptografia que é um hash bem melhorado.

Comment: Não entendi o que tem a ver o aplicativo ser online e offline com salvar senhas localmente.

Comment: @Pablo Tem a ver porque o usuário vai poder fazer login no aplicativo mesmo estando sem internet (offline), ele poderá logar e deslogar mesmo estando offline entende?

Comment: E no caso eu vou salvar no servidor porque como o aplicativo terá uma versão desktop o usuário poderá baixar seu perfil do servidor e usar no desktop e mobile.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante Criptografia não é "um hash bem melhorado", a função do hash é a partir de uma entrada gerar um valor único que a represente mas que não seja possível fazer o processo inverso (obter o dado original a partir do hash). Já a função da criptografia é transformar um dado em outro, ilegível, e depois transformar de volta no dado original com o auxílio de um valor secreto (senha ou chave). São técnicas diferentes, aplicáveis em situações diferentes. Normalmente pra proteger senhas se usa hashes, criptografia é inútil nesse sentido (ver o comentário do André Ribeiro).

Comment: 1. Não guarde a senha do usuario, guarde apenas o Hash gerado dessa senha. 2. Guarde o hash gerado no aplicativo se a autenticacao for valida no servidor (online) 3. Quando o usuario colocar o login offline, gere o Hash do login e valide se a transformação em Hash bate com o armazenado, quando estiver online, ignore a validação local e solicite ao servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uma alternativa que acho boa seria criptografar a senha, gerar um hash para evitar que seja alterada durante o envia para o servidor e gerar uma espécie de hash de assinatura do dispositivo para que o servidor saiba que a senha veio de um dispositivo com a aplicação instalada e concatenar tudo ficaria assim:

Nunca invente sua própria criptografia! As chances de algo saírem errado são enormes. Em vez disso, use um protocolo bem estabelecido para o que quer:

1. Conecte-se ao seu servidor usando SSL/TLS. Assim os dados que você enviar a ele já serão confidenciais e íntegros, não é necessário nem criptografar a senha nem gerar um hash (aliás, um hash não evita que ela seja alterada durante o envio; um MAC talvez, mas isso é outra história). E se você combinar isso com uma autenticação do cliente usando certificados, você já garante a autenticidade também, bastando enviar só a senha simples mesmo e pronto!
2. Se precisar armazenar a senha do usuário no dispositivo (não está claro na pergunta se o usuário vai ter que digitá-la toda vez que for se conectar ao seu servidor, ou se isso ficará salvo no aparelho), procure algum recurso do próprio sistema para auxiliá-lo. Não tenho experiência com Android, mas uma busca rápida me trouxe o [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) - que me parece ser um meio centralizado de gerenciar as contas que o usuário tem em diversos serviços. Sugiro dar uma estudada nele.

### Detalhando

Se o que eu expliquei acima não ficou claro, deixe-me quebrar o problema em partes menores pra ficar mais fácil de entender a solução proposta (e talvez apresentar algumas alternativas):

#### Salvando senhas no dispositivo

A menos que você queira que o usuário entre com sua senha toda vez que for se conectar com seu servidor, é preciso que algum método de autenticação seja armazenado no dispositivo. Nesse caso, não dá pra fazer um hash da senha porque você precisa da senha no seu formato original para enviar ao servidor (do contrário *o hash vira a senha*, e qualquer atacante que obtenha uma cópia do hash já possui as credenciais necessárias para se autenticar com o servidor). Criptografar é uma ideia, mas onde guardar a chave? Essa é uma situação complicada, daí minha sugestão de usar o que já tem pronto no Android e tirar isso da cabeça...

#### Comunicando-se seguramente com o servidor

Se você não usar SSL/TLS (ex.: HTTPS), não dá pra garantir que a comunicação com o servidor não será interceptada e até modificada (em particular em redes abertas). Tentar "se virar" sem TLS vai te deixar com uma solução insegura e/ou vai te obrigar a reinventar muitas rodas. Por isso eu sugiro fortemente usar esse protocolo.

Ao criar um canal seguro via TLS, você pode enviar as credenciais do usuário em formato plano, sem a necessidade de encriptar. Pois o protocolo garante a confidencialidade (i.e. ninguém pode ler a comunicação) e a integridade (ninguém pode alterar a comunicação) de ambos, além da autenticidade do servidor (o cliente sabe que está se comunicando com o servidor certo).

#### Autenticando o dispositivo

Na pergunta você mostra preocupação com o dispositivo que originou a requisição ("...para que o servidor saiba que a senha veio de um dispositivo com a aplicação instalada..."). Ou seja, além de autenticar o usuário com o servidor, você também quer autenticar o dispositivo com o servidor.

A princípio, isso também pode ser feito via SSL/TLS, com o uso de certificados do cliente. Grosso modo, ao instalar a aplicação ela geraria um certificado para aquele dispositivo, registraria esse certificado no servidor (ou simplesmente teria aquele certificado assinado por uma CA que o servidor confia), e então ao se comunicar via TLS utilizaria esse certificado com o protocolo. Assim ambos cliente e servidor estariam autenticados entre si, e bastaria então você autenticar o usuário (enviando a senha em seu formato normal).

Se tudo isso for muito complicado, uma alternativa mais simples seria gerar uma senha aleatória pra ser a "senha do dispositivo", e cadastrá-la no servidor junto à senha do usuário. Essa senha seria então enviada durante a autenticação, também sob o canal seguro estabelecido anteriormente.

#### Salvando senhas no servidor

No servidor, naturalmente, você não vai guardar a(s) senha(s) em formato plano, mas sim um hash da(s) mesma(s). Veja a pergunta ["Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura?lq=1) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Sua ideia para autenticação da aplicação com servidor e vice versa é ótima, no entanto em relação a enviar a senha em texto plano e ter que fazer o hash no servidor eu terei que fazer o mesmo hash no dispositivo e armazenar no banco de dados local se isso for possível então seria ótimo já que mesmo se um hacker tiver acesso ao banco de dados local ele teria que enviar a senha em texto plano e não o hash pro servidor mesmo se conseguisse se passar pelo dispositivo usando os mesmos protocolos.

Comment: Mas como sabemos que não existe nada 100% seguro acrescentar a criptografia na senha que esta sendo enviada não seria ruim desde que não só a senha seja criptografada, mas sim todo o login, desta forma se por algum motivo o hacker obter acesso ao que está sendo enviado ele não saberá o que é usuário ou senha da string criptografada e além disso poderia add nessa string uma espécie de contador de ultimo acesso dessa forma se o hacker usar essa string criptografada novamente para se autenticar não vai conseguir, pois o contador de acesso não será mais válido.

Comment: O problema nesse caso seria descriptografar a string no servidor usando uma chave que não está sendo enviada, pois o hacker poderia ter acesso a chave. Nesse caso eu poderia fazer uma chave única e fixa nessa criptografia, claro que essa forma ainda deixa uma vulnerabilidade de se caso o hacker descobrir uma única chave, ele terá acesso a senha de todos os usuários bastando só capturar a string que está sendo enviada quando o usuário estiver logando, porém isso traria uma maior dificuldade do que enviar os dados em texto plano.

Comment: Em relação ao hash eu vou pesquisar mais para implementar nos dois ambientes cliente e servidor. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Em relação a autenticação com servidor o usuário não vai precisar digitar nada o próprio dispositivo vai gerar sua chave única de autenticação com base no usuário e na senha.

Comment: Repito: não invente sua própria criptografia! Seus argumentos até que fazem sentido, mas são muitos detalhezinhos que são fáceis de passarem despercebidos, por isso minha recomendação de se ater aos protocolos padronizados. Além disso, é bom ter o modelo de ameaça claro em mente: você está preocupado em um hacker interceptar a comunicação? em roubar o aparelho em si? ambos? As defesas aplicáveis (se alguma) dependem desse modelo de ameaça. Felizmente, o SSL/TLS e o `AccountManager` parecem cobrir todos os casos tratáveis de forma satisfatória, e os intratáveis o jeito é deixar pra lá...

Comment: Alguns comentários sobre o que você propôs: 1) hash é irreversível, hashear no banco de dados local vai inviabilizar que essa mesma senha seja usada como **credencial**. Receio não ter nenhum meio 100% seguro de armazenar credenciais num dispositivo, por isso ou você autentica só o dispositivo (e qualquer um que tiver posse dele está autenticado) ou você autentica o dispositivo e o usuário (exigindo que o usuário entre com sua senha ou PIN; ver também [autenticação em dois fatores](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32559/215)). 2) criptografar no dispositivo é inútil se você não conseguir...

Comment: ...proteger a chave! Nesse caso a segurança adicional da criptografia é *zero*, é mais "teatro de segurança" do que segurança em si. E pra proteger os dados em trânsito, não precisa de nada disso, o canal SSL/TLS seguro já da conta disso. 3) realmente usar uma chave simétrica para o servidor e todos os clientes é complicado, pois como você falou um único dispositivo crackeado revela dados de todos os usuários. Ou você tem uma chave por usuário, ou usa criptografia assimétrica (chave privada no servidor, chave pública nos dispositivos). Só não entendi como isso ia ajudar na segurança, pois...

Comment: ...os dados criptografados ainda seriam a mesma **credencial de acesso** (i.e. o que o dispositivo tem e pode ser usado para logar, o hacker pode roubar e também usar pra logar... não tem "mágica" que proteja nesse caso). Enfim, você nota como o problema é complexo? Eu estudo criptografia há alguns anos, mas ainda conheço pouco do assunto, e ainda cometo muita besteira. Por isso reafirmo minha opinião que esse tipo de coisa é melhor ser deixada pros especialistas, sempre que possível. Um protocolo "feito à mão" tem muita chance de dar errado, e acabar pior do que não usar nada.

Comment: Vou aplicar o mais simples e mais utilizado, como você mesmo recomendou. O que eu quero para essa aplicação é que se caso um hacker conseguir pegar o dispositivo de alguém, ele não consiga ter acesso aos dados do usuário local ou em nuvem. Além disso se acaso ele consiga interceptar o que o usuário esté enviado pela rede, ele não consiga saber o que é. De todo caso sua resposta e seus comentários foram de grande ajuda. Vejo que esse é um assunto bem complexo  e precisa ser estudado mais a fundo para tentar fazer algo próprio como foi o que eu quis fazer.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção vou encerrar deixando sua resposta como escolhida, pois o que eu quero fazer é algo que no momento não será possível.

Answer (score 0):

Após umas pesquisas eu achei um exemplo pronto utilizando AES nesse site: http://www.iai.art.br/radar/android-development-criptografia-baseada-em-senha/

Funcionou bem ele criptografa e descriptografa também, pra mim eu só queria um que apenas criptografasse sem possibilidade de descriptografar, mas esse serve por enquanto. Minha dúvida nesse código é em relação a esse método de criptografia que eu não sei se ele vai gerar algum código criptografado com este caractér "#", pois estou usando ele e este "^" para separar a string e montar os campos para armazenar no banco. O método é esse:

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String password)    throws
  NoSuchAlgorithmException,
  InvalidKeySpecException,
  NoSuchPaddingException,
  InvalidParameterSpecException,
  IllegalBlockSizeException,
  BadPaddingException,
  UnsupportedEncodingException,
  InvalidKeyException,
  InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
  byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
  byte[] ivBytes = initializationVector.getBytes("UTF-8");
  SecretKeyFactory factory =   SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

  PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
       password.toCharArray(),
       saltBytes,
       pswdIterations,
       keySize
  );
  SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
  SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new       IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
  byte[] encryptedTextBytes =  cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedTextBytes, 0);
}
```

E se alguém tiver uma sugestão melhor, seria de grande ajuda.