# Restrição de acesso por tempo com php

Tags: php, segurança

Quero desenvolver um sistema de segurança, que sirva tanto para formulário de contato quanto para login, a intenção é que seja um adicional ao uso do CAPTCHA, ou em alguns casos um substituto. A lógica é o seguinte:

O usuário pode acessar no maximo 4 vezes durante intervalos de 7 segundos, se ele acessar mais de 4 vezes aquela determinada pagina de envio de dados dentro de 7 segundos, o sistema entende como um *bot* e redireciona o usuário para outro local para "desviar" o tráfego ou executa outra medida de segurança.

Esse foi o código experimental que desenvolvi junto com alguns amigos.

OBS 1: Não sou especialista em PHP, estou sempre em constante aprendizado, por isso dicas e metodologias são sempre bem vindas.

OBS 2: A ideia é redirecionar *bots* para evitar o envio de *spam* ou até mesmo ataques como *brute force*, então é um código generico para uso em vários casos

```
<?php
// Detecta BOT
session_start();
$maxTempoLim = 7; //Tempo Limite
$maxVezesLim = 4; //Numero de Vezes possiveis dentro do tempo limite

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['temp_bot'])) {
    $_SESSION['temp_bot'] = time();
    $_SESSION['conta_vezbot'] = 1;
}

$diferenTime = time() - $_SESSION['temp_bot'];

if ($diferenTime <= $maxTempoLim) {
    $_SESSION['conta_vezbot']++;
    if ($_SESSION['conta_vezbot'] > $maxVezesLim) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: spam_detectado.php'); //redireciona
        // ou colocar outra ação ao invés de redirecionar
        exit;
    }
}
```

A ideia surgiu a partir de uma situação onde tentaram enviar spams para um formulário de contato na minha página e de alguns clientes, ambos eu adicionei um CAPTCHA e funcionou muito bem, só que eu não queria obrigar o usuário a digitar o CAPTCHA, gostaria de criar algo que detecta que é um *bot* ou qualquer outro tipo de sistema acessando ininterruptamente, e através da quantidade de acesso por segundo, ou por um periodo de tempo que para um usuário comum seria impossivel, redirecionar o tráfego.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Desculpe, mas isso vai ser mais um tiro no pé que uma medida de segurança.

> Spam zombies são computadores de usuários finais que foram comprometidos por códigos maliciosos em geral, como worms, bots, vírus e cavalos de tróia. Estes códigos maliciosos, uma vez instalados, permitem que spammers utilizem a máquina para o envio de spam, sem o conhecimento do usuário. Enquanto utilizam máquinas comprometidas para executar suas atividades, dificultam a identificação da origem do spam e dos autores também. Os spam zombies são muito explorados pelos spammers, por proporcionar o anonimato que tanto os protege. [**Fonte**](http://www.antispam.br/conceito/)

Muito SPAM é enviado por computadores infectados e os usuários nem sabem. Seu formulário poderá ser acessado:

1. Por várias máquinas diferentes ao mesmo tempo
2. Pela mesma máquina em tempos diferentes

---

Se sua ideia é tentar impedir o envio, esses dois casos acima estariam fora da sua lógica.

Não creio que esse seja o caminho para evitar SPAM. Uma possível solução seria você validar o `user-agent` e verificar a incidência de envios por parte daquela máquina, junto com os dados do remetente, e a própria mensagem em si.

Mas serão 'medidas' que não garantirão de que todos os bloqueios serão SPAM ou que os enviados sejam legítimos.

*Se o seu formulário só permite o envio por usuários registrados e identificados, o próprio login se torna uma prevenção ANTI-SPAM.*

---

**Atualização**

Receio que o melhor seja fazer a segurança individual para cada caso. Para um ataque tipo *brute force*, você pode fazer algumas camadas de segurança e validação:

1. Após X tentativas dentre um período de X minutos, você pode incluir o código captcha
2. Você pode pedir alguma informação adicional da conta, como a data de nascimento cadastrada ou outra informação
3. Verificar quantas contas a mesma máquina está *tentando* acessar
4. Você pode criar um algorítimo para comparar a similaridade da senha cadastrada com a senha usada no login

São apenas algumas idéias. Eu jamais usaria um `Location: span_detectado.php` motivado por um comportamento anormal de um usuário. Interação é a chave, use mensagens amigáveis sem que o usuário sinta-se frustrado.

*Outro dia acessei meu email pelo celular e o servidor bloqueou meu acesso mesmo com senha. Quase abandonei e mudei meu email.* Por isso recomendo cuidado para não confundir um usuário sem experiência com uma possível ameaça.

Comment: a ideia para uso desse algoritimo é bem variada, inclusive para evitar Brute force em logins, entre outras aplicações, onde não permite o acesso pelo periodo citado, mas não sei se algo desse tipo que fiz resolveria, ou se aplicaria o mesmo "tiro no pé" que vc disse sobre spam em todas as soluções que pretendo aplicar

Comment: Minha resposta foi uma explicação para os casos de SPAM, como você mencionou. Para o caso de login, você pode adotar um padrão de X tentativas. Acrescente os casos na pergunta.

Comment: Ou crie uma nova pergunta, afinal cada pergunta deve ter apenas um assunto e não deve invalidar respostas já existentes.

Comment: Podia ver esse assunto aqui também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32533/algoritimo-contra-brute-force. Creio que já da uma ajudinha :D

Comment: @Cold Eu tinha lido, mas não concordo com alguns pontos, por isso não linkei. O problema é a paranoia é grande - e com razão -  e pode acabar tornando a segurança uma péssima experiência para o usuário. Bloquear acesso após X tentativas, não é nada bom.

Comment: Realmente, não pensei sobre como ficaria a usabilidade no caso do login, obrigado por me alertar, mas na questão do envio de dados de algum formulario de contato? será que ajudaria? 
não tenho conhecimento avançado sobre o funcionamento dos _bots_, nunca tive a oportunidade de ver o código de um

Comment: fiz uma atualização no código, dá uma olhada

Comment: @GabrielMasson *[...]formulario de contato? será que ajudaria?[...]* É como eu disse, a chance de passar SPAM é grande. Somente usuários logados podem enviar o formulário?

Comment: não, são formularios de sites institucionais, a intenção é diminuir o fluxo deles, pois até esses dias eu recebia 1 spam a cada 3 segundoscom *loren ipson*

Comment: então, ai coloquei Captcha e funcionou, entretanto o usuario ter que digitar Captcha toda vez que for enviar é complicado

Comment: @GabrielMasson, o link que o Cold postou acima tem algumas sugestões que podem ser interessantes. Dê uma olhadinha e se achar que vale a pena eu posso propor algumas outras ideias.

Comment: @Gabrielmasson a resposta do Papacharlie é relevante do problema que tem pela frente. Se não tem experiência vai ser difícil. Já pensou por exemplo o que acontece se a sessão for renovada á terceira tentativa? Com isto dizer que o Cold colocou um link que deve de ler. Uma resposta eficaz ao seu problema passa também pelos recursos que tem á sua disposição.