# Recuperar password md5 de uma aplicação Android

Tags: android, sqlite, md5

Criei uma aplicação Android onde pede uma senha para acesso ao aplicativo.
O usuário cadastra essa senha (numérica) e um email para recuperar senha, os dados são gravados no SQLite e estou usando MD5 para guardar no banco de dados e "logar" no aplicativo...

É um aplicativo que esconde imagens e vídeos... Ele monta uma galeria, ai para acessar o aplicativo e ver a galeria de imagens e vídeos, precisa da senha. Ele não se conecta com algum servidor web...
Se eu deixar a senha visível, a pessoa pode abrir o banco com um explorer ou até mesmo app de SQLite e ver/editar a senha facilmente. Considerando que meu app pode esconder até conteúdo de grande importância (como vídeos íntimos), acontecer isso resultaria em uma infeliz 1 estrela no rate da minha aplicação.

Resumindo, eu não quero uma segurança extra, quero apenas que dificulte para alguém descobrir a senha, ou pelo menos não dificulte que seja visualizada pelo próprio banco.

Como fazer para recuperar esta senha caso o usuário esqueça, estava pensando em enviar via email, mas não há como, já que eu estaria enviando a senha em MD5!

Algum outro método?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, usar MD5 pra hashear senhas é uma péssima ideia. Você deve decidir se é ou não importante fazer esse hash e, se a resposta for "sim", [fazê-lo da forma apropriada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215) (i.e. usando um algoritmo de hash próprio para esse propósito, que empregue um sal e um fator de trabalho).

Em geral, se faz o hash de senhas baseado no seguinte cenário: "eu tenho um banco de dados, servindo uma aplicação que pode ser acessada pela internet; se alguém obter uma cópia desse banco de dados - via SQL Injection, ou através de um backup achado no lixo, ou seja como for - eu não quero que essa pessoa possa imediatamente ver quais são as senhas dos usuários, e assim fazer login como se fosse eles".

De acordo com a descrição acima, pergunte a si mesmo:

- Meu aplicativo pode ser acessado remotamente?

  Se a resposta for **não**, não há muito sentido em se hashear as senhas - guarde-as em texto plano mesmo. Pois quem tiver a posse física do aparelho não precisa da senha para acessar - e inclusive modificar - seu banco de dados SQLite.
- Há algum cenário em que alguém não autorizado possa obter uma cópia de leitura (e somente de leitura) do meu banco de dados?

  Eu tenho dificuldade de imaginar tal cenário. Talvez, você emprestou seu telefone pra alguém mal intencionado, e essa pessoa achou uma vulnerabilidade no seu aplicativo e usou ela pra obter uma cópia do banco? Sem o primeiro item de "acesso remoto" esse cenário me parece meio exagerado... Veja se consegue pensar em algum outro.

  Se tal cenário existir, então o ideal é fazer um hash mesmo, de forma correta (ver pergunta linkada no início dessa resposta). Nesse caso, não se deve dar a opção do usuário de recuperar sua senha, mas sim de resetá-la.

Hash de senhas não é uma panacéia: ele serve a propósitos bem específicos - 1) Proteger **a senha em si** (i.e. seu sistema já foi invadido, já era! Mas você não quer que o atacante aproveite disso pra invadir *outros* sistemas nos quais o usuário reutilizou a senha); 2) Evitar que uma vulnerabilidade de leitura escale para uma vulnerabilidade de escrita/acesso completo.

Se essa resposta não resolveu suas dúvidas, favor detalhar melhor qual é seu **modelo de ameaça** (*threat model*) - descreva como é essa senha, o que ela protege e o quão importante é o que ela protege, e quais as consequências dela ser "vazada"; cite os cenários no qual você espera que uma senha hasheada seria melhor que uma senha simplesmente armazenada, ou outras possibilidades de uso indevido do seu aplicativo que te vêm à cabeça. Etc.

P.S. Um último ponto, sobre "recuperar a senha/o acesso pelo e-mail": no seu celular você consegue acessar seu e-mail? Sem precisar de senha nenhuma? Pois a pessoa que estiver de posse do mesmo e for "barrada" de acessar seu aplicativo por causa de uma senha, não pode simplesmente pedir pra resetar a senha por e-mail e então ler, no próprio aparelho, a resposta desse e-mail?

Comment: Obrigado, você me tirou duvidas que eu nem sabia que tinha :D

Comment: Em aparelhos com acesso root pode-se facilmente acessar os bancos sqlite e ler ou modificar qualquer coisa neles...

Comment: @Jader De fato! Se o cenário de ameaça for esse, nada vai adiantar pra proteger o banco, de modo que uma senha em texto plano mesmo é suficiente (i.e. hashing é perda de tempo). O mesmo vale pra casos em que o banco está inacessível para o usuário via explorador de arquivos, acessível somente pra aplicação (não conheço bem de Android, mas lembro que existe essa modalidade, ou algo do tipo). Reiterando, hashing é só pra cenários em que se antecipa que um atacante poderá ler - mas não modificar - o conteúdo do banco. (ou quando a senha é usada pra alguma outra coisa também)

Comment: É um aplicativo que esconde imagens e vídeos... Ele monta uma galeria, ai para acessar o aplicativo e ver a galeria de imagens e vídeos, precisa da senha. Eu sei dessa parte de aplicação com acesso a internet (o que não é meu caso), mas com uma senha não criptografada, a pessoa pode abrir o banco com um explorer ou até mesmo app de SQLite e ver/editar a senha facilmente. Considerando que meu app pode esconder até conteúdo de grande importância (como vídeos íntimos), acontecer isso resultaria em um infeliz 1 estrela no rate da minha aplicação

Comment: Eu sei também que tem maneiras de "decryptar", mas pelo menos estaria protegendo contra leigos ou usuários que não sabem "decryptar". Uma segurança a mais

Comment: @mgibsonbr Editei a resposta adicionando meu comentário. E Jader, já existem aplicativos que dão acesso ao banco (visualização) sem necessitar de root.

Comment: +1 Ótima advertência. MD5 não é recomendado para senhas, hoje é usado para verificar a integridade de arquivos.

Comment: @g.carvalho97 Então você tem um exemplo de outro tipo de criptografia ou outra solução para o meu caso? O texto que o mgibsonbr linkou é muito grande, ainda não li por completo por estar no trabalho

Comment: @felipe.rce Veja a minha resposta para um breve resumo das criptografias geralmente usadas. Ainda assim, recomendo a leitura do artigo que o mgibsonbr postou, é uma ótima leitura.

Comment: @felipe.rce Você precisa ter claro na sua cabeça a distinção entre ***hashing*** e **cifragem** - o primeiro é unidirecional (não dá pra fazer a função inversa), o segundo é bidirecional (uma operação de cifrar, outra de decifrar). E da mesma forma que não faz sentido trancar uma porta e deixar a chave pendurada na fechadura, se você quer "esconder" arquivos você precisa que a senha - ou equivalente - que os abre não seja armazenada no próprio aplicativo. Quem conseguir uma cópia do banco não precisa crackear o hash - basta olhar pros próprios arquivos! (se esses estiverem em formato original)

Comment: Se eles **não** estiverem em formato original - i.e. se eles estiverem cifrados - então a chave de criptografia não pode estar armazenada no aplicativo, **em nenhum formato**. Ela tem de ser *derivada* da senha, armazenada só em memória, e rapidamente "esquecida" (não deixar registros permanentes). Por essa razão, os requisitos de "permitir ao usuário recuperar/resetar a senha" e "usar a senha para proteger arquivos" são inconciliáveis. É preciso estabelecer um limiar a partir do qual você jogue a toalha: "vou tentar parar atacantes casuais, mas quem tiver acesso a X tem acesso a tudo".

Comment: @mgibsonbr na verdade o que estou dando importância é apenas tentar dificultar que alguém abra o banco e leia a senha, tirando as partes de quebras, Brute Force, etc. Eu não entendo muito de cryptografia, ainda estou pesquisando

Comment: Não estou querendo recursos avançados e de grande segurança, até pq eu não tenho tanto conhecimento sobre. Por enquanto preciso que somente "camufle" a senha, por isso acabei usando o MD5...

Comment: É claro que se for para adicionar uma segurança a mais, seria ótimo, mas se for bem mais complicado adicionar essa segurança, para mim não serve, por enquanto... Ainda estou estudando

Comment: Blz, não é minha intenção te desestimular a ir em frente com seu projeto, mas simplesmente "colocar as cartas na mesa" para que você tome decisões conscientes. Você quer parar atacantes casuais, mas eu pergunto: alguém que abre e lê seu BD ainda pode ser considerado um atacante casual? Se você considera que "sim", e quer impedir que ele descubra a senha só de dar uma olhada (mesmo ele podendo olhar todos os dados que a senha protege), então: 1) use um dos algoritmos de hashing sugeridos (BCrypt é bom, mas se estiver difícil achar uma boa implementação, PBKDF2 pode ser mais acessível). E...

Comment: 2) envie para o e-mail do usuário um código pra resetar a senha. Não resete ela de cara, apenas dê um código/link especial que pode ser usado para resetá-la. Isso é muito usado em serviços web - pra evitar que qualquer um resete sua senha sem seu conhecimento. Dessa forma se o e-mail não chegar, você simplesmente manda outro! A senha não foi alterada. P.S. E se no futuro você decidir usar criptografia, lembre-se de não derivar a chave da senha (pois se ela for alterada, o acesso a todos os arquivos será perdido). Boa sorte e, se tiver dúvidas adicionais, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @mgibsonbr se desse para aceitar duas respostas, eu aceitava a de vocês dois, foram importantes para clarear minhas ideias, consegui solucionar o problema, não sei se é uma gambiarra, mas por enquanto é a solução que encontrei (e testei), de uma olhada na minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar, mude seu algoritmo de hashing. MD5 não é recomendado para senhas, e pode ser quebrado facilmente. Dê uma olhada nos algoritmos SHA256, SHA512, BCrypt e BlowFish (recomendo os dois últimos, sendo que os dois primeiros são muito semelhantes ao MD5, porém muito mais fortes).
Em segundo lugar, não seria mais fácil redefinir a senha do que recuperá-la, visto que hashes são praticamente irreversíveis?
Na prática, a recuperação de senhas é uma redefinição, portanto em sistemas protegidos por senha você não recupera sua senha, mas sim a redefine.
A redefinição pode ocorrer de duas maneiras: ou o sistema gera uma senha nova e envia-a ao usuário, ou o sistema faz uma pergunta de segurança definida pelo proprietário da conta, de modo que se a pergunta for respondida corretamente, inicia-se a redefinição de senha. O segundo método é preferível em aplicações web por ser mais fácil para interagir com o usuário.
Minha sugestão é adicionar um sistema de pergunta de segurança ou endereço de redefinição, como os provedores de E-Mail fazem.

Comment: Eu havia pensado na primeira opção, mas ela tem um problema, meu aplicativo não possui conexão com servidor Web, redefinir a senha apenas clicando no botão geraria um problema caso a pessoa não recebesse o email por algum motivo, já que a senha seria alterada antes mesmo de enviar o email... Como eu faria para redefinir a senha sem enviar aqueles links de confirmação que existem na web? para que a senha seja redefinida apenas se o usuário confirmar o recebimento do email? Pela lógica não acho muito possível sem um servidor web

Comment: @felipe.rce Uma pergunta de segurança seria o melhor a se seguir. Registre a pergunta e a resposta no SQLite, e faça o hashing da resposta e da senha com o mesmo algoritmo escolhido.

Comment: Encontrei poucas informações sobre BCrypt no java... Mas encontrei isto aqui: https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/  Já ouviu falar?

Comment: @felipe.rce Nunca ouvi falar dessa, uso uma biblioteca chamada BCrypt.java em meus projetos, mas esse SQLCipher é interessante... só não sei se seria aplicável a seu projeto.

Answer (score 2):

Achei a resposta, não irei aceitar minha própria resposta pois ela foi finalizada graças as respostas do g.carvalho97 e mgibsonbr, estou respondendo para apenas agregar ao conteúdo para quem estiver na dúvida também.

Usei BCrypt no password e na verificação do password. A utilização dele é bastante simples. No site do BCrypt JAVA tem um exemplo e link para download: [BCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)

Caso o usuário esqueça a senha, será enviado um código para reset da senha, este código é uma sequencia de caracteres geradas automaticamente e armazenada na memória por um tempo. O usuário informa este código na aplicação, então ele terá acesso a redefinição de senha!

Como mencionado pelo mgibsonbr, não é uma solução totalmente segura, mas é o que esta me servindo por agora.