# Sessions num sistema de login

Tags: php, session, login

Fiz um sistema de login em PHP onde, depois da autenticação, eu volto para a página de `index.php`.

Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que quando eu redireciono o usuário para o `index.php` novamente, ele me pede os dados de login.

Alguém sabe o que eu estou fazendo errado?

Segue a página `index.php`:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
   session_start(); 
} 

if(!isset($_SESSION["$Email"])){
   echo 'todos os forms de login';
} 
else{
   echo 'todo o site';
}
```

E aqui tem a função de autenticação:

```
public function autenticacao($Email, $Senha){
    $oConexao = new conexaoclass();
    $oConexao -> abrirConexao();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Professores 
            WHERE Email = '$Email' AND Senha = '$Senha'";

    $this -> resultado = mysql_query ($sql, $oConexao -> getConn());

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($this -> resultado);

    if ($rows > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["$Email"] = $Email;
        $_SESSION["$Senha"] = $Senha;

        echo "Login realizado com sucesso! <br> Aguarde, você será redirecionado...";
        echo "<script>login()</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Login inválido!!! Dados incorretos! <br> Aguarde, você será redirecionado...";
        echo "<script>loginFail()</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No lugar de $_SESSION['$email'] utilize $_SESSION['email'] = $email.

Comment: Talvez não seja o foco da pergunta. Mas sempre tente evitar guardar senha pura no banco. Tente guardar a senha criptografada e na hora de autenticar somente comparar as senhas criptografadas. Questão de segurança. Caso seja do seu interesse aqui tem uma boa discussão sobre o assunto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na parte `$_SESSION["$Email"]` tire o `$`.

Você está dizendo ao php que deseja usar como índice da sessão o conteúdo da variável `$Email`, que não está definida no vetor.

De preferencia, ao usar arrays associativos, utilize aspas simples `'`.

Faça isso com as outras ocorrências parecidas no seu código.

Mais informações: [Strings no php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)