# Problema com função mcrypt*

Tags: php, mcrypt

Estou usando essas duas funções abaixo para *encriptar* e *decriptar* uma string. Deixei o exemplo o mais limpo possível.

<sub>**Função para encript**</sub>

```
$key = '123';
$iv  = md5( md5( 'key' ) );
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

<sub>**Função para decript**</sub>

```
$key = '123';
$iv  = md5( md5( 'key' ) );
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Não conheco a fundo a função, e estou com problema para usar json encode/decode. Consigo usar encode sem problema, mas o decode não roda a string *descriptografada*.

Usei como exemplo um array simples `array( 123 )` e o output descriptografado é exatamente igual à `json_encode( array( 123 ) )`, a diferença é o tamanho, mas não aparecem espaços nem antes nem no fim.

<sub>**Dump**</sub>

```
decrypt( $argument )        : string(32) "[123]"
json_encode( array( 123 ) ) : string(5) "[123]"
```

---

Achei uma [*questão*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8429900/1244639) que relata o mesmo problema que o meu e a solução proposta foi o uso de `rtrim( $decrypted , "\0" )`. Funcionou para o autor e para mim, mas a explicação é superficial:

> Diz que a função ENCRYPT/DECRYPT adiciona lixo para ficar com o tamanho correto, e deve remover os nulos ao final da string.

*Também criei valores nulos no final da string mas não afetaram o tamanho no dump.* Não consigo entender de como o tamanho da string não combina.

---

1. O uso de `\0` no `trim` abrange quais caracteres?
2. Gostaria de saber mais sobre as opções **cipher** e **mode**, não encontrei na DOC referências mais profundas de cada caso.
3. É possível combinar **cipher** e **mode** de modo que a string não crie valores nulos para satisfazer o tamanho.

Comment: `rtrim( , "\0" )` abrange apenas o caractere "\0" mesmo. É o mesmo que `rtrim( ,chr(0) )`. Esse _padding_ é uma característica do modo escolhido para a criptografia. É usado para que os blocos fiquem do mesmo tamanho para a função criptográfica. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher - Pena que não dá tempo de eu elaborar como resposta agora cedo.

Comment: @Bacco, usei `trim( $crypt )` e surtiu o mesmo efeito - há diferença? Vi que diz algo a respeito na **RFC 5652**, vou procurar com calma.

Comment: O problema de `trim` sem especificar o `chr(0)` é que se a string original tem espaços e/ou quebras de linha no começo ou no fim, vc acabou de perdê-los também. Ah, outra coisa, aquele `md5(md5())` me dá frio na barriga de ver. Aproveitando, ja leu isso aqui? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/ não tem uma conexão direta com a sua pergunta, mas é interessante saber.

Comment: Entendi a questão do *trim*. O link tem coisas interessantes, lerei com calma - sua resposta precisa de tempo pra assimilar :). Sobre o *md5*, foi um exemplo que peguei para fins didáticos. Nunca trabalhei com `mcrypt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quem vier a encontrar esse tópico no futuro, o que o Bacco disse [nesse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38498/problema-com-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mcrypt#comment74940_38498), basicamente, é remover todo o "lixo" adicionado pelas cifras para que tenham o mesmo tamanho o que, em código, seria isso:

```
$string = json_encode( array( 123 ) );

$key = '123';
$iv  = md5( md5( 'key' ) );

$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(

    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $key ),

    $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv
);

$decrypted = rtrim(

    mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv),

    "\x00..\x1F"
);
```

Basta comparar com um var_dump() e ver que **sem** aquele rtrim() a string encriptada é bem diferente da não encriptada, porém ambas têm o mesmo comprimento:

```
string '’!Ù Èžtvûþ×Ij>+|oÙ(Œà¢qŒ)·Î"“Æ¡h' (length=32)
string '[123]���������������������������' (length=32)
```

Mas (e agora vem minha contribuição), não basta remover apenas o *byte* nulo (\0 ou 0x00) pois cada linguagem pode incluir seu próprio lixinho.

Por isso meu pseudo-código traz um intervalo de caracteres mais amplo **\x00..\x1F**, isto é, os 31 primeiros caracteres da Tabela ASCII.

A propósito, respondendo a [esse seu levantamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38498/problema-com-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mcrypt#comment74942_38498), se você considerar a remoção apenas do *byte* nulo (\0) pode tranquilamente usar rtrim() sem argumentos pois esse caractere já consta na lista de remoção padrão da função.

Comment: Valeu Bruno. Parece que o *decrypt* é meio capenga e esquece de remover o próprio complemento usado. Andei procurando mais sobre a função e encontrei exemplos usando `mcrypt_create_iv` e `mcrypt_get_iv_size`, depois calcula o tamanho do *iv* e subtrai a string.