# Como descriptografar MD5?

Tags: php, criptografia, md5, senhas

Se eu tenho o seguinte código `$senha = md5("senha")` e mando para o banco de dados `$senha`, deveria ser possível recuperar esse `MD5` no banco e mostrar "senha" de volta num formulário de atualização de informações, não?

Isso é possível ou uma *string* criptografada em `MD5` não tem pode ser descriptografada?

Comment: "MD5 Calcula o *hash MD5* de uma string", não é um algo. de criptografia, embora muito usado para "criptografar" senhas. O máximo que faz é gerar um hash de comparação. A propósito, qual motivo de reverter a senha do usuário? Se ele esqueceu, basta criar uma nova.

Comment: Imagina que algum erro ocorra e escape dados dos usuários, ou forneça acesso ao DB, qualquer um com a 'pseudo-senha-criptografada' poderia revertê-la. O que não seria nada bom.

Comment: Relacionado: ["Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215). Resumidamente, você não "descriptografa" MD5 - já que essa é uma função de ***hashing***, não **cifragem** (como o AES ou similar). Para verificar se um dado novo é igual a um dado previamente hasheado, você faz o hash do dado novamente e compara com o hash armazenado (dados iguais geram hashes iguais). Mas como a pergunta linkada mostra, não se deve usar MD5 para fazer a segurança de senhas.

Comment: MD5 não é criptografia. É hash. Não sendo criptografia, não há como descriptografar. Se você pegar 1TB de dados ou um único byte e gerar o MD5 de ambos, obterá um hash do mesmo tamanho. Se fosse possível "descriptografar" o hash e obter o 1TB de volta, você teria o melhor compactador de dados do Universo! rs... O que existe são dicionários de hash, que guardam dados que foram processados e assim, conseguem obter a informação original a partir do hash.

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que deve aceitar alguma?

Comment: Olá, nesse site você consegue descriptografar md5: http://www.md5online.org/

Comment: Teorema do buraco do pombo: se 9 pombos entrarem em 8 casinhas, pelo menos 2 pombos vão ter de compartilhar uma casinha. Como MD5 tem apenas 128 bits, há inúmeras senhas que geram o mesmo MD5. Claro, como é um hash de alta qualidade, uma colisão acidental é improvável. O que o pessoal tenta, para descobrir senhas comumente utilizadas, são as "rainbow tables. Às vezes procurar pelo MD5 no Google resulta na string original (ou melhor, na string original mais provável, porque como dito, há infinitas strings que geram um mesmo hash)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Isso não é possível.

A string MD5 não tem a informação que foi encriptada no seu conteúdo. Ele é uma representação única da string original mas no seu conteúdo não tem uma versão encriptada do conteúdo original.

MD5 é referida como uma função unidirecional, ou seja uma vez encriptado não tem como desencriptar.

Para perceber melhor pode dizer-se que o que é guardado na base de dados não é a password mas sim a representação MD5 da mesma. Quando inserir a password novamente a MD5 vai gerar a mesma string e vai funcionar, mas a password é perdida/trocada pela nova string encriptada em MD5.

Uma string MD5 tem 128 bits, independentemente do tamanho do conteúdo original. Isso quer dizer que existem 2<sup>128</sup> hashes possiveis.

<sub>Pode dar uma olhada aqui a uma [boa pergunta e respostas em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1240852/2256325) no SOen</sub>

Comment: Só pra complementar, o único jeito é "quebrar" a MD5, ou seja, usar algum método de força bruta. Existe esse site aqui: http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx onde eles usam um banco de dados com hashes conhecidos para decodificar o MD5.

Comment: Você não pode simplesmente assumir que não é possível "quebrar" o MD5, pois através do "método da biblioteca de conhecimento anterior" como disse o @g.carvalho97 é possível quebrar **vários** hashes (porém não todos).

Comment: @PauloRoberto não é possivel descriptar um hash pois exitem várias strings que podem dar o mesmo hash. Improvável mas possivel. Daí a minha resposta. Não dá para descriptar pois o conteudo não está lá. Pode ser possivel fazer um match, mas como disse pode ser a string errada visto existe um numero limitado de hashes e as strings possiveis são ilimitadas.

Comment: @Sergio por isso que eu disse **(porém não todos)** mas concordas comigo que muitos podem ser quebrados? **principalmente os mais utilizados** como 12345, ou 2468 ou pass, senha, pasw, dentre outros

Comment: @PauloRoberto sim, não esquecendo que se encontrar-mos uma string que gera uma hash que estamos a tentar quebrar pode haver mais representações para a mesma hash.

Comment: @Sergio desculpe por reviver a discussão mas, estava aqui pensando ao rever estes comentários, e queria perguntar uma coisa. Você disse que "existem várias strings que podem dar o mesmo hash." Bom mas se eu encontrar apenas uma destas strings seria o suficiente não seria? afinal o que a aplicação vai validar é se o hash === hash no banco de dados então mesmo que haja outros hashes todos eles vão dar true e vai logar, a minha teoria continua sendo a mesma.. não seria?

Comment: Na verdade a sra. Wang já quebrou o MD5, e tem um [app para fazer isso](http://www.insecuritynet.com.br/materias/decodifique-hash-md5) aqui [tem outro exemplo](https://agiletesters.com.br/topic/353/descobrindo-senhas-md5-e-sha1-em-menos-de-10-minutos)

Comment: Além disso, há colisão no md5: https://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Answer (score 36):

## O que é MD5?

MD5 é uma técnica para gerar um código um [*hash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). É um código que procura buscar uma representação única de uma informação (não há garantias que não tenha colisões - mesmo código para duas informações diferentes). Não é feito para criptografar informações. Isto já deve ter ficado claro de acordo com o que já foi dito aqui em comentários e respostas. Isto é usado para criar uma dificuldade de acesso ao dado.

[O problema do MD5 é que é possível quebrar a segurança dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101). Não é algo simples de fazer mas [é possível](https://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/). Se deseja realmente fazer isto, é bom se preparar não só para estudar muito o assunto mas também ter disposição para conseguir o que quer. Quebrar a segurança não é o mesmo que descobrir seu conteúdo original.

## MD5 para proteger senhas

Não existe nenhum motivo para reverter uma codificação da senha a não ser para fazer algo ilegal. Se você está querendo quebrar uma senha que você pode (mesmo em sistemas seus, em todos os sentidos) quebrar uma senha pode ser ilegal. Se perdeu a senha, crie outra, não tente descobrir qual era a senha.

Se deseja apenas comparar para saber se a senha enviada ao sistema é válida então você deve aplicar o *hash* MD5 nela e comparar os dois *hashes*. De qualquer forma usar simplesmente MD5 puro não é boa prática (leia o *link* acima).

## Criptografia reversível

Se você precisa criptografar alguma coisa que dependa de reversão, de descriptografia, por algum motivo, você deve usar um algoritmo que permita isto ([criptografia simétrica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)). Evidentemente que um algoritmo assim tem suas deficiências em termos de segurança. Algoritmos reversíveis tem a base da segurança pelo ocultamento da chave de criptografia. Se alguém tiver a chave, a criptografia está comprometida. Aí o problema passar ser proteger bem a chave. Mas até onde eu sei ninguém conseguiu uma forma melhor de resolver este problema.

Nos casos em que isto é importante é comum usar chaves que se complementam para realizar a operação. Isto é usado em criptografia para codificação de conteúdo e comunicação como usado no SSL, criptografia de arquivos e canais de TV por assinatura ([criptografia assimétrica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)).

Em alguns casos a chave pode mudar com frequência tornando a sua descoberta e utilização mais difícil. Quando alguém descobre a chave ela já não é mais usada. Evidentemente isto é mais útil em conteúdos instáveis (transmissão de TV por exemplo). É possível aplicar para um arquivo em disco mas dá trabalho fazer isto de forma minimamente segura.

## Conclusão

Quebrar segurança costuma usar várias técnicas em conjunto. E a mais usada é a [engenharia social](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)), é usar o [171](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/171/) ([origem](https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/topicos/10617301/artigo-171-do-decreto-lei-n-2848-de-07-de-dezembro-de-1940) do termo popular) para obter o que você quer. Humanos são bem mais fáceis de driblar que equipamentos, que a matemática.

[Tente usar isto](https://md5decrypter.com/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 18):

O MD5, falando numa linguagem popular, é um *hash* de via única.

Não há informação para reverter o *hash* para o valor original.

Há alguns anos, diversos websites oferecem soluções para "reverter" o *hash* e isso causa uma certa confusão pois quem não entende do assunto acaba por acreditar que o MD5 é reversível. O que esses sites oferecem é o chamado *rainbow table*. A técnica consiste na mesma lógica de um "*brute force*".

As *rainbow tables* são apenas base de dados contendo strings e seus respectivos valores em MD5.

Esse esquema funciona somente para hashes sem "salto".

A lógica é simples. Um script gera automaticamente, num "loop infinito", todos os tipos de combinações de caracteres possível. Dentro desse laço de repetição, é também gerado o hash MD5 dessa combinação e salvo num banco de dados, o qual possui um pseudônimo conhecido como "rainbow table".

Atualmente, diversos sites garantem possuir combinações de 5 caracteres completos e quase completando 6 caracteres.

Para entender melhor, veja um exemplo da lógica envolvida:

**Combinações de caracteres de tamanho 1 e seu respectivo MD5**

```
 a -> 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
 b -> 92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
 c -> 4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33
```

E assim vai seguindo até gerar o MD5 de todo tipo de caracter, inclusive números e caracteres multibyte

```
あ -> 8c0c3027e3cfc3d644caab3847a505b0
い -> 655dcb0e6519c34baf6d9d53e1932389
う -> 31e55ff7f86aaee740277059a9983d89
□ -> 8c8586b6fb99a8815eeec4ea97e6222d
```

Parece fácil gerar os hashes, porém, é preciso criar as combinações.
Aqui temos um exemplo de tamanho 2:

```
ab -> 187ef4436122d1cc2f40dc2b92f0eba0
ac -> e2075474294983e013ee4dd2201c7a73
ba -> 07159c47ee1b19ae4fb9c40d480856c4
bc -> 5360af35bde9ebd8f01f492dc059593c
ca -> 5435c69ed3bcc5b2e4d580e393e373d3
cb -> d0d7fdb6977b26929fb68c6083c0b439
```

Até aqui parece fácil, mas imagine 5 combinações. Quantas combinações possíveis existem em 5 casas?

```
abcde -> ab56b4d92b40713acc5af89985d4b786
acbde -> e0e56a95aff0ee48fc44e8a4faf69adb
adbce -> a44a7eb2135809f67ce273e0de8b52cb
```

Mesmo com tamanho 5, não parece difícil se lidarmos apenas com alfabeto romano e números, mas lembre-se que também deve-se incluir caracteres especiais/multibyte. Nesse ponto as combinações passam de trilhões de registros.

**Como que esses sites retornam o valor de um hash?**

Apenas consultando no banco dados.

```
select original from rainbowtable where hash = 'ab56b4d92b40713acc5af89985d4b786'
```

Isso retornaria "abcde", se estiver já previamente salvo no banco de dados.

Por isso, recomenda-se evitar senhas curtas, menores que 6 caracteres e também senhas contendo caracteres simples.

Exemplo de senha simples, onde, obviamente, sites de rainbow tables já possui seus hashes:

```
abc
111
123
abc123
senha
passord
user
admin
123456
111111
```

Quando criar uma senha, procure fazer, no mínimo, algo assim:

```
j&SCjV:Kd#A!6VN7x=eY
```

Misture caracteres especiais, letras maiúscula e minúscula, números. Por fim, quanto maior e mais complexo, menor a possibilidade de existir numa *rainbow table* ou ser quebrada por *brute force*.

**Recuperação de senha**

> deveria ser possível recuperar esse MD5 no banco e mostrar "senha" de
>   volta num formulário de atualização de informações, não?

Um website que retorna a senha original para o usuário, é inseguro. Quando encontrar um site que faz isso, evite usá-lo caso possua informações importantes, principalmente transações financeiras.

Um website que consegue enxergar a senha digitada pelo usuário, fere normas de privacidade e segurança básica pois mesmo um administrador do servidor de hospedagem ou o programador do site podem ser maliciosos e obter as senhas dos usuários.

Um agravante nisso é que a maioria dos usuários usam uma mesma senha para tudo. Serviços de email, contas de redes sociais, até senha de cartão de crédito.

Ou seja, se conseguir a senha, terá o passaporte para quase todas ou todas as contas que esse usuário possui em serviços terceiros.

A mesma senha 1234, que é usada no facebook, também usa no cartão de crédito, no cartão de débito, email e diversos serviços. Infelizmente o usuário abre mão da própria segurança pela "praticidade".

(O termo *facebook é mero exemplo. Obviamente o facebook não permite uma senha dessas)

Nesse ponto vem a responsabilidade dos prestadores de serviços em obrigar o usuário a criar senhas complexas. A complexidade depende do modelo de negócios do serviço.

**Observação final**, também existe raibow tables de outros hashes como o sha1, des, crypt16, dentre outros.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Complemento com um site que realiza conversões simples: https://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=4012dd35d6cbfb0f33faa6981db70f88

Answer (score 2):

Quando você criptografa uma senha e grava no banco de dados não é necessário descriptografar para saber se está correta.
Você deve criptografar a que foi informada no momento da autenticação e comparar com a que foi gravada na base de dados.

```
select * 
from user 
where usuario = usuario_informado 
and senha = md5(senha_informada)
```