# Não deixar usuário ter acesso a dados de um script

Tags: python, script, proteção

Possuo um script foi gerado em `python` e chama funções em `R`.

A principio  foi desenvolvido para uso interno, mas agora estão pensando em liberar para uso dos clientes. Porem não querem que os usuários tenham acesso aos calculos utilizados.

Gostaria de que o usuário não tivesse acesso aos dados.

O Script é utilizado dentro da plataforma `QGIS`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como descriptografar MD5?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41517/como-descriptografar-md5)

Comment: Criptografar o que? Senhas? Dados em trânsito? Dados em repouso? Se você especificar melhor qual é seu objetivo, provavelmente poderemos te ajudar mais.

Comment: refiz a pergunta. acho que ficou mais claro.

Comment: Complicado... o que você está buscando é basicamente uma forma de [DRM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gest%C3%A3o_de_direitos_digitais), e até onde eu saiba não é possível de se fazer [garantidamente]. Dá uma olhada na minha resposta à pergunta ["Como proteger o código fonte?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/215). Se a máquina do cliente precisa fazer operações com esses dados, então: a) não dá pra esconder o algoritmo; b) não dá pra esconder os dados, a menos que se use **criptografia homomórfica** - algo teórico, que já foi provado possível mas que não está disponível para uso prático.

Comment: @Guilherme Lima, de uma olhada nessa ferramenta, talvez seja útil pra esse caso: http://www.moernaut.com/default.aspx?item=supercrypt
Já usei ela mas com vbs.

Comment: bacana, porem ele não é um executavel

Comment: @GuilhermeLima você gera o arquivo lsc com o software e usa o executável para chamar o lsc dessa forma: `supercrypt /lscfile:"c:\google.lsc"`
Você não consegue chamar uma linha de comando como essa no ambiente em que ele está executando?

Comment: Boa tarde Guilherme, você não quer que ele acesso os **dados** ou você não quer que ele acesse o conteudo do script como por exemplo o algorítimo que você usou pra fazer o calculo?

Comment: Boa tarde xará, exatamente isso.

Comment: Não entedi kkk! Desculpe é que eu perguntei `A ou B? ` e você disse é `exatamente isso`. Mas eu não sei se é o dados ou o algorítimo que você quer proteger, eu espera uma resposta tipo `é o A` ou `o B`

Comment: Gostaria que ele não visse o algorítimo usado.

Comment: É uma pergunta legal, só acho que precisa melhorar um pouco o texto, de qualquer maneira +1

Comment: @GuilhermeLima o SuperCrypt que citei acima faz exatamente o que você está pedindo. Você não fornece o script, mas sim o arquivo.lsc que será chamado por pelo executável que vem junto com a ferramenta.
Você tentou usa-lo?

Comment: Sim, porem o meu script está sendo usado em uma outra plataforma "Qgis", esse é o problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima entendi, infelizmente não sei nada sobre Qgis. A unica possibilidade é rodar o arquivo .py? O script é chamado pelo Qgis? Ou o script que faz as chamadas ao software?

Comment: Somente pelo Qgis, por que o mesmo realiza ações que necessitam do Qgis

Comment: @GuilhermeLima essa pergunta é parecida com o que você precisa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code
Mas infelizmente não há uma forma de proteger. A solução seria verificar no QGis se realmente não há uma outra forma de chamar o script, ou se ao invés do script se não tem como chamar um executável.
Nesse caso não sei como devo fazer. Se coloco isso como resposta traduzindo ou se apenas coloco o link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python, é uma linguagem interpretada, sendo assim , é muito difícil de bloquear o acesso ao código fonte. Mesmo se você usar um Conversor `exe` como [py2exe](http://py2exe.org/), o layout do executável é conhecido, pois fica apenas compactado em um zip.

Normalmente, em casos como este, você tem que fazer uma escolha. Quão importante é proteger o código? Existem verdadeiros segredos lá (como uma chave para a criptografia simétrica das transferências bancárias), ou você está apenas sendo  paranóico? Escolha a linguagem que lhe permite desenvolver o melhor produto mais rápido e seja realista sobre o quão importante são as suas ideias inovadoras.

Se você decidir que você realmente precisa proteger o script, escreva-o como uma pequena extensão `C`, no entanto não sei se isso se aplicaria para a plataforma `QGis`. Se fosse possível por ele chamar um executável você já teria considerado a primeira sugestão que deixei nos comentários referente ao `SuperCrypt`, ou até mesmo de usar uma linguagem compilada.

> Traduzido e adaptado de [outra questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code) do SO inglês.