# Usar MD5 é a maneira mais segura de se criptografar senhas no PHP?

Tags: php, criptografia, md5, base64, sha1

Eu sei que existe vários métodos de criptografar senhas no PHP (md5, sha1, base64...) apesar de eu não conhecer muito sobre, o que eu mais vejo é o uso do MD5.

Usar MD5 para criptografar senhas é a maneira mais segura? Se não, qual usar?

Comment: Não é, dê uma olhada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2405/21328.

Comment: é muito complicado falar em "a mais segura" isso não existe. Procure sempre usar senhas no formato Hash (criptografia não reversivel) uma boa tecnica é chamada de "hash-sal" que consiste em "salgar um hash" ou seja, além da senha adicionar outras informações que somente o programador sabe, por ex. ao gravar a senha no banco, adicionar outros dados como tamanho do email, da senha, etc.. senha = senha + email + tamanhoDaSenha, dessa forma é mais dificil um ataque por força bruta.. força bruta (tentativa e erro) é a única forma de quebrar uma senha no formato hash.

Comment: @AlexandrePreviatti Na verdade, "adicionar outras informações que somente o programador sabe" é chamado de "pimenta", e não de "sal" (i.e. é um tipo de chave, mas de importância não tão crítica). Um sal só precisa ser único, ele não precisa sequer ser secreto. O ideal é que seja aleatório (mas sua sugestão de usar o email não é de todo ruim - exceto que se o usuário trocar sua senha, depois trocar de volta pra senha anterior, o resultado do hash será o mesmo, e isso não é bom).

Comment: Olá Vinícius. base64 não é criptografia. Apesar do uso desse algoritmo tornar qualquer texto ilegível para uma pessoa, a transformação do base64 é simples e não requer uma chave, por isso a informação não é escondida de fato.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Existe uma solução muito segura e nativa do PHP que é a API de senha (*password* API). Ela está disposta desde a versão 5.5 nativamente, mas pode ser utilizada a partir da versão 5.3 com uma *lib* disponível no Github, chamada [*Password Compat*](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

As vantagens de se utilizar tal API é que ela é simples e extremamente segura. Veja o exemplo da saída para `teste` com os mecanismos de *hash* mais utilizados (md5 e sha...):

**MD5**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    md5('teste');
}

/* Iterações
    1 - 698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
    2 - 698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
    3 - 698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
    4 - 698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
    5 - 698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b

    Resultado: Sempre a mesma string
*/
```

**SHA1**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    sha1('teste');
}

/* Iterações
    1 - 2e6f9b0d5885b6010f9167787445617f553a735f
    2 - 2e6f9b0d5885b6010f9167787445617f553a735f
    3 - 2e6f9b0d5885b6010f9167787445617f553a735f
    4 - 2e6f9b0d5885b6010f9167787445617f553a735f
    5 - 2e6f9b0d5885b6010f9167787445617f553a735f

    Resultado: Sempre a mesma string
*/
```

**SHA256**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    hash('sha256', 'teste');
}

/* Iterações
    1 - 46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5
    2 - 46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5
    3 - 46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5
    4 - 46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5
    5 - 46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5

    Resultado: Uma string complexa e grande mas ainda assim sempre a mesma string
*/
```

**PASSWORD API**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    password_hash('teste', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}

/* Iterações
    1 - $2y$10$zRlWkrqyTlEBsCVVf9KOvu3ADTEjOV.TiPHDu8efmgaPCQ75c2V7K
    2 - $2y$10$BydsqC30UGc3QmvalCFTt.pm22fg22195cav.lZOnfSNY9wL5ZcJe
    3 - $2y$10$XHpaG8blIsZCTNPXEubiz.2EyyyZktvydLDu1HtieBkpohN9vswQS
    4 - $2y$10$vNJabya/sj9MZd.DaEwtXuVwqpIwEOcBPN38gOh2gr2wanPwsQVSu
    5 - $2y$10$z3PB5TQHXgml3J0iDMhI8.HrM19Ce77YcI5sYfQQFU3a94.XBzQO.

    Resultado: a cada iteração uma nova hash gerada
*/
```

Para a validação é utilizado o `password_verify` passando como primeiro parâmetro a senha fornecida pelo usuário e como segundo o *hash* que encontra-se no banco de dados.

```
$hash1 = '$2y$10$zRlWkrqyTlEBsCVVf9KOvu3ADTEjOV.TiPHDu8efmgaPCQ75c2V7K';
var_dump(password_verify('teste', $hash1));
//true

$hash2 = '$2y$10$BydsqC30UGc3QmvalCFTt.pm22fg22195cav.lZOnfSNY9wL5ZcJe';
var_dump(password_verify('teste', $hash2));
//true

$hash3 = '$2y$10$XHpaG8blIsZCTNPXEubiz.2EyyyZktvydLDu1HtieBkpohN9vswQS';
var_dump(password_verify('teste', $hash3));
//true

$hash4 = '$2y$10$vNJabya/sj9MZd.DaEwtXuVwqpIwEOcBPN38gOh2gr2wanPwsQVSu';
var_dump(password_verify('teste', $hash4));
//true

$hash5 = '$2y$10$z3PB5TQHXgml3J0iDMhI8.HrM19Ce77YcI5sYfQQFU3a94.XBzQO.';
var_dump(password_verify('teste', $hash5));
//true

$hashDesconhecida = '$2y$10$z3PB5TQHXgml3J0iDMhI8.HrM19Ce77YcI5sYfQQFU3a94.X99999';
var_dump(password_verify('teste', $hashDesconhecida));
//false
```

Existem outras formas de aplicar *hash* em senhas, é claro. Muitos *frameworks* possuem seus próprios mecanismos, uns bastante seguros, outros um tanto menos mas comparado aos métodos aqui apresentados (md5, sha1, hash com sha256 e *password* API) a *password* API leva a melhor sem sombra de dúvidas.

Caso queiram verificar tais exemplos que passei: https://3v4l.org/mdFil

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema quanto a isso. Agora como posso adicionar a tal "salgada" sem problemas no password_hash(), lembrando que no PHP 7.0.3 eles falam algo sobre ter proibido algo na função

Comment: Você pode utilizar salt de duas formas: 

1) um salt único para a aplicação - deve ser armazenado em um arquivo de configurações por exemplo; 

2) um salt único por usuário - deve ser armazenado no banco de dados por usuário

Comment: Testei agora e verifiquei o seguinte: mesmo utilizando um salt, para comparar a senha (password_verify), basta fornecer somente a string fornecida pelo usuário e a hash no banco de dados, o salt não se faz necessário na varificação, somente na criação mesmo.

Comment: Em código como é o salt? Desculpa pergunta, mas é pra ter certeza que não estou fazendo de modo errado

Comment: @Vinicius, olha este exemplo: https://3v4l.org/flgN3. Lembrando apenas que se for utilizar a versão 7 do PHP o salt já é deprecated.

Comment: @Vinicius a password API já usa um sal, você não precisa acrescentar um você mesmo (a propósito, o hash padrão dessa API é o bcrypt, que é considerado bastante seguro pra hasehar senhas). Andre, usar "um salt único para a aplicação" é inútil, a função do sal é ser único para cada usuário *e para cada senha* (i.e. se o usuário mudou a senha, o sal tem que mudar também). Mas como nas versões recentes a própria API já faz isso pra você, tanto faz... E na hora de verificar, de fato não é necessário passar o sal de novo, porque a saída do hash já inclui o sal.

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Answer (score 10):

O MD5 é seguro, porém é exagerado dizer que é o melhor. Portanto, respondendo de forma direta, não é o melhor. Mas não significa que não pode usar e que deve mudar tudo onde estiver usando MD5.

Provavelmente encontrará recomendações para evitar o uso como se fosse algo extremamente inseguro e fácil de burlar. Mas o que acontece é um alarde desnecessário.

**Desafio! Vamos provar na prática que MD5 é fácil de quebrar?**

Vejamos aqui, um desafio para os que afirmam que MD5 é inseguro e fácil de descobrir uma combinação.

Temos essa string **MD5**: `bc99449990cd1dedd0b3af807f862fbe`

Tente decifrar. É válido também se conseguir encontrar uma colisão. Já que é tão fácil "quebrar o hash", então deve ser um desafio fácil. rsrs

Esse é o hash da mesma string em **sha1**:

```
6cc0d1e3259b4a7df3b3609207842a08332357b4
```

Aqui o mesmo em **sha256**:

```
562e5a05b801149cb70092fd1335bb6f40320b44bd7873fb7c05ee1e05f5a606
```

Dentre os 3 acima, obviamente o sha256 é mais seguro. Se puder usar sha256, use-o ao invés de MD5.

**O problema é o hash ou a senha?**

Note que uma senha fraca do tipo *12345* é tão insegura em MD5 quanto em quaisquer outros hashes. Não há vantagem alguma usar um hash moderno e recomendado se o sistema permite senhas fracas.

Para decifrar uma hash são usadas técnicas de brute force. Os programas de brute force possuem 2 tabelas. Uma tabela é onde contém palavras óbvias usadas em senhas como "root", "123", "senha", "pass", "admin", etc.

A segunda tabela é chamada de "[rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)".

A lógica consiste em checar se o hash existe nas tabelas e retornar a respectiva string que gerou aquele hash. Simples assim. Todos os hashes conhecidos são vulneráveis. O que vai diferenciar o nível de segurança é o tamanho do hash, uso de salt, complexidade da string original e colisões.

O MD5 possui "apenas" 32 caracteres. Isso implica num número maior de colisões. E é aí onde mora o maior problema do MD5.

**O que são as a colisões?**

Exemplo, vamos supor que `1234` gere o hash **dfji34iudhfkjfdbn**.

A colisão se dá quando uma outra combinação de strings gera o mesmo hash de outra combinação. Suponha que `5%sdi¨¨4dd89 $$Fi9w孤nrrピfe0e90にnf+nbs` gere o mesmo hash **dfji34iudhfkjfdbn**. Pronto! Temos uma colisão!
Mesmo que não tenha descoberto a string original `1234`, acabou passando na autenticação porque encontrou uma colisão.

*(importante: o hash acima é meramente ilustrativo, com finaldiade didática)*

Também há o fato de que MD5 é gerado mais rapidamente, o que torna "menos difícil" para gerar combinações. Perceba que preferi dizer "menos difícil" do que usar "mais fácil", porque, fácil não é.

Note que combinações de todos os caracteres existentes podem levar anos, décadas ou séculos, dependendo dos computadores que utiliza pois necessita de muito poder de processamento de dados.

Consulte essa resposta antiga como complemento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96652/4793

**Força bruta**

Ok, agora vamos avaliar o ambiente. Para descobrir uma combinação para um determinado hash precisa ter acesso direto aos dados pois o método consiste em brute force, ou seja, tentativas de força bruta.

Um website, por exemplo, não deve permitir múltiplas tentativas de login em menos de 1 segundo, por exemplo. Quando detectar algo assim, o sistema deve bloquear o login. Portanto, via web, submetendo dados por GET, POST, é inviável um hacker aplicar brute force. A menos que o site seja muito ruim e permita tal ação. Nesse ponto não é culpa do hash usado e sim de quem fez o sistema. Além do mais há também o custo do tempo de requisição e resposta, tornando as execuções mais lentas. Portanto, no ambiente web é simplesmente inviável.

Outro ponto é que normalmente deve ter uma combinação de nome de usuário e  senha. Mesmo que consiga descobrir uma combinação de um hash ainda tem que combinar com o nome de usuário.

```
if ( user == 'foo' && pass == MD5('senha') )
```

Por isso, é exagero o alarde que fazem a respeito da suposta falta de segurança no uso de MD5 pois **depende do contexto**, do **ambiente**, da **situação**, da **circunstância**, etc.

**Hacker tem acesso direto ao banco de dados e ao sistema**

Vamos supor que o hacker conseguiu acesso direto ao banco de dados e ao sistema. Ok, agora ele pode usar *brute force* para decodificar uma senha. Ok, mas pense um pouco. Por quê o invasor vai querer saber da senha se ele já está dentro do sistema? Qual o intuito? Se normalmente quer roubar algo, o sujeito não vai ficar perdendo tempo brincando com senha. Ele vai direto onde interessa. Nesse ponto, com acesso direto aos dados, as senhas e o sistema de autentição são inúteis. E mesmo que ainda assim precise de uma senha para , por exemplo acessar um sistema onde ele não conseguiu invadir, ele pode modificar o email de uma conta para um email no qual ele tenha acesso e assim requisitar a troca da senha. Bingo!

**Então, onde o uso do MD5 ou um hash "fraco" deve realmente ser evitado?**

Um hash considerado vulnerável deve ser evitado em casos como uma assinatura digital, uma chave pública, dentre outros. Dados que ficam expostos publicamente. Pois nesses casos, o hacker não tem trabalho algum em ter que invadir sistema. Basta pegar o hash e buscar combinações. O SSL utiliza chaves públicas e privadas, por exemplo, pois precisa de uma identificação pública para autenticar com a chave privada.

Por isso, é exagero e sem sentido preocupar-se com senhas de um website, dentro desse contexto que estamos abordando. A menos que as senhas tenham uma finalidade de uso específico que não seja somente autenticar para ter acesso a dados nesse site. Por exemplo, se a senha provê a chave de acesso a um sistema terceiro.

Comment: Você começa a resposta dizendo que MD5 é seguro, contudo isso vai na contramão de uma porrada de respostas do SO en http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713810/how-secure-is-md5-and-sha1.

Comment: Sim, o texto começa com essa frase seguida de 66 linhas de textos explicando em detalhes todo o contexto que é formado por 5518 letras. Conseguiu ao menos ler metade? Aliás, todos esses links do SO que postou falam o mesmo que postei aqui. O problema das colisões.

Comment: Você também diz que "não é fácil gerar combinações" "precisa de muito poder de processamento", contudo geração de hashes por GPU é absurdamente rapido, por exemplo [aqui](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/387852/md5-hash-on-a-gpu-implementation-and-benchmarks/) tem uma discussão sobre o uso delas para gerar 110 milhões de hashes por segundo.

Comment: Se vc não reparou, deixei aí acima um desafio. Prove para mim que consegue a combinação do hash que coloquei no texto. Aliás, esse nem é  a parte relevante pois há um contexto maior que é o uso para website. Apenas leia o texto inteiro. Não interprete trechos isolados. Tudo faz parte do contexto das 66 linhas de texto. Enfim, está tudo explicado acima. Não vou explicar novamente nos comentários.

Comment: @BrunoRB, apenas leia a resposta com atenção e poderá entender que não faz sentido o que está comentando. Não estou induzindo ninguém a nada, aliás recomendei uso de um hash melhor. Num outro comentário vc diz `vamos ignorar que a maioria da população usa a mesma senha em 100 sites diferentes`. Se tivesse lido com atenção perceberia que a resposta também fala sobre isso, mas está em forma resumida apontando para um link numa outra pergunta onde respondi sobre o assunto. Não há problema no texto que escrevi. O problema que vejo é que está forçando a barra levando a uma interpretação pejorativa.

Comment: Eu não dei -1, mas o raciocínio sobre quando o hacker tem acesso direto ao sistema está totalmente errado. Quando se fala em segurança, sempre tem que se considerar o elo mais fraco. Por exemplo, eu sei que muitos dos funcionários de um banco tem cadastro num app tosco do facebook. Se eu hackear aquele sistema e recuperar, digamos, umas 5 senhas, há grande chance de pelo menos uma delas ser a senha que a pessoa usa também em outras contas e posso seguir assim e chegar até a uma senha válido do banco.

Comment: Além disso, senhas de até uns 8 caracteres com MD5 cru aplicado são viáveis de quebrar por força bruta [como exemplificado aqui](http://blog.codinghorror.com/speed-hashing/). Nesse caso, o problema não é da senha.

Comment: A vulnerabilidade do MD5 a colisões é irrelevante no contexto do hash de senhas (seria relevante se usado diretamente num esquema de assinatura digital, por exemplo). A propriedade que importa nesse cenário é a resistência à pré-imagem, e nisso o MD5 ainda não foi quebrado. O maior problema do MD5 não é sua saída pequena, mas sim o fato dele ser **rápido** - eu não sei se é ou não viável quebrar esse seu "desafio", não vou pagar pra ver. Mas se ele for quebrável, é *muito* mais fácil quebrá-lo se ele estiver hasehado em MD5 do que em um hash lento.

Comment: Outra coisa, sobre o hacker ter acesso ao sistema, uma coisa é ele ter acesso passivo (digamos, usou um SQL Injection pra dumpar o conteúdo inteiro do banco, mas não tem como invadir o servidor de fato) e outra acesso ativo. O hash protege contra o primeiro cenário, essa é a sua principal razão de existir (caso contrário, hasehar pra que, guarda em texto plano mesmo...). Uma função secundária é proteger *a senha em si* - pois como na prática muitos usuários reusam senhas (e desse crime eu próprio sou culpado), um ataque a um servidor fraco poderia acabar comprometendo um servidor mais forte.

Comment: @migsonbr, se  você lesse com atenção a resposta não teria postado tais comentários pois na reposta eu menciono o mesmo.

Comment: agora que li o comentario do utluiz também...  parece que o pessoal não lê direito...

Comment: @DanielOmine Claro que eu li sua resposta, se não tivesse lido teria te negativado pela primeira frase rsrs (ainda tá tem tempo!). E não, nem você e nem ninguém nessa pergunta parecem perceber que colisões são irrelevantes no hash de senhas (mesmo com uma saída de "só" 32 bytes). Que eu saiba, colisões "acidentais" (i.e. não feitas deliberadamente) de MD5 ainda não foram observadas na prática. Quanto ao segundo comentário, em que momento você menciona isso? Eu o coloquei como complemento, não crítica, pois o que você fala sobre "hacker com acesso direto ao sistema" está correto mas incompleto.

Answer (score 9):

A resposta é simplesmente **não**, MD5 não é o mais seguro e nem ficou perto dos primeiros colocados. :)

## Hash != segurança

A primeira coisa que precisa ser desmistificada é que algoritmos de criptografia ou de geração de hashes não são sinônimos segurança, que é algo muito mais abrangente.

Por exemplo, não adianta nada toda a segurança no servidor se o a comunicação com o cliente ocorre enviando senhas na URL ou mesmo se não há uso de HTTPS. Da mesma forma, não adianta nada esconder bem a senha e deixar os números de cartão de crédito armazenados em texto puro.

## Riscos do MD5

É realmente difícil dizer que o MD5 é *absolutamente seguro ou inseguro*. Mas se comparado aos outros algoritmos, ele é um dos **menos seguros** simplesmente por ser mais rápido de calcular e assim facilitando um pouco o trabalho de adivinhar a senha por força bruta.

Um [artigo sobre velocidade de hashing](http://blog.codinghorror.com/speed-hashing/), de 2012, contém um calculo da velocidade para fazer o hash MD5 de todas as combinações de senhas usando letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, números e símbolos. Parte do resultado foi:

- 6 caracteres: 47 segundos
- 7 caracteres: 1 hora e 14 minutes
- 8 caracteres: aproximadamente 465 dias

Considere que o hardware está ultrapassado e que existem muitas possibilidades de paralelizar ou simplificar esse trabalho. Alguém com muita vontade, disposto a investir um pouco de tempo e dinheiro, poderia facilmente diminuir esses 465 dias para poucos dias ou até mesmo horas.

Tenha em mente ainda que o tempo acima é o tempo **total**, então, a não ser que sua senha seja uma sequência de letras "z", provavelmente ela vai ser encontrada antes. Além disso, técnicas simples como deixar os caracteres especiais para depois podem acelerar ainda mais. [Neste site](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/beyond-password-length-complexity/) apenas 17% dos usuários usavam símbolos.

Temos que concordar que senhas de 8 caracteres não podem ser culpadas de serem inseguras. Neste caso, o algoritmo é. E isso vai colocar a maioria dos seus clientes em risco. Estatísticas coletadas por [alguns](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/beyond-password-length-complexity/) [sites](http://www.codelord.net/2011/06/18/statistics-of-62k-passwords/) mostram que a maioria das senhas tem 8 dígitos ou menos.

Em cima disso, muitas das implementações de MD5 usam apenas oa lgoritmo "cru", isto é, não usam nenhum tipo de "sal", o que deixa em aberto o uso de dicionários de hashes que já possuem as senhas mais comuns.

## Além do MD5

Voltando ao assunto, pode ser que MD5 seja *suficientemente* seguro e livre de colisões para um caso simples que você tem hoje. Porém, algoritmos de hash simples geralmente não são adequados para senhas e não existe uma razão para que você não use algo melhor.

Existem soluções específicas para gerar hashes de senhas como [`bcrypt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) e [`PBKDF2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) que possibilitam você ajustar o nível de segurança que deseja. Eles são iterativos, isto é, aplicam várias iterações de encriptação de acordo com o nível desejado.

## Tempere a senha

A vantagem dos algoritmos citados acima é que eles reforçam o uso do [*salt* (sal)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_(criptografia)), que é muito importante para diminuir o impacto de ataques.

O sal deve ser um valor único por senha que faz com que cada uma delas seja gerada de um jeito único.

Isso diminui muito a eficiência de ataques de força bruta no sentido de que mesmo senhas iguais terão um valor de hash diferente.

## Não reinvente a roda, o PHP já está redondo

O PHP (a partir do `5.5`) possui a função [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) que usa o algoritmo `bcrypt` para codificar as senhas de forma segura.

O seguinte código, extraído da documentação, ilustra como você pode usar a função:

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n";
```

Note que a função já cria um sal criptograficamente seguro. Não se esqueça que esse valor é incluído  juntamente com o hash para possibilitar a verificação da senha posteriormente através da função `password_verify`.

## Deixa de preguiça, menino

Em resumo, com uma função já implementando o que é recomendado para fazer hash de senhas, não existe uma razão hoje para continuar usando algo potencialmente mais inseguro.

Comment: Boa resposta, só tenho duas observações: 1) senhas de 8 caracteres [ASCII] só comportam 56 bits de entropia, provavelmente muito menos, mas nunca mais. 12 é o mínimo aceitável, e quanto maior melhor (o fato de muita gente usar < 8 não é desculpa); 2) pelo que li da documentação não é necessário passar essas opções `cost` e `salt` pro `password_hash`, pois os valores que ele usa por padrão já são bons o bastante (e se a pessoa não souber o que está fazendo, vai acabar passando parâmetros piores). E o sal já faz parte da saída do hash, não é preciso nesse caso armazená-lo separadamente.

Comment: @mgibsonbr muito obrigado pelas observações. Corrigido!

Answer (score 3):

Jamais use *hash* MD5 puro para encriptar senhas e salvá-las em banco de dados. Por se tratar de um algoritmo de cálculo muito rápido, torna fácil um ataque por força bruta.

http://blog.thiagobelem.net/encriptando-senhas-de-forma-segura

Answer (score 3):

MD5 não é uma boa opção para encriptar senhas, por diversos motivos. É certamente melhor do que nada, mas não é uma proteção "séria". Alguns motivos são do MD5, outros do tipo de algoritmo que ele é.

1) O MD5 é um algoritmo de hash com diversas fraquezas, ou pelo menos já teve diversas fraquezas descobertas. Não se recomenda usar MD5 para verificar a integridade de um documento, pois há meios de gerar outro documento com o mesmo MD5 facilmente.

2) Para encriptar senha com hash, você deve no mínimo usar um 'salt'. Do contrário, é fácil usar uma "rainbow table", ou seja, uma lista de hashes precomputados com senhas comuns. Por exemplo, se você procurar por 455c99907225a26d1a6e3fa2ce99c9c0 no Google, vai descobrir que este é o MD5 da palavra 'sux'. Ou seja, se eu tivesse usado MD5 para criptografar a senha 'sux', seria trivial descobrir a senha original!

O 'salt' ou 'tempero' é adicionado à senha original antes de calcular o hash, de modo que o hash seja diferente para cada usuário e senha. Por exemplo, o MD5 de 'saltsux' é 5b599ee9dbeb7d6469fa9c300cad07cc, esse você já não encontra mais fazendo uma procura simples no Google, e mesmo que um invasor soubesse que o 'salt' é igual a 'salt', isso não ajuda muito na hora de calcular o hash. Obviamente, o 'salt' deveria ser aleatório e diferente para cada usuário, usar um 'salt' fixo e curto foi apenas um exemplo bobo.

3) Os algoritmos de hash em geral (MD5, SHA1, SHA2, SHA256, etc.) são concebidos para rodar o mais rápido possível. Isso viabiliza outra forma de ataque: ficar calculando o hash de inúmeras palavras (com o 'salt') para tentar encontrar o hash que bate com seu sistema - e assim descobre-se a senha.

Para evitar este problema, deve-se usar hashses específicos para encriptar senhas, como o bcrypt, que consome bastante CPU e tempo para calcular o hash. Um adversário que queira tentar diversos hashes perderia um tempo enorme calculando cada hash possível.

O Bitcoin usa um esquema curioso para consumir muita CPU no cálculo do hash. Ele usa SHA-256, que é muito rápido, porém o hash tem de ter um número de zeros (bits 0) no início. O número de zeros é calibrado de forma a que o hash demore em média 10 minutos para ser encontrado. Esta é uma estratégia que também poderia ser usada para, a partir de um algoritmo de hash rápido, criar um algoritmo de hash 'lento', que serviria para senhas.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Sobre o Bitcoin, o propósito do hash nesse caso é muito diferente, de modo que não tem como comparar uma coisa com outra. O problema de se usar uma estratégia semelhante pra proteger senhas é que verificar o hash seria custoso tanto pro atacante quanto pro próprio servidor - e queremos que ele seja custoso só pro atacante. Pois se o servidor não pode armazenar o prefixo aleatório (ou o atacante também o obteria junto aos hashes), como ele faria pra verificar se uma senha bate com um hash sem fazer a operação trabalhosa toda de novo? :P

Answer (score 3):

Muito bem colocada a resposta do @daniel-omine.

Concordo que o md5 não é tão inseguro assim, não adianta ter um sistema de login super-seguro, que bloqueia múltiplas tentativas de login, etc se temos o senhor **usuário**. Já li em algum lugar (e concordo) que a parte mais insegura de um sistema são os usuários. Dificilmente em um sistema não terá um user sequer que irá utilizar uma senha tosca, comumente usada, e que use essa mesma senha para logar-se no email cadastrado no sistema e o resto é fácil prever.
Não recomendo **md5** já que existem alternativas melhores como o próprio 
[password_hash](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php).

Sei que muitos não estão nem aí pra esse problema que sempre existirá em sistemas que não preveêm senhas fracas, mas dificultar o trabalho de possíveis invasores, já é um bom começo.

Comment: Não, o problema geralmente é o programador. O usuário só faz o que o programador permite.

Comment: Não foquei corretamente a parte do "senhor usuário". No caso não se aplicaria diretamente a invasão de um database mas sim em um dado sistema. Seria algo mais relacionado a Engenharia Social.

Answer (score 2):

MD5

O md5 gera uma string alfa-numérica de 32 caracteres, não importa se você tá gerando o md5 de duas letras ou de um texto de 20 parágrafos… O md5 gerado sempre vai ter 32 caracteres.

SHA1

A outra hash de mão única é o sha1. Ele é praticamente identico ao md5, só que tem 160 bits, o que acaba criando uma string-resultado maior: 40 caracteres alfa-numéricos. Outro ponto do sha1 é que, por ser 160 bits e gerar uma cadeia de caracteres maior, uma colisão (encontrar duas strings que, codificadas, sejam a mesma coisa) é bem mais rara que numa chave de 128bits.

http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografia-no-php-usando-md5-sha1-e-base64