# Erro ao verificar resultado das variáveis com else e if

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema para retorno de mensagem de autenticação em uma pagina de login.
Especificamente e onde ele verifica que o campo login e senha são verificados como TRUE, se sim e o usuário não conter no banco ele ira retornar "usuário inválido", se conter o usuário e a senha estiver errada deverá retornar o erro de "senha inválida".
O problema e que ele retorna usuário inválido e senha inválida na mesma condição. Já tentei varias formas ali no else e if sempre acontece a mesma coisa de outras formas que tentei.

Onde foi que eu errei?

Onde acontece a inconsistência:

```
if ($login == TRUE && $senha == TRUE) {
        $_SESSION['login']=$login;
        unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
        echo "Senha inválida";      
}
if ($login == TRUE && $senha == TRUE) {
        unset ($_SESSION['login']);
        echo "Usúario inválido";
}
```

Validação completa:

```
session_start(); 
$login = $_POST['login']; $senha = $_POST['senha']; 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Sem conexão com o servidor"); 
$select = mysql_select_db("portal") or die("Sem acesso ao DB");  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `USUARIO` WHERE `NOME` = '$login' AND `SENHA`= '$senha'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows ($result) > 0 ) {
     $_SESSION['login'] = $login; 
     $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha; 
     header('location:editar-excluir.php');
 } 
 else {
if ($login == FALSE && $senha == FALSE){
         echo"Por favor preencha o nome do usuário e senha" ;
         } 
if ($login == FALSE && $senha == TRUE) {
        echo "Por favor preencha o campo do usuário";
        }
if ($login == TRUE && $senha == FALSE) {
        echo "Por favor preencha o campo senha";
        }

if ($login == TRUE && $senha == TRUE) {
        $_SESSION['login']=$login;
        unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
        echo "Senha inválida";      
}
if ($login == TRUE && $senha == TRUE) {
        unset ($_SESSION['login']);
        echo "Usúario inválido";
}
    }
```

Comment: aparentemente não há nada de errado com sua condição, o erro pode ser na hora de pegar valores do banco de dados, use o `echo` para escrever seu `sql` em tela e coloque para rodar no *SGBD*. veja se retorna algum valor.

Answer (score 2):

Duas coisas. Primeiro que você está fazendo uma série de comparações
separadas. Segundo que o ideal seria verificar se está vazio, e usar o `else` para ir eliminando condições:

```
if ( empty( $login ) && empty( $senha ) ){
    echo"Por favor preencha o nome do usuário e senha" ;
} elseif ( empty( $login ) ) {
    echo "Por favor preencha o campo do usuário";
} elseif ( empty( $senha ) ) {
    echo "Por favor preencha o campo senha";
} elseif ( $_SESSION['login'] == $login ) {
    unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
    echo "Senha inválida";      
} else {
    unset ($_SESSION['login']);
    echo "Usúario inválido";
}
```

Pra complementar, faltou o `die()` (ou `exit()` ) no redirect:

```
header('location:editar-excluir.php');
die();
```

Vale dizer que trabalhar com senha em aberto como você está fazendo é inadmissível em sistemas para uso real, mas se for só um exercício, "até passa".

Além disso, como você não está sanitizando os valores do POST, grande chance de um curioso com um mínimo de conhecimento apagar todo o seu DB remotamente.

Outra coisa estranha é o uso que você está fazendo do `unset()`. Como não entendi direito qual é o objetivo real destas linhas, não tenho como dar detalhes se deveriam ser como estão.

Pode ter outros problemas, pois só olhando o trecho do código postado, não dá pra ter certeza de como realmente é pra funcionar.

Comment: Eu ia tentar algo parecido. Mais analisando parece que vai solucionar.

Comment: Eu vou criptografar com md5 ou sha1.

Comment: MD5 não é criptografia, nem SHA1; no mínimo tem que usar bcrypt ou similares (e aprender a usar corretamente).

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113378

Comment: Funcionou! Vou dar uma olhada com bcrypt. Vou fazer alguns testes e confirmo a resposta. Valeu Obrigado.