# Criptografia de senhas em MD5?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Qual segurança o MD5 traz se a criptografia da uma senha está somente no banco de dados no campo password? se por acaso o sistema for invadido por qual quer outra brecha o MD5 influenciaria em alguma coisa? sendo que qual quer site na internet Decrypta esse MD5? Por quer usar?, qual segurança ele me traz? Abraços.

Comment: Acho que isso responde: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41517/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101. Em resumo, MD5 não serve para criptografar senha. Embora muita gente acha que serve, depois não sabe porque tem problemas de segurança em seu site. Ou pior, nem sabem que o site tem problemas de segurança.

Answer (score 8):

MD5 já não é confiável, é uma função de hash que está já obsoleta.

Se por acaso um atacante tiver acesso à tua BD e extrair as hashes basta usar isto, https://hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx , como centenas de outras ferramentas para cracar hashes deste tipo, ficando a saber as passwords reais respectivas às hashes  armazenadas na BD. Não digo que decifrará todas, mas grande parte delas.

Sublinho, isto só acontecerá se conseguirem as hashes, ou seja, penetrar e extrair a informação da base de dados... Mas convém sempre MAXIMIZAR A SEGURANÇA e não usar MD5 para armazenar hashes de passwords, usa antes por ex, bcrypt, sha256 etc... há boas alternativas.

Para o caso de ser php >= 5.5 podes usar uma funcão nativa, http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php, esta, na data desta resposta, usa bcrypt

Comment: Vou absorver essa MASTER informação. Obrigado. Também concordo. Mas me fala uma coisa, Criar uma criptografia própria , seria uma boa opção hoje em dia?

Comment: +1 Se está usando PHP use o `password_hash`, é simples e muito melhor que qualquer MD5.

Comment: @Amaral nop, já há tudo feito, usa as que há mais recentes que são muito boa. Seria uma perda de tempo

Comment: @Inkeliz obrigado, acrscentei isso na resposta. Boas festas

Comment: Essa sem dúvida é a melhor resposta, é uma pena que o autor da pergunta tenha aceito outra. Eu uso MD5 somente para criar UID's básicas sem grande importância, no mais a sua resposta é excelente.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 ele é uma criptografia de codificação sem volta. Após codificado não pode ser revertido. 
Eu vi em algum lugar que esse algoritmo tem uma certa vulnerabilidade pois é possível fazer cálculos que podem acerta a hash gerada sem tem o valo que foi codificado no inicio.

A segurança: As criptografias do tipo hash são usada APENAS para comparação. Um exemplo de sua utilização: Sistema de login. Quando o usuário digita sua senha o próprio lado front-side é gerado a hash a parti dessa senhas e é mandado para o lado back-side onde o server pega a hash que já está no banco e compara com a que foi recebida se as hashs forem iguais permissão concedida se não permissão negada. Em uma situação onde essa hash vaze do BD e for inserida novamente no campo de login será gerada uma nova hash só que essa será diferente da que esta na BD impedindo um login válido.

Alguns seres dedicados por saber da possibilidade de não poder decriptar a hash criam bd com a senhas inicial e a hash lado a lado. para que numa possível consulta a hash proposta será comparada com todas as que estão lá no banco de dados.

Um ataque de força bruta pode quebrar a segurança da hash se a senha proposta for fraca ex: 123, um algoritmo pode gerar diversas senhas aleatórias até cair em 123 sendo assim a hash será achada.

Resumindo as criptografias hash são usadas para autenticar uma informação sem expô-la diretamente.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, não foi exatamente minha pergunta mas ajudou MUITO!