# Login e senha errado com php

Tags: php, mysql

Bom tarde, estou criando um sistema de login e senha simples mas me deparei com alguns erro estranho, quando coloco o email e a senha e tento entrar ele me acusa que a senha está errada, e verifico no banco as informações estão certas, não sei por que mas aqui estão duas imagens para vocês entenderem...

a primeira imagem são as informações do banco...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A segunda imagem e o que está acontecendo na hora que tento entrar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código php:

```
<?php 
include("conexao.php");

if(isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 0){

    if(!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

    $_SESSION['email'] = $mysqli -> escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $_SESSION['senha'] = md5(md5($_POST['senha']));


    $sql_code = "SELECT senha, codigo FROM usuario WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
    $sql_query = $mysqli -> query($sql_code) or die ($mysqli -> error);
    $dado = $sql_query->fetch_assoc();
    $total = $sql_query-> num_rows;


    if($total == 0){
        $erro[] = "Este email não pertence a nenhum usuário.";
    }
    else{
        if($dado['senha'] == $_SESSION['senha']){

            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $dado['codigo'];

        } else{

            $erro[] = "Senha incorreta.";
        }

    }

    if(count($erro) == 0 || !isset($erro)){
        echo "<script>alert('Login efetuado com sucesso... Seja bem vindo'); location.href='sucesso.php';</script>";
    }

}


?>



<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php if(count($erro) > 0)
        foreach($erro as $msg){
            echo "<p>$msg</p>";
        }


    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input value="" type="text" placeholder="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="senha">

        <input type="submit" value="Entrar">



    </form>


    </body>

</html>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar, estou estudando essa parte de php e com banco de dados....

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54246/discussion-on-question-by-nathan-login-e-senha-errado-com-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso dá que "a senha está errada" porque tu na BD tens 1234 em "plain-text" e depois vais comparar com uma hash (`md5(md5($_POST['senha']))`) , ou seja, a password que tens armazenada na base de dados é diferente da password em hash com que estás a compara-la, 1234 != md5(md5(1234))...

Dito isto, o que deves fazer é inserir também a hash na BD para que a comparação, caso a password correta, seja igual. Em vez de armazenares na BD como "1234" deves inseri-la como hash também `md5(md5(1234));`, para que quando comparares com a password digitada no login as duas sejam iguais e o login seja bem sucedido.

NOTA: ontem respondi a uma pergunta que tinha a ver com MD5, apesar desse tema não ser relevante para esta questão convém saberes isto: [Criptografia de senhas em MD5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173343/criptografia-de-senhas-em-md5/173347#173347)