# Como trabalhar com criptografia base64 no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, criptografia

Preciso trabalhar com criptografia no MySQL e preciso usar `base64` porque ouvir dizer que o MD5 possui uma pequena falhar de que permite que tenha duas senha distintas com o mesmo MD5.
Preciso criptografar e descriptografar.

```
insert into scl_usuario (login, senha, email, nome, sobrenome, setor) value ("jose", base64_encode("123"), "jose.silva@bol.com.br", "José", "da Silva", "Desenvolvimento");
```

Comment: Esta dando que a função não existe.

Comment: Se você quer proteger as senhas no banco, recomendo que leia o artigo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura

Comment: base64 não é criptografia, é uma representação de dados binários como texto. Você não "criptografa" para base64, você "codifica" e "descodifica", e isso é bem simples de fazer (no sentido de que não é útil como proteção contra leitura dos dados codificados). Leia as respostas da pergunta cidata por @Avelino.

Comment: Eu vi aqui.
Esta bem completo esse link.
Obrigado.

Comment: Base64 é praticamente a mesma coisa que senha em aberto. Você deve usar algo que não seja reversível. Pra conferir a senha você deve fazer a mesma operação no que o usuário digitou e comparar com o BD, e não tentar decodificar a do BD pra comparar com a senha limpa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## MySQL >= 5.6.1

Em MySQL, realizar codificação ou descodificação em BASE64 só é possível a partir da versão 5.6.1. Versões anteriores dão o seguinte erro:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION impor_website_2014.TO_BASE64 does not exist
```

As funções introduzidas na versão referida em cima foram:

[**TO_BASE64()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64)

> Converte o argumento para uma forma codificada em base-64 e retorna o resultado como uma *string* com o *character* e *collation* da ligação à base de dados. Se o argumento não é uma *string*, ele é convertido para *string* antes de conversão. O resultado é *NULL* se o argumento é *NULL*.

[**FROM_BASE64()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64)

> Pega uma *string* codificada com as regras de base-64 usadas por `TO_BASE64()` e retorna o resultado decodificado como uma *string* binária. O resultado é *NULL* se o argumento é *NULL* ou não uma *string* em base-64.

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```mysql
SELECT TO_BASE64('abc'), FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64('abc'));    # Devolve: 'JWJj', 'abc'
```

---

## MySQL < 5.6.1

Existe um projeto no GitHub com vista a solucionar codificação e descodificação em BASE64 para versões mais antigas de MySQL:

### [mysql-udf-base64](https://github.com/y-ken/mysql-udf-base64)

É essencialmente uma UDF <sup>User Defined Function</sup> que visa criar as funções: `base64encode()` e `base64decode()`.

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```
SELECT base64encode('data,binary,text,...');
SELECT base64decode('b64strings');
INSERT INTO t1 (body) VALUES (base64encode('something'));
```

Para poderes utilizar, tens que fazer a construção e a ativação:

**Construir**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/y-ken/mysql-udf-base64.git
$ cd mysql-udf-base64
$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -shared base64.c -o base64.so
$ sudo install -m 755 base64.so `mysql_config --plugindir`
```

**Ativação**

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION base64encode RETURNS STRING SONAME 'base64.so';
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION base64decode RETURNS STRING SONAME 'base64.so';
```

<sup>Exemplos e método para construir e ativar retirados do GitHub da [página do projeto](https://github.com/y-ken/mysql-udf-base64).</sup>

---

<sup>**Nota:**

Convém salientar que esta resposta visa lidar com o problema exposto: *O uso de uma função e o fato de estar a dar um erro ao tentar usar a mesma.*

Base64 não produz o resultado descrito na [encriptação](/questions/tagged/encripta%c3%a7%c3%a3o), Base64 não é criptografia, é apenas a conversão da string para um padrão radix-64 comummente utilizado para uniformizar caracteres, como o caso da transferência de imagens entre diferentes sistemas. Qualquer sistema de *Encode* que tem o método  *Decode* não deve ser utilizado para senhas (passwords).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Base64 não é criptografia, se trata de apenas um padrão de codificação como outros UTF-8 entre inúmeros padrões de codificação, isto dito o MD5 tem sim sua possibilidade de colisão, mas é muito pequena.

veja esse paper para uma explicação mais detalhada sobre a colisão:
<https://ad-pdf.s3.amazonaws.com/papers/wp.MD5_Collisions.en_us.pdf>

Diferenças entre, criptografia, hash criptográfico e codificação.

**Criptográfia** existem dois tipos a simétrica e a assimétrica, o principio básico é que quando falamos de criptografia temos uma chave para criptografar/descriptografar o conteúdo. Alguns algoritmos de criptografia são:

1. AES
2. DES
3. RSA
4. Blowfish

**Codificação** é oque usamos para transitar informações entre sistemas diferentes, como por exemplo uma imagem, ela pode ser codificada em base64 e transferida sem perda de dados e depois decodificada, perceba que aqui não tratamos de um segredo, a informação é sempre visível, só que de forma diferente. Esse é um assunto bem extenso e uma pesquisa rápida no google sobre encoding, descobrira mais sobre, mas em essencial codificação são tabelas que vão nos dizer o que aquele binário significa em caracteres.

**Hash criptografico ou Digest** Aqui chego ao que acredito que vai de fato ser útil para a sua aplicação, que pelo que entendi é salvar a senha do usuário no banco de dados de forma que ela n fique exposta para nenhum administrador do banco e possível hacker, assim garantindo que a senha só é conhecida pelo usuário. Um algoritmo de hash o que ele vai fazer é calcular um código único e de tamanho único, sendo assim é feito o hash do que o usuário digita e comparado com o que hash que esta no banco de dados para ver se a senha é valida. Mais que o problema de colisão do md5 acredito que tenha outros problemas mais graves a se preocupar como:

- **rainbow tables** O problema aqui são hashes pré calculados e salvos em um banco de dados assim por exemplo se o usuário tiver uma senha fraca será simples descobrir a senha do mesmo, para solucionar isso temos varias estratégias, a primeira é forçarmos o usuário a ter uma senha forte e a segunda chama de salt, é junto a senha que o usuário digitou usarmos mais dados para torna-la mais complexa assim dificultando que esse hash já tenha sido pré calculado, as informações que são colocadas junto a senha podem ser absolutamente qualquer coisa, mas recomendo que sejam valores pseudo aleatórios.
- **O que usar?** Colisão na maioria dos algoritmos de Hash não é algo gravíssimo a se preocupar, pois levaria muito tempo para calcular uma possível colisão, e se feito um bom hash isso fica totalmente inviável, alguns algoritmos para utilizar para armazenar senhas, bcrypt(Blowfish based), SHA-256. Hashes com custo computacional alto em geral são utilizados pois evitam ataques de força bruta e geração de rainbow tables, hashes de custo computacional mais baixos são utilizados normalmente em outras aplicações como conferencia de arquivos em redes e banco de dados (neste caso menos ainda é importante ter ou não colisão).

Comment: A parte do Base64 está correta. Mas, o MD5/SHA-256 não são feitos para senhas, sugerir isso é um erro, veja o [Password Hashing Competition](https://www.password-hashing.net) para entender o motivo (no minimo você deve sugerir PBKDF2, se quer uasr SHA-256, e com custo de iteração alto). Existe outro tópico sobre isso aqui no SO, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura/2405#2405.