# Como decidir qual hash criptográfico usar?

Tags: criptografia

Gostaria de saber em que casos devo usar os diversos hash existente, pois pelo que sei existem diferenças grandes entre a segurança e processamento entre eles.

Existe algum considerado o melhor em relação velocidade x segurança?

Comment: Eu acho que isto já resposta isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101

Comment: Justamente isso que eu precisava. Devo remover a pergunta @bigown?

Comment: Acho que este caso seria bom.

Answer (score 0):

O mais comum de todos é o MD5, a maioria dos bancos de dados já possuem funções nativas para gerar esse tipo de hash. Esse também é o seu principal problema pois já existem na internet bibliotecas de MD5, por isso se você pretender usa-lo acrescente um prefixo e/ou um sufixo algo como 123456.

O recomendado pela New European Schemes for Signatures, Integrity and Encryption (NESSIE), uma organização europeia e pela própria ISO é o Whirlpool-T.

Pessoalmente eu uso o MD5 após adicionar sufixos e prefixos e embaralhar a mensagem.

Comment: MD5 não é um algoritmo seguro, é possivel quebralo com algoritimos de colisão, o SHA-2 ou SHA-3 não mais indicados para se realizar um Hash. Quanto ao Salt, não é interresante que ele seja um valor estatico e previsivel, o ideal seria utilizar uma Guid para o serviço.

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de sugerir um algoritmo de Hash, no caso o BLAKE2.
O BLAKE, foi um dos candidatos finalistas para ser o algoritmo para o SHA-3, porém o Keccak saiu vitorioso.

Porém o mesmo sofreu algumas modificações, nascendo a segunda versão (BLAKE2), que diz ser mais rápido que o MD5 e tão forte quanto o atual SHA-3

Mais sobre:
https://leastauthority.com/blog/BLAKE2-harder-better-faster-stronger-than-MD5.html