# Criptografia de senha em login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, autenticação, criptografia

Preciso criar uma forma de criptografar minha senha no login do meu sistema, pois ainda não implementei essa segurança e não tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso.

Então como eu poderia criar essa criptografia e compara-la a hora do login e ver se está certo ? Ou seja, criar aquele hash pra confundir o atacante (caso eu tenha uma pessoa usando o *While Shark* pra tentar interceptar minha senha) ?

Qual é a melhor forma (base 64,MD5, RSA, entre outras formas) ?

Aqui o código do meu *controller* que uso pra fazer o login e comparar o login e a senha no banco:

## AutenticacaoController

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
    {
        //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
        Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();
        if (login != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Nome.ToString(), false);
            Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);
            Session.Add("UsuarioID", login.UsuarioID);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //pagina padrao para todos os usuarios...
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
       
    }
```

Comment: [Nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215) você vai achar todas as informações que precisa. Em resumo, não use uma forma reversível (base 64 é uma simples codificação de dados, nem é criptografia), nem um hash rápido (tipo o MD5). Nunca ouvi falar em HSA, do que se trata? A propósito, a função do hash não é impedir que alguém "intercepte" sua senha - pra isso proteja a sua comunicação (i.e. use SSL/TLS/HTTPS) - e sim impedir que alguém que já obteve uma cópia do banco de dados (via outro ataque) descubra todas as senhas e faça login.

Comment: @mgibsonbr RSA, perdão o erro, fiz na rapidez a pergunta nem me atentei a isso, mas vou editar aqui pra deixar certinho! E muito obrigado pelo comentario. Só quero evitar que alguém use o while shark e consiga visualizar a senha certa. Quero fazer exatamente isso que falou.

Comment: Blz. RSA, sendo criptografia reversível, também não serve pra proteger a senha (se o atacante tem uma cópia do BD, ele também tem a cópia da chave, então ele pode descriptografar a senha). O hash, por outro lado, não dá pra "desfazer", mesmo se você tiver acesso a tudo - a única coisa que resta é no login fazer o hash de novo e comparar os resultados. De novo, a pergunta linkada tem informações mais completas.

Comment: Mas você entende de C# para que eu possa ter uma ideia de como implementar essa criptografia ? Vou ler a pergunta que linkou assim que puder. Dei uma olhada rápida e vi que tem muta informação.

Comment: Para o PBKDF2 você pode usar o [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) que faz parte do próprio .Net (o exemplo de uso na documentação está meio ruim, tente [esse no OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_Rfc2898DeriveBytes_for_PBKDF2)). Para o BCrypt existe o [BCrypt.Net](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/), e para o scrypt tem algumas sugestões [nessa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4845977/520779).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada um destes algoritmos tem uma finalidade diferente, então para se proteger a senha é interessante se utilizar deles em diferentes momentos.

Por exemplo, para proteger a senha de um ataque man-in-the-middle, é importante se usar SSL, que basicamente usa RSA.

Agora para armazenar a senha no Banco de dados, é interessante se usar AES ou SHA.

Caso opte por utilizar AES, tem a combinação do algoritmo Rijndael com blocos e chaves de 256 bits.

Uma outra opção é utilizar um algoritmo de Hash, neste caso dê preferência para o SHA-2, SHA-3 ou BLAKE2, neste caso eu aconselharia o uso do BLAKE2.

Em ambos os casos é interessante utilizar um Salt, eu aconselharia uma Guid Aleatória e Única para cada senha.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta @TobyMosque. Será que teria exemplos de códigos ou links de exemplos para que eu possa traçar um norte em como fazer isso ?

Comment: Para o BLAKE2 você pode olhar o seguinte site https://blake2.net, nele você vai encontrar a implementação e exemplos para várias linguagens. Quanto ao SHA-3 você só precisa fazer uma busca rápida no nugets. No caso de SHA2 e AES, eles já estão implementados dentro do Framework,  você pode exemplos nos seguintes sites: http://adventuresindevelopment.com/2009/06/02/hash-passwords-in-c-and-visual-basic-using-sha-512/ e http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704372/How-to-use-Rijndael-ManagedEncryption-with-Csharp. E quanto ao Salt, basicamente é colocar uns bytes adicionais antes de criptografar.

Comment: Putz @TobyMosque valeu demais !

Comment: O BLAKE2 foi projetado para ser **rápido**, mas para um hash ser útil na proteção de senhas ele precisa necessariamente ser **lento**. O SHA-3, que eu saiba, oferece essa opção de "lentidão programável", mas todos os outros que você citou não. AES/Rijndael (são +/- a mesma coisa) também não serve pra armazenar a senha com segurança (onde você guardaria a chave? num módulo de hardware?), pois se o seu servidor consegue descriptografar o atacante também consegue... Por fim, SSL pode usar RSA sim (essa parte da resposta está correta), mas também pode usar outros algoritmos, como Curvas Elípticas.

Comment: P.S. No próprio [FAQ do BLAKE2](https://blake2.net/#qa) ele diz explicitamente: "Você não deve usar \*nenhuma\* função de hash de propósito geral para senhas de usuários, nem BLAKE2, e nem MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, ou SHA-3. Em vez disso você deve usar uma função de derivação de chave baseada em senha tal como PBKDF2 ou scrypt com um número apropriado de iterações de modo a desacelerar o processo de hashing, mitigando assim o risco de ataques de força bruta."

Comment: @mgibsonbr, obrigado pelas observações, realmente "PBKDF2 + Hash" seria a melhor opção.