# Adicionar um campo de login em tabela existente de usuários

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Qual seria a melhor forma de adicionar um campo de **login** em uma tabela existente de banco do dados com mais ou menos 10 mil usuários. Estou usando no momento o MySQL e gostaria de dar uma remodelada na tabela de usuários, no momento a tabela contem nome, e-mail, senha, e data de cadastro, e os usuários iniciavam a sessão com e-mail e senha apenas. Gostaria de colocar a opção de fazer login com nome de usuário também.

Pensei em adicionar o campo login e popular os usuários existentes com strings aleatórias, mas não sei se seria a melhor forma de fazer isso. Alguém teria uma sugestão de uma forma mais "correta" de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do ponto de vista da experiência do usuário, usar e-mails como login costuma ser mais conveniente que usar "nomes de usuário" (*usernames*). Em primeiro lugar porque é mais uma coisa pro usuário lembrar ("qual *username* eu usei nesse site?"), segundo porque e-mails são únicos, enquanto o nome de usuário pode já ter sido utilizado obrigando-o a escolher outro, etc. Se seu sistema funciona bem sem nomes de usuário, sugiro não introduzi-los "só por fazer".

Se por outro lado você tem motivos para querer isso (ex.: não é bom expor o e-mail de um usuário aos outros sem seu consentimento, e às vezes é necessário que um deles identifique unicamente o outro de alguma forma), há duas principais formas de fazer isso a meu entender:

- Pegar uma combinação do primeiro nome e iniciais do sobrenome (ou vice-versa, dependendo do que é mais comum na cultura desses usuários), talvez acrescentando um sufixo numérico caso dois recebam o mesmo *username*; ou:
- Pegar a primeira parte do seu e-mail (antes da @) e fazer o mesmo caso dois possuam isso igual. Isso expõe um pouco mais da privacidade do usuário (fica mais fácil "adivinhar" seu e-mail baseado no seu *username*), mas creio que depende do ponto de vista... (outros podem preferir não ter seu nome verdadeiro revelado, varia de caso a caso)

Usar string aleatórias teria pouco benefício, como você bem questionou, talvez exceto se for dada ao usuário a oportunidade de mudar seu *username* se ele assim o quiser (de todo modo, ainda é uma chateação...). E um último detalhe: se sua tabela contém um campo `senha`, espero que você a esteja [armazenando de forma correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se a preocupação for manter sigilo do endereço de email do usuário durante o login e diante dos demais usuários, há também uma opção simples que é utilizar um campo de texto (INPUT) tipo (PASSWORD) para a digitação do Endereço de Email.