# Como calcular o valor de hash de um array de bytes específico

Tags: android, eclipse, android-eclipse, hash, md5

Como eu calculo o valor de hash de um array de bytes específico?

Estou usando criptografia MD5 e o código para calcular que estou usando é este:

```
        byte[] dataRegCodeToCompare = md5.digest(toHash);
```

A variável `toHash` é o array de bytes. Eu já tenho uma tabela pronta dos valores de `toHash` e `dataRegCodeToCompare` que tem que sair mas, os calculados e inseridos em `dataRegCodeToCompare` não estão batendo.

Segue os valores de `toHash`:
[52, 80, 69, 82, 68, 73, 57, 78, 69, 67, 56, 73, 56, 80, 49, 73, 53, 79, 48, 68, 65, 65, 51, 67, 52, 79, 50, 82, 53, 82, 65, 69]

Segue os valores de `dataRegCodeToCompare`: [43, 252, 237, 75, 30, 238, 188, 243, 213, 203, 78, 212, 226, 27, 49, 241]

E estes são os valores de `dataRegCodeToCompare` que estão saindo com o código indicado no começo da pergunta: [43, -4, -19, 75, 30, -18, -68, -13, -43, -53, 78, -44, -30, 27, 49, -15] *alguns valores estão até negativos*.

Comment: Relevante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101

Comment: @bigown, infelizmente este link não me ajudou...