# Função de encriptação melhor que o md5?

Tags: php, criptografia

Li uns artigos dizendo que a encriptação `md5` não deve mais ser utilizada, já que ela não é considerada mais segura (também pudera, em 5 minutos eu entro em um **site qualquer** e quebro uma senha dessas). Eu estive procurando por outros meios de encriptação e ouvi falar do `crypt()`, não o acho tão seguro comparado aos que irei falar agora.
Li [esse artigo](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografia-no-php-usando-sha512-whirlpool-e-salsa20/) e achei os métodos muito interessantes (em especial o SHA-512), porém o mesmo é de 2010, esses meios de encriptação continuam sendo os melhores ou já existem superiores?
Lembrando que meu foco é encriptar senhas.

### Referências

Artigos que eu tomei base ao fazer essa pergunta:

- http://www.zdnet.com/article/md5-password-scrambler-no-longer-safe/
- http://blogs.gartner.com/ramon-krikken/2012/06/06/linkedin-password-hack-and-the-case-of-the-misunderstood-crypto-function/
- http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografia-no-php-usando-sha512-whirlpool-e-salsa20/

Comment: Por alguma razão eu acho que isto deveria estar no meta, mesmo assim, eu tenho usado [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php). Mas há algum tempo que nao preciso de fazer uma bd importante, pelo que tenho lido, sha256/512 é o caminho a seguir :)

Comment: Não sei se exatamente duplicada, mais talvez possa encontrar suas respostas aqui [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Comment: @abfurlan, li a resposta da pergunta que você vinculou e me esclareceu bastantes coisas. Vou optar por utilizar o `bcrypt`, até que alguém sugira algo contra.

Comment: Marquei como duplicada, apenas para criar um link entre as questões.

Comment: Creio ser duplicata sim. Você não "encripta" senhas (ou pelo menos não deveria, infelizmente vejo muito disso por aí...), você "hasheia". Está tudo explicado na pergunta linkada. MD5 está sim "quebrado" para a maioria das aplicações, mas não todas (ex.: ainda pode ser usado para testar a integridade de arquivos, ou talvez como parte de um HMAC), e nem sempre pelos mesmos motivos (colisões não são importantes no caso de hash de senhas, lentidão sim).

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, marquei como duplicata. Apenas uma coisa, eu li esse tópico em um fórum: http://goo.gl/e2VKBh. Nele dizem que o `bcrypt` não é seguro. Como fica então?

Comment: Você conseguiu achar a resposta?