# Segurança em sistema de login

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Olá, eu fiz um sistema de download e upload de arquivo torrent, e nesse site tem um sistema de login com um banco de dados, e eu gostaria que me explicassem um pouco sobre segurança no PHP e mySql e oque devo fazer para manter a segurança do site.

Se puder evitar de me mandar uma material/tópico em inglês ou me mandar procurar no Google eu agradeceria.

Sistema para fazer o cadastro

```
    include("connection.php");

$login = $_POST['login_cadastro'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_cadastro'];
$confirmarsenha = $_POST['confirmarsenha_cadastro'];
$email = $_POST['email_cadastro'];

if($senha != $confirmarsenha)
{   
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
          <script type='text/javascript'>alert('As senhas estão diferentes')</script>";
}
else
{
    $sqlpegar = mysqli_query($coneccao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios");

    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpegar))
    {   
        $login_db = $linha['login'];
        $email_db = $linha['email'];
    }

    if($login_db == $login)
    {
        echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>
                <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse usuario já existe')</script>";
    }
    if($email_db == $email)
    {
        echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>
                <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse email já esta sendo usado')</script>";
    }
    else
    {

        $sql = mysqli_query($coneccao, "INSERT INTO usuarios(login, senha, email) VALUES ('$login', '$senha', '$email')");  
        header("location: index.php");  
    }
}

mysqli_close($coneccao);
```

Sistema para fazer login

```
    include "connection.php";

$login = $_POST['login_entrar'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_entrar'];

$sql = mysqli_query($coneccao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'");    


while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $senha_db = $linha['senha'];
    $login_db = $linha['login'];
}

$cont = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if($login_db != $login || $login == "")
{       
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Este usuario não existe')</script>";      
}
else
{
    if($senha_db != $senha )
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Senha incorreta')</script>";  
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $login;

        header("location: index.php");  
    }
}

mysqli_close($coneccao);
```

connection.php

```
$coneccao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($coneccao, "luppbox");
```

Comment: Claro, já edito a pergunta

Comment: Relacionado: ["Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, este é um "rabisco" de um sistema de login do tutorial que criei recentemente, não é o mais complexo, mais vai ajudar-te a entender o básico sobre a segurança atualmente.

## Formulário login & cadastro

```
<?php
// index.php
require_once("database.php");
// [Nao usar estes modelos em aplicacoes reais]
// Estes são apenas para demonstração e teste, e não são nada seguros
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["tipo"]) && $_POST["tipo"] === "novo"){
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    // Limpar caracteres invalidos
    // Incompleto [Nao usar estes modelos em aplicacoes reais]
    // Validar Letras para o usuarios e remover espaços brancos com o trim()
    $usuario = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","", $usuario) ? trim($usuario) : NULL;
    // Validar Conjunto alfa-numérico para o password e remover espaços brancos com o trim()
    $password = preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9]/", $password) ? trim($password) : NULL;
    if($usuario !== NULL && $password !== NULL){
        $sim = registar($usuario, $email, $password);
        if($sim){
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            //Erro para o caso de o usuario ja existir, ou nao ser armazenado
            echo "<span style=\"color:red;\">erro: cadastro falhou, tente novamente.</span>";
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        //Erro para o caso de a senha, usuario, email estar(em) vazio(s)
        echo "<span style=\"color:red;\">erro: usuario/senha vazio(s)</span>";
        exit;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["tipo"]) && $_POST["tipo"] === "entrar"){
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    // $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    // Limpar caracteres invalidos
    $usuario = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","", $usuario) ? trim($usuario) : NULL;
    $password = preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9]/", $password) ? trim($password) : NULL;
    if($usuario !== NULL && $password !== NULL){
        $sim = login($usuario, $password);
        if($sim){
            header("Location: privado.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            //Erro para o caso de o usuario nao ser encontrado ou para o caso de os dados nao corresponderem
            echo "<span style=\"color:red;\">erro: usuario/senha nao encontrados</span>";
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        //Erro para o caso de a senha e usuario estar(em) vazio(s)
        echo "<span style=\"color:red;\">erro: usuario/senha vazio(s)</span>";
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<!-- HTML !-->
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login/Cadastro [Seguro]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            if(isset($_GET["opcao"]) && $_GET["opcao"] === "entrar"){
            ?>
            <!-- LOGIN !-->
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="index.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="entrar"/>
                Usuario:<br/>
                <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" size="40"/><br/>
                Password:<br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="40"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Entrar"/>
            </form>
            <a href="index.php?opcao=novo">Cadastrar</a><br/><br/>
            <?php
            } elseif(isset($_GET["opcao"]) && $_GET["opcao"] === "novo"){
            ?>
            <!-- CADASTRO !-->
            <h1>Cadastrar</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="index.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="novo"/>
                Usuario:<br/>
                <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" size="40"/><br/>
                Email:<br/>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40"/><br/>
                Password:<br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="40"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Entrar"/>
            </form>
            <a href="index.php?opcao=entrar">Login</a><br/><br/>
            <?php
            } else {
            ?>
            <!-- LOGIN !-->
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="index.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="entrar"/>
                Usuario:<br/>
                <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" size="40"/><br/>
                Password:<br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="40"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Entrar"/>
            </form>
            <a href="index.php?opcao=novo">Cadastrar</a><br/><br/>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

O Formulário de login e cadastro estão num único ficheiro juntamente com a validação para ambos.
Num script de login e cadastro, é sempre crucial `sanear, validar` as informações provenientes do formulários de modo a verificar se possuem o tamanho certo, ou se não contém nenhum caráter problemático.
Presta atenção as notas no script, e repare que eu não utilizei sequer uma validação decente.

## Banco de dados

```
<?php
// database.php
session_start();
// Em fase de correcção não vamos querer essa função no ativo
// Se esta linha for descomentada, os erros estarao visiveis apenas no log.log
// ini_set("error_reporting", "E_ALL");
require_once("blowfish.php");

// Host, normalmente é o local
DEFINE("HOST", "localhost");
// O port, na maior parte das vezes é dispensavel
// Ainda assim o POST inicia conexoes seguras/nao seguras dependendo do PORT usado
// DEFINE("PORT", "80");
// Usuario do banco de dados
DEFINE("USR", "root");
// Senha do usuario do banco de dados
DEFINE("PWD", "");
// Banco de dados
DEFINE("BD", "_banco_de_dados_em_uso_");

// Ficheiro de log, caso não exista, crie um manualmente;
// Ou crie uma função que o faça de forma segura e autonoma
$error_log = "log.log";

$db = new mysqli(HOST, USR, PWD, BD);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    error_logi("Conexao falhou", mysqli_connect_error());
}

function error_logi($error,$msg=""){
    global $error_log;
    
    $log_msg = $error . " : " . $msg . PHP_EOL;
    
    return file_put_contents($error_log, $log_msg, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    exit;
}

// Função para encontrar usuario por nome;
function encontrar_usuario($usuario){
    global $db;
    ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username,senha FROM usuarios WHERE username=?")) || error_logi("STMT Encontrar Usuario", $db->error);
    
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $usuario) || error_logi("STMT Bind Param", $db->error);
    
    $stmt->execute() || error_logi("STMT Execute", $db->error);
    
    $stmt->bind_result($username,$senha) || error_logi("STMT Bind Result", $db->error);
    
    $stmt->fetch();
    
    $result = ["username"=>$username,"senha"=>$senha];
    
    return $result;
}
// Função para efectuar o registo;
function registar($usuario, $email, $password){
    global $db;
    $password = hash_password($password);
    ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (username, email, senha) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
    || error_logi("SQL Prepared Statment",$db->error);
    ($stmt->bind_param('sss', $usuario, $email, $password)) || error_logi("SQL BindParam",$db->error);
    $exec = $stmt->execute() ? true : error_logi("SQL Execute",$db->error);
    return $exec;
    $stmt->close();
    $db->close();
}
// Tentar fazer o login
function login($usuario, $password){
    $usuario = encontrar_usuario($usuario);
    if($usuario){
        // usuario encontrado
        // Verificar a hash para a password
        if(verifica_hash($password, $usuario["senha"])){
            $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario["username"];
            return true;
        } else {
            // hash não encontrada
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // usuario não encontrado
        return false;
    }
}

function check_login($usuario){
    $existe = encontrar_usuario($usuario);
    if($existe){
        return $existe["username"] === $usuario ? true : false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

No banco de dados o campo senha deve ser do tipo `VARCHAR(60)` para poder armazenar a `hash`.

## Pagina Privada (restrita a pessoas sem sessão)

```
<?php
// privado.php
// Esta é a página protegida
require_once("database.php");

if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    if(check_login($_SESSION["usuario"])){
        echo "Logado";
        // Isto é um sistema para teste, daí usar esta função aqui
        // Significa que a página só pode ser visualizada apenas 1 vez por login
        session_destroy();
    } else {
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

## HASH

```
<?php
// blowfish.php
// Script util apenas para versões do PHP < 5.5.0;
// Função que gera a hash
function hash_password($password){
    $formato = "$2y$10$";
    $salt = salt(22);
    $formato_salt = $formato.$salt;
    $password_hash = crypt($password, $formato_salt);
    return $password_hash;
    // Se algo correr mal a função vai retornar falso;
}
// Função que gera o salt
function salt($tamanho){
    //$random = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    // ambas funções geram valores aleatorios
    $random = md5(uniqid(mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM), true));
    $base = base64_encode($random);
    $base64 = str_replace('+', '.', $base);
    $salt = substr($base64, 0, $tamanho);
    return $salt;
}
// Função para comparar as duas hash
function verifica_hash($password, $hash_existente){
    $hash = crypt($password, $hash_existente);
    if($hash === $hash_existente){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


?>
```

Neste script acima, as funções servem apenas para o `PHP < 5.5.0`, para versões superiores recomendo o substituir no ficheiro database.php as funções `hash_password, verifica_hash` pelas novas funções oficialmente introduzidas pelo `PHP >= 5.5.0`:

[password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php)
[password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php)

E se possível, usar estas funções em vez de usar o ficheiro `blowfish.php`.

também existe uma `API` para versões do `PHP >= 5.3.7` que inicializa estas novas funções do `PHP >= 5.5.0` em versões inferiores, basta que o script em uso faça um `require` desta `API`.

[PASSWORD COMPAT API](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

## Outras dicas de segurança:

*Evitar usuários do tipo `root` para manejar aplicações como cliente.

*Evitar salvar passwords como `texto simples` ou `plain-text` para o inglês.

*Pedidos do tipo `GET` têm de ser sempre `idempotentes`, ou seja, incapazes de realizar modificações no lado do servidor (para modificações utilize `POST`).

Para além destas citadas, existem vários pontos em que se deve ter atenção. No entanto deixo apenas este resumo, e boa sorte.

[WikiHow - How to create a secure login script in PHP and MySQL](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

[GitHub - PHP Login Advanced](https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced)

Comment: Olá, não entendi direito para que serve o privado.php

Comment: Olá, imagina que a página `privado.php` é a página que os usuários só podem visualizar se estiverem autenticados.

Answer (score 3):

**Armazenando Senhas no Banco de Dados**

É recomendado que ao armazenar senhas no banco de dados, você não o faça de forma a armazená-las como text-plain (ou texto puro). Uma forma de salvá-las seria utilizando **hashs** e **salts**. Existe um exemplo bem didático [aqui](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografando-senhas-no-php-usando-bcrypt-blowfish/).

**Evitando SQL Injection**

Quanto à conexão e execução de queries no banco de dados, é importante utilizar Statements para evitar ataques de SQL Injection. Este é um tipo de ataque que permite quem o está executando a executar queries maliciosas quando você realiza alguma query com variáveis concatenadas.

Ao invés de concatenar os atributos na string da query, use os wildcards e statements

Trocar isso:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($coneccao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'");
```

por:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'database');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $login);
$stmt->execute();
```

Desta forma você indica ao banco de dados que você enviará um atributo no lugar do caractere coringa '?' no método prepare(). Logo em seguida informa o tipo dele em bind_param, enviando o 's' para indicar que será uma string. Mais informações sobre os tipos de dados que podem ser enviados [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (em parameters > types)

Para efeito de exemplos segue um trecho de código com mais de 1 parâmetro (e com tipos diferentes):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE populacao > ? AND estado = ?")
$stmt->bind_param('is', 42000, "PR"); // 42000 é inteiro (i), "PR" é string (s)
$stmt->execute();
```