# Problema com criptografia de senha (PHP)

Tags: php, criptografia, login, senhas

Estou fazendo um sistema de Pet Shop e o problema é o seguinte: o cliente faz o cadastro, e a senha vai criptografada pro banco, mas na hora de fazer o login dá erro.
Exemplo: o usuário é Marcos e a sua senha é 123. Na hora de fazer o login, se coloco a senha "123" não entra, só entra se colocar o código criptografado.

Comment: Leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63411/seguran%C3%A7a-em-sistema-de-login/63461#63461

Answer (score 1):

1. Seja qual foi a criptografia usada para gravas no banco.
2. Na tela de login recupere a senha digitada e aplique a mesma criptografia da senha no banco.
3. Compare as duas strings e caso sejam iguais efetue o login.

#### Codigo

```
$senhaBanco = md5('123');

$senhaDigitada = '123';

echo md5($senhaDigitada) === $senhaBanco // true
```

Comment: O.o `md5` para senha ?

Comment: A lógica é essa mesma,mas MD5 e ainda por cima sem sal não dá, né... Sugiro [essa pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura?rq=1) para opções de algoritmos melhores (TL;DR: PBKDF2, Bcrypt ou scrypt).

Comment: Acho que md5() da resposta do Guilherme é meramente didático. A dicussão aqui não é qual o uso de criptografia mais adequada ou recomendada...

Comment: Sim, era meramente ilustrativo, e ate pelo que conheço de cursinhos geralmente de ensina com `md5` e `sha1`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr esse rua resposta é muito boa e didática, ja tinha lido sobre ela = D

Comment: De fato, a ciência e a tecnologia avançam, e o que é adequado hoje pode não ser amanhã. Um cursinho/tutorial escrito na época que MD5/SHA-1 (ou mesmo SHA-2) era usual, e que nunca foi atualizado, não está "errado" ou "ruim" só porque o cenário mudou - está apenas defasado. Ainda que sua resposta usasse o estado-da-arte hoje, ela não seria eternamente válida, portanto cabe ao leitor mostrar discernimento ao lê-la. Dito isso, ainda tem muita gente hoje que acha que MD5 é suficiente pra proteger senhas, e em parte isso se dá pela abundância de materiais nesse sentido. Queremos mais um?