# Manipular arquivos com C#

Tags: c#

O objetivo é capturar duas `string` digitadas em dois blocos de texto e salva-las em um arquivo (esse arquivo já está pré-definido e o usuário não saberá onde ele fica). Também quero saber como leio as informações do arquivo e armazeno essas informações em strings.

Exemplo de arquivo:

```
    Nome: Leonardo
    Sobrenome: Vilarinho
```

O nome e o sobrenome é o que o usuário vai digitar nos blocos de texto, e é o que eu devo colocar no arquivo, mas também devo acessar essas informações depois e armazena-las em strings, exemplo, armazenar "Leonardo" em uma string nome e "Vilarinho" em uma string sobrenome. E sempre que o usuário colocar outro nome ou sobrenome no bloco de texto ele substituir o arquivo.

O arquivo está dentro do projeto do Visual Studio, se possível, como criptografar o arquivo depois que ele é salvo. Já tentei usar `File` da biblioteca `IO`, mas não entendo muito disso.

Tentei assim:

```
File.Open(dados.txt, FileMode TextWriter);
 File.WriteAllText("Nome: %s\nSobrenome: %s", usuario, sobrenome );
```

Mas como dá pra ver não entendo nada sobre arquivos, e o código está todo errado, já vi vários vídeos, mas nenhum parecido com o meu objetivo. Nem tentei pegar as informações do arquivo depois, já que nem salvar eu consegui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada melhor na documentação da [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx), o método [`.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) não funciona do jeito que você está tentando fazer. O primeiro parâmetro é a localização do arquivo e o segundo o conteúdo.

```
var conteudo = string.Format("Nome: {0}{1}Sobrenome: {2}", usuario, Environment.NewLine, sobrenome);
var caminho = @"C://seudiretorio/meuarquivo.txt";

File.WriteAllText(caminho, conteudo);
```

Para ler utilize o [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(caminho);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if (line.Contains("Nome:"))
      usuario = line.Replace("Nome:","").Trim();
   else if (line.Contains("Sobrenome:"))
      sobrenome = line.Replace("Sobrenome:","").Trim();
}
file.Close();
```

Sobre criptografar sugiro que tu leia isso aqui antes: [Qual a diferença entre Encoding, Encryption e Hashing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66227/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-encoding-encryption-e-hashing)

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho string :)

Comment: Consegui aqui, obrigado, código bem escrito deu pra entender tudo.. E funcionou, agora verei o treco de criptografar

Comment: Para criptografar usei esse vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxQbu65xt7Q

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho bacana o video :)