# Retornar valor do select

Tags: php, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT username, mail, password FROM users WHERE username = :user_name OR mail = :user_name;";

$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':user_name', $user_name);
$query->bindParam(':user_password', $user_password);

$query->execute();
```

Como faço para retornar o valor de password do usuário?

Comment: Se você está explicitamente armazendo a senha dos seus usuários no banco de dados, [você está fazendo bobagem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura).

Comment: Eu estou fazendo hash '-' http://prntscr.com/7k1d7l

Comment: Leia o link que eu mandei — MD5 ou SHA1 (ou SHA-qualquer-coisa) não são o suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recuperar os valroes, tu pega pelo `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, assim:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username, mail, password FROM users WHERE username = :user_name OR mail = :user_name;");

$stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $user_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_password', $user_password);

$usuarios = array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // seu objeto $row que possui os username, mail, password

        // para adicionar o resultado num array
        $usuarios[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: E se eu quiser recuperar somente o valor password do usuário ?

Comment: é pelo $row dentro do while, `$row["password"]`

Comment: Fiz o code sem o while, e retornou o valor certo. Tem algum problema?

Comment: Não, é só pela iteração do resultado :)

Comment: É que no seu contexto realmente não vai retornar + de 1 resultado, então não tem problema