# Criptografia com Java e PostgreSQL/ MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, criptografia

Olá estou com um dúvida no meu projeto de faculdade, no escopo diz assim:
 "Os usuários e senhas podem    ser armazenados no banco de dados, utilizando a criptografia do próprio banco."

A cripto em ambos por default é feita com MD5?
Nesse caso eu preciso utilizar a cripto MD5 tanto na minha aplicação java e no banco ou apenas no banco é possível?
Grato!

Comment: O tipo de criptografia que protege senhas é chamado de ***hash***. A ideia é não salvar a senha em si no banco, mas o resultado da aplicação de uma função "de mão única" à senha (i.e. fácil de fazer, difícil de desfazer). Para verificar depois se a senha está correta, refaz-se o *hash* e compara-se os resultados. Na prática, você vai querer usar *hashes* "fortes", como o PBKDF2, BCrypt ou scrypt, mas pra fins desse exercício você pode usar o que o banco te oferecer mesmo, não vejo necessidade de ir muito além. Mas se der tente usar um **sal**, isso será importante depois "no mundo real".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Postgre você pode encriptar uma string manualmente com funções do próprio banco.

Por exemplo, a função MD5(varchar):

```
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome, senha) VALUES (1, 'Joao',md5('123'));
```

Fazendo um SELECT podemos obter:

```
1   "Joao"   "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70"
```

Comment: é bom lembrar que md5 é um algoritmo extremanente fraco e quebravel em questão de segundos

Comment: Sem dúvida! Há diversos sites pela rede com decriptadores de MD5. É interessante dar uma olhada neste link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/encryption-options.html

Comment: Tem o pgcrypto também, que é um plugin para o banco. 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html

Comment: @JoãoFelipeGonçalves É bom diferenciar entre as senhas dos usuários **do banco de dados** das senhas dos usuários **da aplicação/site**. o 1º link se refere às opções de criptografia pro primeiro caso - o que é razoável, pois é impraticável dar uma proteção abrangente para usuários do BD, de modo que MD5 por padrão é só pra dar uma "ofuscada", e mais nada. Para realmente se proteger contra ataques *offline*, é necessário [uma solução mais robusta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215). Para fins de aprendizado, entretanto, isso não importa, um MD5 (de preferência com sal) é bom o bastante.

Answer (score 2):

Para criptografar uma senha ou qualquer outra `string` você fazê-la na aplicação ou no banco. Aqui vou tratar com *SHA1* e *MD5*, porém este último já não é recomendado, veja [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura).

**PostgresSQL**

*MD5*

```
SELECT md5(senha);
```

*SHA1*

O algoritmo MD5 já vem pronto para ser usado no seu banco, porém o SHA1, não.
Para ser usado deve ser criada a extensão [pg_crypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) com seu *schema* selecionado e depois pode ser usada a função `digest` que também dispõe de outros algoritmos além do SHA1.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
SELECT encode(digest('senha', 'sha1'), 'hex');
```

**MySQL**

*MD5*

```
SELECT md5('senha');
```

*SHA1*

```
SELECT sha1('senha');
```

**Java**

```
// MD5
String criptografadaMd5 = criptografar("123456", "MD5");
// SHA1
String criptografadaSha1 = criptografar("123456", "SHA1");

public static String cripografar(String input, String tipoAlgoritmo) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(tipoAlgoritmo);
    byte[] result = mDigest.digest(input.getBytes());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```