# É possível usar MD6 em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, hash, md6

Falando em *hash*, é possível usar MD6 em C#?

Alguém teria um exemplo da utilização em uma simples *string*?

Em minhas pesquisas não encontrei nada muito objetivo.

Comment: Tem, mas porque você vai querer usar algo tão fora de padrão? Use algo melhor, algo que as pessoas se importam. Use o que dá para usar com SHA2. Ponto. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512(v=vs.110).aspx Nem estou recomendando esta, ela é mais forte mas é pesada de calcular.

Comment: Possível é. [Só precisa converter o algoritmo do link da Wiki em C para C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/md6/info).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez muito obrigado, esse será meu desafio pra hoje.

Comment: Se quiser fazer isso para fins de aprendizado, vá em frente, é sempre bom! Mas nunca, NUNCA implemente você mesmo um algoritmo criptográfico para usar na prática! Até mesmo portar um algoritmo de uma linguagem pra outra pode introduzir defeitos - não defeitos funcionais (tipo, o resultado sair errado) mas defeitos "colaterais" (ver *side-channel attacks*), que permitam a um atacante destruir completamente a segurança do seu sistema explorando detalhes da sua implementação (ex.: medindo o tempo que demora pra calcular, ou quanta energia o computador consome enquanto calcula, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pra não ficar sem resposta vou colocar aqui que é possível, já que todo algoritmo pode ser implementado em uma linguagem de programação.

Se quer saber se tem no .NET, não, não tem. Se tem em alguma biblioteca externa, desconheço alguma.

Então você terá que estudá-lo e fazer ou pedir para alguém fazer.

Mas a questão é: pra que? Porque quer usar algo que não é bem aceito na comunidade?

Você quer uma solução e isto você obtém com outros algoritmos. Experimente os algoritmos disponíveis na coleção do SHA2. Duvido que eles não atendem o que precisa. Um deles é o [SHA512](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha512?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que é pesado mas é bem forte. EM geral o pessoal até prefere usar algo menos forte e que seja mais rápido de calcular.

Exemplo:

```
static string sha512(string password) {
    byte[] bytes = new SHA512Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), 0,
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(password));
    var hash = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in bytes) {
        hash.Append(item.ToString("x2"));
    }
    return hash.ToString();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KhscjN). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4mQaL). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Cryptography.cs).

Comment: o mais recomendado não são o Rfc2898DeriveBytes e o BCrypt? Foi o que vi em minhas pesquisas...

Comment: Sim, Bcrypt é mais forte. E obviamente precisa saber usar direito. Se quer usar Bcrypt, use. Eu preferi dar uma solução que existe no .Net. Para usá-lo tem que pegar uma [biblioteca externa](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/). Mas coloquei alguma informação adicional para ter algum exemplo, a pergunta se refere a MD6 e não Bcrypt. Se tivesse falado dele, eu talvez tivesse colocado algo sobre ele. A [PBKDF2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) também é muito boa e tem no .Net. Não pensei nela. Pode ser melhor que estas opções.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues O "mais recomendado" depende do que você quer fazer. Hashear senhas? Use um hash lento. Verificar a integridade de arquivos? Use o hash mais rápido que encontrar (MD6 não me parece ruim, e há muitos outros, talvez até melhores). Verificar a **autenticidade** de arquivos? Use um hash rápido no conteúdo e em seguida um HMAC seguro em cima do hash. Etc.

Comment: @mgibsonbr quero apenas hasher senhas... Estou usando o PBKDF2, mas gostaria de experimentar o MD6 para fins de teste mesmo.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues, nenhum algoritmo de hash sozinho é seguro para proteger uma senha, caso queira um algoritmo sem risco de colisão e muito rapido, aconselho usar o [BLAKE2](https://blake2.net/). Ainda no site do BLAKE2, leia o FAQ, especialmente este item: [So I shouldn't use BLAKE2 for hashing user passwords](https://blake2.net/#Q4_hashing_passwords)

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues http://cynosureprime.blogspot.se/2015/09/how-we-cracked-millions-of-ashley.html bcrypt não serve pra nada se o resto não estiver certo. MD6 também não servirá.

Comment: @bigown e [qual é a maneira correta de se usar o bcrypt?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87725/qual-a-forma-correta-de-usar-bcrypt)

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues como eu nunca usei, eu não sei :P Na verdade isso é igual para qualquer algoritmo usado. Na [pergunta sobre *hash*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101) que você já conhece tem algumas coisas sobre isto. Se tiver algo específico, abra uma pergunta.